# Criar lista sem valores duplicados

Tags: c#, .net, estrutura-de-dados, set, hashset

Tenho uma list de `int` e quero salvar mais números nela, porém números que não se repetem.

Como eu faço para localizar se já tem um determinado valor nessa lista?

Answer (score 14):

O que você procura é a estrutura chamada `HashSet`

Se um elemento existir no `HashSet`, ele não será adicionado novamente.
Ou seja é uma *"lista"* que não aceita valores duplicados.

Para saber se um valor existe no *HashSet*, poderá chamar a função `HashSet.Contains()`:

```
var hashset = new HashSet<int>()
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
bool tem_4 = hashset.Contains(4);    // verdadeiro
bool tem_11 = hashset.Contains(11);  // falso
//verifica se o conjunto pertence ao hashset (caso não queira procurar um a um)
bool resultado = hashset.IsSupersetOf(new []{ 4, 6, 7 }); // verdadeiro
```

Para adicionar ou remover chamará as funções:

```
hashset.Add(99);   // adiciona o valor 99 a "lista"
bool add99 = hashset.Add(99);   // tenta adicionar novamente 99 à "lista" (retorna falso)
//Continua havendo só um 99 na lista
hashset.Remove(99);   // remove o valor 99 da "lista"
```

E para iterar sobre o set poderá usar o `foreach`

```
foreach(int valor in hashset)
{
    // faz algo
}
```

Além disso também é possível a conversão para lista e `Array`:

```
int[] array = hashset.ToArray();
List<int> lst = hashset.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Você tem três opções: o `Set`, o `HashSet` e o `SortedSet`. Cada uma com sua característica e depende da sua necessidade um é melhor que o outro.

O .NET não possui uma implementação da estrutura [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) que **pode** ser o mais indicado para o que você deseja. O `Set` guarda os dados na ordem (*ordered*) que você determinar (na ordem que forem inseridos na "lista".

Não confundir estar ordenado com estar classificado (*sorted*) em determinada ordem. Se precisar da classificação (numérico crescente, por exemplo) aí você precisaria de um [SortedSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0)).

O que fazer se não existe um `Set` no .NET?

- Implementar a sua própria estrutura, não é difícil.

  Mas isto leva tempo, se não dominar o assunto provavelmente fará uma implementação ineficiente e com *bugs*.
- Usar uma implementação de terceiros que é bem recomendada e testada.

  Estou falando da biblioteca [PowerCollections](https://www.wintellect.com/power-collections-library/). Veja o [fonte da estrutura do Set](https://github.com/timdetering/Wintellect.PowerCollections/blob/master/Source/PowerCollections/Set.cs). Claro que existem outras opções mas esta é boa.

## Características e performance

Apesar da sua utilidade, geralmente, um `Set` (O(n)) é bem mais lento que um `HashSet` (O(1), embora existam casos em que isto não seja verdade). Por isso o .NET não o implementa. O `SortedSet` (O(log n)) (conhecido como `TreeSet` em algumas implementações) costuma ser mais rápido e pode até ser melhor que o `HashSet` em algumas situações. [Entenda a notação Big O](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33330/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).