# O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo, teoria-da-computação

O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo? 
E quais as formas de medi-la? (Big O, Big Theta...)

Comment: Certamente, esse tópico estará na 'galeria de topicos para ler sempre'.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A complexidade de um algoritmo tem a ver com quanto tempo e memória esse algoritmo gasta de acordo com o tamanho de sua entrada. Por exemplo, queremos responder a perguntas como "se meu algoritmo gasta 1 minuto para processar uma entrada de 1000 bytes, quantos minutos ele gastará para processar uma entrada de 2000 bytes?"

Uma maneira muito direta de calcular a complexidade seria encontrando alguma fórmula que dê o número exato de operações feitas pelo algoritmo para chegar no resultado, em função do tamanho da entrada. Por exemplo, no algoritmo

```
 for(i=0; i<N; i++){
     print(i);
 }
```

poderíamos dizer que o tempo gasto é

```
 T(N) =
    N*(tempo gasto por uma comparação entre i e N) +
    N*(tempo gasto para incrementar i) +
    N*(tempo gasto por um print)
```

No entanto, dá muito trabalho fazer uma conta super precisa dessas e geralmente nem  vale a pena. Por exemplo, suponha que tenhamos nos esforçado bastante e descoberto que um certo algoritmo gasta tempo

```
 T(N) = 10*N² + 137*N + 15
```

Nesse caso o termo quadrático 10*N² é mais importante que os outros pois para praticamente qualquer valor de N ele irá dominar o total da soma. A partir de N ≥ 14 o termo quadrático já é responsável pela maioria do tempo de execução e para N > 1000 ele já é responsável por mais de 99%. Para fins de estimativa poderíamos simplificar a fórmula para `T(N) = 10*N²` sem perder muita coisa.

Outro ponto em que podemos simplificar a nossa fórmula é o fator constante multiplicando o `N²`. Para prever o quão rápido o tempo de execução cresce dependendo da entrada não importa se `T(N) = 10*N` ou `T(N) = 1000*N`; em ambos os casos dobrar o N vai quadruplicar o tempo de execução.

Por isso tudo, a forma mais popular de se trabalhar com complexidade de tempo e espaço na análise de algoritmos é a *complexidade assintótica*, que ignora esses fatores constantes e os termos que crescem mais devagar. É agora que entra a história de O-grande, Θ-grande e Ω-grande: essas são notações que usamos para caracterizar uma complexidade assintótica.

Vamos começar pelo O-grande, que é uma maneira de dar um limite superior para o tempo gasto por um algoritmo. O(g) descreve a classe de funções que crescem no máximo tão rápido quanto a função g e quando falamos que f ∈ O(g) queremos dizer que g cresce pelo menos tão rápido quanto f. Formalmente:

> Dadas duas funções f e g, dizemos que f ∈ O(g) se existem constantes x0 e c tal que para todo x > x0 vale f(x) < c*g(x)

Nessa definição, a constante c nos dá margem para ignorar fatores constantes (o que nos permite dizer que `10*N` é `O(N)`) e a constante x0 diz que só nos importamos para o comportamento de f e g quando o N for grande e os termos que crescem mais rápido dominem o valor total.

Para um exemplo concreto, considere aquela função de tempo f(n) = 10*N^2 + 137*N + 15 de antes. Podemos dizer que o crescimento dela é quadrático:

> Podemos dizer que f ∈ O(N²), já que para c = 11 e N > 137 vale
>
> 10*N² + 137*N + 15 < c * N^2

Podemos escolher outros valores para c e x0, como por exemplo c = 1000 e N > 1000 (que deixam a conta bem óbvia). O valor exato desses pares não importa, o que importa é poder se convencer de que pelo menos um deles exista.

Na direção oposta do O-grande temos o Ω-grande, que é para limites inferiores. Quando falamos que f é Ω(g), estamos dizendo que f cresce pelo menos tão rápido quanto g. No nosso exemplo recorrente, também podemos dizer que f(n) cresce tão rápido quanto uma função quadrática:

> Podemos dizer que f é Ω(N²), já que para c = 1 e N > 0 vale
>
> 10*N² + 137*N + 15 > c*N^2

Finalmente, o Θ-grande tem a ver com aproximações justas, quando o f e o g crescem no mesmo ritmo (exceto por um possível fator constante). A diferença do Θ-grande para o O-grande e o Ω-grande é que estes admitem aproximações folgadas, (por exemplo, N² ∈ O(N³)) em que uma das funções cresce muito mais rápida que a outra.

Dentre essas três notações, a mais comum de se ver é a do O-grande. Normalmente as análises de complexidade se preocupam apenas com o tempo de execução no pior caso então o limite superior dado pelo O-grande é suficiente.

Comment: Dica de um ótimo livro sobre o assunto: Cormen, Thomas H. Introduction to algorithms. MIT press, 2009.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, você deve encontrar essa discussão de O-grande em qualquer bom livro de análise de algoritmos. Eu pessoalmente não sou tão fã assim do Cormen. Acho ele meio chato de ler.

Answer (score 40):

Se você quer uma informação mais teórica, mais correta de como isto funciona, a resposta do hugomg é mais adequada.

Tenha esta resposta como uma alternativa para quem tem dificuldade ou não tem paciência com a teoria que é importante se o seu objetivo for obter resultados precisos e corretos.

Mas é importante sinalizar que a definição mais teórica raramente é usada de fato no "mundo real", mesmo que alguém insista que é um erro, não deixa de ser um fato que é como demonstro abaixo que as pessoas interpretam estes conceitos e esta forma funciona para a maioria dos casos. Estou respondendo porque o assunto é importante para todos e também precisa estar mais acessível. De nada adianta uma informação correta quando uma pessoa não consegue entendê-la.

Aproveite para ter em seu *bookmark* uma [tabela de complexidades](https://bigocheatsheet.com/).

## Definição

[Complexidade de algoritmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) é a quantidade de trabalho necessário para executar uma tarefa. Isto é medido em cima das funções fundamentais que o algoritmo é capaz de fazer (acesso, inserção, remoção, são exemplos mais comuns em computação), o volume de dados (quantidade de elementos a processar), e é claro, a maneira como ele chega no resultado.

Esta quantidade de trabalho tem a ver com tempo mas também pode referir-se à quantidade de memória necessária para garantir sua execução.

Você pode comparar diferentes grandezas. Você estabelece a complexidade medindo como o algoritmo se comporta quando ele precisa manipular, por exemplo, 10, 100 e 1000 elementos. Se ele consegue fazer em uma operação nos três casos, o algoritmo é constante, se cada um precisa 10 vezes mais operações ele é linear e se preciso do quadrado do número de elementos, obviamente é quadrático. Lembro que são apenas alguns exemplos ilustrativos. Não é difícil notar como isto pode fazer uma enorme diferença de desempenho se você tem grandes volumes de dados. Em algoritmos de altíssima complexidade até pequenos volumes podem ter um desempenho bastante ruim.

Eu achei esta [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338937/221800) que me pareceu bem precisa e informa bem o que é mais importante sobre o assunto. Como demonstrado nela os termos mais corretos e que muda também a percepção do que seja a informação são **limite superior** e **limite inferior**, que efetivamente não são apenas sinônimos para pior e melhor caso.

Em tese qualquer fórmula pode estar dentro da notação Big O ou Big Omega ou Big Theta, mas algumas são mais comuns.

O Big-O é o mais usado, mesmo que de forma ingênua. Veja na Wikipedia as [fórmulas mais comuns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions). Eu destacaria como principais: constante (um `if` é um exemplo de algoritmo constante, um *array* e um *hash* ou dicionário é um exemplo de estrutura de dados que possui acesso constante), logarítmica ([busca binária](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) é o melhor exemplo), linear (um `for` simples, uma lista ligada na maioria das implementações são exemplos) e quadrática ou exponencial (`for`s aninhados).

Você não pode medir coisas distintas para compará-las. Não pode comparar uma operação de adição numérica com uma ordenação de uma lista.

Costumamos nos referenciar ao [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) como o pior caso e ainda mais raramente Big Omega como o melhor caso (normalmente não é uma informação relevante). E ainda ao Big Theta quando os anteriores se confundem.

## Uso trivial

Esta seção não deve ser levada muito ao pé da letra, ela não tem uma base teórica forte, é só uma forma para facilitar o entendimento por quem não tem estudo formal sobre o assunto e deseja ter um pássaro na mão. Estou fazendo simplificações. Não há espaço para explicar todos os detalhes a variações. Pincei alguns aspectos apenas.

#### Big-O

É muito comum chamar de Big-O quando a informação é sobre a média de execução, mesmo que isto não seja a definição mais precisa para ele. É comum também fazer aproximações ou desconsiderar casos excepcionais. Por exemplo, um *hash* costuma ter o pior caso como O(n), mas em geral é dito que ele tem O(1) porque isto é o que geralmente acontece. O O(n) acontece apenas em casos extremos.

Em muitos casos é melhor ater-se ao caso médio ainda que seria importante saber antes se realmente há boa distribuição para garantir que a média ocorra na prática. Então o mais comum é usarmos o caso típico como referência e não o pior caso.

#### Velocidade real

Outro ponto importante é que isto não é uma medida de velocidade real do algoritmo, isto depende de fatores práticos que podem variar de maneira que não é possível especificar formalmente. Esta variação pode ocorrer em função da implementação específica do algoritmo e/ou arquitetura onde está sendo executado (veja um relato de caso real no comentário abaixo do mgibsonbr), conjunto e capacidade das instruções do processador, predição de *branch*, re-ordem de execução, cache, localidade, custo de administração de outras operações e outros fatores mais "exotéricos" (difíceis de determinar de antemão como necessidade de *swap* em disco, concorrência e falhas) podem fazer um algoritmo se comportar de forma mais ou menos eficiente em termos de velocidade real. Em teoria estas coisas não existem. Na prática...

Então, em tese e em alguns casos na prática, um O(1) pode ser mais lento que um O(n) ou mesmo um O(n^m), embora neste último seria bem raro. Se esta única operação necessária para um algoritmo constante demora `100ns` e a operação individual do algoritmo que tem complexidade O(n^m) demora `10ns` com N e M valendo `2`, fica claro que o segundo algoritmo irá executar mais rápido, neste raro caso. A grandeza dos dados faz com que a curva de execução não se distancie suficientemente para fazer diferença.

#### Contra-intuição

Mas é mais comum você ter um O(log n) mais rápido que um O(n) mesmo para um volume de dados maior, afinal o logaritmo costuma se aproximar de números baixos. Mas é claro que pode não valer nada disto pelos fatores acima. O algoritmo O(log n) costuma ter problema de [localidade de referência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) então o O(n) acaba sendo mais rápido em muitos casos.

Olhando um outro aspecto um O(1) pode ser mais lento em alguns casos que um O(log n) ou mesmo complexidades maiores como O(n). Pode parecer estranho que um O(1) possa ser mais lento, mas é normal porque este número indica a quantidade de operações necessárias para se alcançar um resultado. Não fala sobre o tamanho desta operação, quanto tempo a operação individual leva para executar. O hugomg fez uma objeção a isto nos comentários. Eu concordo com ele que isto está errado, mas precisa avisar todo mundo disto. As pessoas fazem aproximações já que elas são suficientes para entender onde se vai chegar na maioria dos casos. Um O(1) pode levar `100ns` para achar um item em uma estrutura de dados e um O(n), onde N é 5 pode levar só `50ns` se cada operação demora `10ns`. Está errado? Pode ser mas é assim que as pessoas usam na prática. É assim que os algoritmos costumam ser divulgados na audiência geral. E sim, sempre aparece alguém contestando esses números porque eles não são bem o que a **teoria** define.

Existe ainda uma outra variável. Imagina que para calcular um valor *hash* de uma *string* você tem que percorrer todos os caracteres desta *string*. Fica óbvio que o cálculo de um *hash* individual provavelmente tem complexidade O(n), mesmo que a coleção em que o *hash* será usado como chave possa ser localizar um item com complexidade O(1).

No caso de uma coleção de *hashs* não há garantia que o acesso seja feito em O(1). Se houver colisão destes *hashs*, pelo menos parcialmente a coleção passa procurar com complexidade O(n). Mas é um exagero dizer que a coleção tem complexidade O(n) por causa disto, na prática nunca atingirá esta complexidade no todo. E pode ser que alguma otimização específica consiga que esta procura seja melhor que O(n).

Viu como é complexo determinar complexidade? (*pun intended... or not*)

Para entender como pode ser ruim em linguagem simples:

```
O(1) = O(yeah) - constante
O(log n) = O(nice) - logarítmica
O(n) = O(k) - linear
O(n log n) = O(k-ish) - logarítmica linear
O(n^2) = O(my) - quadrática
O(2^n) = O(no) - subexponencial
O(n^n) = O(fuck) - exponencial
O(n!) = O(mg!) - fatorial
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/AlgorithmComplexity.txt).

Existem diversas outras, essas são as mais comuns, espero que as últimas bem pouco comuns.

## Referências externas

- [Como calcular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255/221800)
- [Um pouco de teoria](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/%7Ekeller/courses/cs60/slides/Complexity.html).
- E [em português](https://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/%7Eting/Courses/ea869/faq1.html).

Comment: big theta não quer dizer caso médio, ele quer dizer que o limite superior big-O e o limite inferior big-Omega são o mesmo. Por exemplo podemos falar coisas como o tempo médio gasto pelo algoritmo é Omega(N) ou o tempo gasto no pior caso é Theta(N^2)

Comment: @hugomg é verdade, me confundi na correria, vou acetar isto agora mas ainda precisa melhorar algumas coisas depois (do vôlei :) )

Comment: cuidado também quando você fala que a complexidade de beta e chamada de (beta). o que pode ser O de algo são sempre funções. logo, você tem que dizer que o tempo de execução do algoritmo é dado por uma função f que depende do tamanho da entrada e f é O de alguma coisa. e ainda, dizer que que f = O é um abuso de notação, já que deveria ser um símbolo de pertence. mas isso é completamente irrelevante na prática :P

Comment: "isto não é uma medida de velocidade real do algoritmo" Quando estava estudando computação paralela, fiz um trabalho que consistia em paralelizar um algoritmo em matrizes (não lembro qual, mas era `O(n^3)`). No final, a versão paralela ficou mais **lenta** que a sequencial! Investigando, vi que ambos os algoritmos continuavam `O(n^3)`, mas embora o fator constante do `n^3` tivesse de fato diminuído, o fator constante do `n^2` cresceu enormemente. Pois embora tivéssemos levado em conta a complexidade em tempo e espaço, esquecemos de considerar na conta a troca de dados entre os processadores...

Comment: @LucasVirgili Eu retirei esta parte já que nunca foi o foco da minha resposta e porque eu não domino o assunto tão profundamente.

Comment: @mgibsonbr citei seu exemplo. Eu digo que é importante "ignorar" um pouco a teoria nestes casos porque ela se mostra irrelevante e pode nos levar à conclusões incorretas. Por isto quando estamos desenvolvendo softwares precisamos medir a realidade e não confiar nas suposições (mesmo que boas, corretas) que a a teoria nos dá.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Você tem esse trabalho publicado em algum lugar?

Comment: @utluiz Isso foi só um trabalho de faculdade, no curso de graduação, não tinha nada pra publicar não. Porém... eu encontrei ele no meio dos meus arquivos antigos! :P Segue o [link pro Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/057u50ep9l2xdog/AAA4ix7vonVUHit6PtM8EsWva?dl=0) se você quiser mesmo ver. Trata-se do [método de decomposição LU  para solução de sistemas de equação lineares](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_LU). Foi testado num "supercomputador" com 16 processadores (pros padrões de 2001 ainda tava bom... acho). P.S. o código não é meu.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Muito obrigado! Tenho um trabalho de CP no mestrado para implementar o [Método de Jacobi](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Jacobi) para resolver equações lineares. Vai ser muito interessante ter uma outra abordagem para comparar! :)

Comment: @utluiz Espero que ajude alguma coisa então! Infelizmente, não tenho o relatório final, somente a parte que eu escrevi (por isso o arquivo está incompleto). A propósito, pra que fique bem claro (pois isso não foi mencionado até agora): a minha implementação deu errado porque meu grupo resolveu dividir a matriz em **linhas** - cada processador recebia um número igual de linhas para trabalhar; se tivéssemos dividido a mesma em **colunas**, o *overhead* da troca de dados entre processadores seria da ordem de `n`, não `n^2`, e de fato os grupos que fizeram isso obtiveram os resultados desejados.

Comment: Descupa bigown mas complexidade assintótica é um troço bem definido mas a última revisão da sua resposta está dizendo muitas coisas que podem acabar aumentando a confusão das pessoas e passando a impressão de que a teoria não serve pra nada.

1) Adições e multiplicações são O(1) no caso comum em que multiplicamos inteiros com um número fixo de bits.

Comment: 2) Também se usa O-grande para falar sobre o tempo esperado (tempo médio) gasto pelo algorítmo. Não insista em passar a impressão de que O-grande tem a ver com o pior caso e que não se usa complexidade assintótica para o caso médio. A teoria não tem na contra com o estudo do caso médio, pelo contrário!

Comment: 3) Na explicação sobre localidade de referência você deveria estar comparando O(log n) com O(n), não com O(1).

4) A razão da não intuitividade do problema de localidade de referência e outro problemas "exotéricos" é simplesmente devido a esses fatores constantes serem muito grandes, o que é significativo para complexidades baixas como O(n). Para entradas suficientemente grandes o log(n) vai ser melhor - é só que as entradas que usamos na prática são menores que isso.

Comment: 5) O(1) fala sim sobre o tamanho de uma operação. Quer dizer que o custo dessa operação é limitado por uma constante e não cresce tendendo ao infinito quando a o tamanho da entrada cresce. Se calcular o hash de uma string longa é O(n) então o custo de inserir essa string na tabela é O(n) mesmo, não O(1).

Comment: 6) Hash table não tem nada a ver com essa história sobre N pequeno e nenhum livro de estruturas de dados vai dizer que o custo de uma inserção é O(1). O custo O(1) é o custo *amortizado* e só faz sentido falar sobre amortização quando fazemos uma longa sequência de operações e as operações mais baratas compensam as operações caras de redimensionamento de tabela (O(n)), que só ocorrem raramente.

Comment: @hugomg eu fui bem claro quanto a teoria ser importante. E fui claro que a teoria excessiva também não ajuda as pessoas entenderem o problema. De fato, teve pessoas que me falaram que não entenderam nada do que você falou. É claro que você pode alegar que elas deveriam se esforçar mais, que elas são limitadas, que... mas ainda assim, para elas a sua resposta não ajudou nada. Não estou dizendo que ela seja ruim, EU achei muito boa e ela é a mais correta. Eu ressalto isto na minha resposta. Verei suas objeções específicas e se achar algum problema editarei a resposta.

Comment: @hugomg Melhorei algumas coisas que estavam confusas, consertei um erro bobo que não tinha percebido, tentei clarificar a intenção em alguns casos, insisti no que eu vejo sendo usado na prática, mesmo que de forma errada, tem  no texto a ressalvo q ele não é preciso e deixei de lado o que você falou que eu não citei em nenhum momento (não falo de inserções). Estou lendo seus comentários se ainda tiver algo a dizer, mas entenda que meu objetivo é passar algumas informações para quem não pode se valer de toda base teórica para conseguir aprender alguma coisa, mesmo que de forma imprecisa.

Comment: Realmente concordo com você @hugomg. As vezes precisamos simplificar ao máximo para leigos possam compreender algo complexo.