# Complexidade de classe P e NP

Tags: máquina-de-estado

Boa noite, acabei de começar a ver FSM (máquina de estado finito) e eu li sobre complexidade de algoritmos e sobre P e NP, porém tenho 2 perguntas que não estou entendendo.

Tenho essa foto das 2 máquinas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Qual a complexidade da classe P?
- Qual a complexidade da classe NP?

O que seria a complexidade da classe?

Comment: Veja se as respostas a [esta pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34104/74) esclarecem sua dúvida.

Comment: Dei umas pesquisadas aqui também e este outro tópico que você citou já ajudou muito!

Comment: Você considera que sua pergunta é duplicata daquela, ou tem algo que lá não explica?

Comment: @bfavaretto são diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

João,

## Preliminares

A tua pergunta está pouco clara!
Se for realmente "Qual a complexidade da classe P/NP?" os dois automatos apresentados não estão a fazer nada -- presumo que não seja isso que pretendes.

Para a pergunta fazer sentido tens que definir o enunciado -- complexidade a fazer qualquer coisa de concreto: tens que definir / apresentar um algoritmo sobre esses autómatos, constata-se que.

**Tentando adivinhar**:

Presumindo que os dois autómatos vão ser usados para reconhecer se uma strings 0/1 é válida, e olhando para os dois autómatos:

- M1 é um autómato não determinístico (no estado 0 perante um "1" tenho dois estados possiveis para transitar.)
- M2 é o autómato determinístico equivalente à máquina M1. (provavelmente obtido através de um algoritmo clássico de conversão autómato não determinístico --> automato determinístico)
- Se M1 tiver n estdos, a máquina M2 poderá ter no máximo 2^n estados (como é o caso presente) embora normalmente tenho um número bastante menor que isso.

Sendo M2 uma máquina determinística, O algoritmo é evidente: (transitar por cada símbolo da entrada) e o reconhecedor dessa máquina  é **linear** em relação ao comprimento da string de entrada (O(k))

A tempo demorado pelo reconhecedor de M2 vai ser mais demorado e vai depender do algoritmo concreto usado...