# O que é uma Matriz de Adjacência?

Tags: terminologia, matriz, matemática, grafo

Sempre que [leio](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148316) algo em relação a teoria dos grafos eu esbarro com um termo chamado *Matriz de Adjacência*, me parece que isso esta fortemente relacionado com esta teoria. Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber mais a respeito do assunto.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é a Matriz de Adjacência? Seria algum tipo de estrutura de dados?
2. Que tipo de relação ela tem com a teoria dos grafos?
3. Há alguma matemática por traz dessa matriz?

Comment: Sim, é uma estrutura de dados. Ela basicamente é um grafo, e sim, tem muita matemática envolvida.. já estudou sobre Dijkstra?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza nem é a parte matemática o mais importante, mas sim o uso dela na teoria dos grafos.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza , não sei se é porque eu já ensinei e expliquei tanto o que é isso que levaria uma pessoa à exaustão, mas para mim ela é perfeitamente clara e objetiva. Poderia caber no Mathematics sim, mas como também é um termo relacionado a programação é extensamente usado em problemas de grafos finitos de uma aresta (no máximo) entre dois vértices, é perfeitamente cabível dentro do SOpt. Tão cabível quanto perguntar o que é a classe de complexidade NPI (assunto mais direcionado ao Computer Science)

Comment: [Abri uma discussão no meta sobre o assunto - e a questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6959/78713). Conto com a porticipação, obrigadão!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## O que é a Matriz de Adjacência?

A grosso modo, é uma matriz de booleanos acessado de maneira direta.

Dado um grafo com `n` vértices, a matriz de adjacências é uma matriz booleana de `n*n` casas. Se há alguma aresta ligando os vértices `i,j` (nessa ordem), então `matriz_adjacencias[i, j] == True`; caso contrário, seu valor é falso.

Ela se encaixa em uma das estratégias de representação de grafos. Note que ela se aplica a grafos *finitos* e de vértices *conhecidos*. O que quero dizer com isso?, por acaso existem grafos infinitos?

Sim, existem grafos infinitos. Eles são descritos proceduralmente. Inclusive eu falei de um grafo infinito na [minha resposta sobre o Problema da Parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276658/64969). No caso em específico, o grafo é descrito a partir de uma gramática irrestrita da seguinte forma:

1. todo vértice `V` do grafo é uma forma sentencial
2. se `V` tem algum não-terminal em sua composição, então pode haver aresta saindo de `V` em direção a outro vértice
3. considere a aresta `Aijkl = (Vi, Vj)`, isso significa que há uma produção `Pk` na gramática capaz de transformar **diretamente** a forma sentencial `Vi` na forma sentencial `Vj`

   - o `l` no índice da aresta `Aijkl` serve para indicar que a produção `Pk` foi aplicada na posição `l` da forma sentencial `Vi`
4. `S` é um vértice que pertence ao grafo

Essa descrição acima respeita a definição de grafos (um conjunto de vértices e arestas que contém dois elementos do conjunto de vértices). Note que aqui determinar se um vértice `V` pertence ou não ao grafo (ou seja, está dentro do conjunto de vértices daquele grafo) é uma tarefa Turing-completa, mas pelo meu entendimento de Teoria dos Conjuntos não inviabiliza definir conjuntos desse jeito. Similarmente, as arestas também foram definidas de maneira procedural, mas aqui é determinístico e polinomial determinar se a aresta `(Vi, Vj)` existe.

Nesses casos, de grafos cujas descrições são procedurais e se gera um conjunto infinito de dados, não é possível usar matrizes de adjacência.

### Seria algum tipo de estrutura de dados?

> Atenção, alguns códigos com uma sintaxe semelhante a Python vai ser exibido a seguir, mas saiba que eles são meramente ilustrativos e que poderiam ser feitos de maneira muito mais eficiente em Python; a ideia é apenas exibir um pseudo-código de como seria a implementação em uma linguagem imperativa

Com certeza. Como dito anteriormente, ela indica a existência ou não de arestas entre dois vértices.

A pergunta a ser feita a uma matriz de adjacência é: "há uma aresta entre os vértices `Vi` e `Vj`?" Programaticamente seria mais ou menos `G.adjacente(Vi, Vj)`.

A operação é mais ou menos assim (usando como `v_origem` e `v_destino` os índices dos vértices):

```py
def adjacente(grafo, v_origem, v_destino):
  return grafo.matriz_adjacencias[v_origem, v_destino]
```

Outras estruturas que servem de concorrentes a essa estrutura (e que servem para grafos finitos) são:

- **matriz de distâncias**
  na matriz de distâncias você armazena a distância relacionada a aresta `Aij = (Vi, Vj)` e, caso não haja tal aresta, você pode armazenar um valor que indica a não existência (como `null`, `NaN`, `infty` ou negativos, dependendo da linguagem e do protocolo de armazenamento de dados); considerando que as distâncias são armazenadas como `NaN` para indicar que não há arestas, o código a seguir responde sobre as adjacências ([baseado nisto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944733/4438007)):

  ```py
  def adjacente(grafo, v_origem, v_destino):
    return not math.isnan(grafo.matriz_distancias[v_origem, v_destino])
  ```
- **matriz de arestas**
  semelhante ao modelo de **matriz de adjacência** ou de **matriz de distâncias**, mas aqui quem é armazenado é uma aresta, não um booleano ou uma distância; na ausência de aresta, ou se armazena `null` ou uma "aresta inválida"; esse modelo permite armazenar outros dados nas arestas que não apenas a distância entre dois pontos, mas também outros tipos de dados, como a "**cor**" da aresta; a simples existência da aresta (válida) nessa matriz implica na adjacência

  ```py
  def adjacente(grafo, v_origem, v_destino):
    return grafo.matriz_arestas[v_origem, v_destino]) is not None
  ```
- **lista de adjacências**
  nesse modelo, cada vértices tem suas arestas diretamente; para o grafo `G`, perguntar `G.adjacente(Vi, Vj)` se torna uma chamada para `Vi.adjacente(Vj)`; por sua vez, `Vi.adjacente(Vj)` vai consistir na iteração de uma lista (ligada ou contígua, nesse ponto não interessa) mas ou menos assim:

  ```py
  def adjacente(grafo, v_origem, v_destino):
    # esse laço abaixo é equivalente a v_origem.adjacente(v_destino)
    for aresta in v_origem.arestas:
      if aresta.destino == v_destino:
        return True
    return False
  ```

#### Quando devo usar essa estrutura de dados?

Depende do uso =)

Particularmente, eu não sou fã de matriz de adjacência por si, exceto se por acaso o seu grafo for um grafo de *distâncias unitárias*. Prefiro outros modelos, principalmente de *matriz de distâncias*. As vezes as pessoas confundem as duas matrizes, então há a hipótese de alguém falar de matriz de adjacência mas na verdade estar usando matriz de distâncias.

Outro caso possível é quando há a possibilidade de existir diversas arestas distintas entre dois pontos, cada uma boa em um dos objetivos da otimização. Nesse caso, indicar a existência da ligação não é o suficiente, pois podem existir várias ligações entre dois vértices. E todas essas diversas ligações com diversas propriedades devem ser levadas em consideração. Por exemplo, [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241293/64969), existem duas ligações distintas entre `(ap,ap)` (sim, duas arestas auto-incidentes de para `ap`).

## Que tipo de relação ela tem com teoria dos grafos? / Há alguma matemática por traz dessa matriz?

Essas duas perguntas basicamente tem a mesma resposta. Grafos é matemática pura. Basicamente, a relação é essa:

[image: se a matriz na posição (i,j) for verdade, então há aresta de i para j no grafo]

## Algumas observações

Como dito anteriormente, tome cuidado com o tipo de grafo que você está mexendo. Se ele permitir a existência (e a distinção) entre arestas diferentes com mesmos origem e destino, então a matriz de adjacências não é o suficiente para o seu problema.

Há distinção entre matrizes de distâncias e matrizes de adjacências. A matriz de distância pode ser transformada em matriz de adjacência, mas a recíproca não é verdadeira.

Em grafos direcionados, é comum encontrar `M[i,j] != M[j,i]`. Por exemplo, [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969) eu coloquei um autômato cuja matriz de adjacência é:

```py
                  destino
o         | q0 | qb1 | qb2 | qa | damn
r    q0   | 1  | 1   | 0   | 0  | 0
i    qb1  | 1  | 0   | 1   | 0  | 0
g    qb2  | 1  | 0   | 1   | 1  | 0
e    qa   | 1  | 0   | 0   | 0  | 1
m    damn | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0  | 1
```

Isso acontece pois o grafo é *direcionado*. Se fosse um grafo *não-direcionado*, então todas as recíprocas seriam verdadeiras.

Existem casos em que não é permitido ter arestas auto-incidentes.

As seguintes questões podem ser respondidas tendo somente a matriz de adjacências:

1. o grafo é conexo?
2. o grafo `G` é isomorfo ao grafo `H`? (só porque pode responder não quer dizer que [seja fácil responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285452/64969))
3. quais são as pontes nesse grafo?
4. qual o caminho/quais os caminhos entre os vértices `i` e `j` com *menos saltos*?<sup>1</sup>
5. existe algum "poço" em relação ao subconjunto de vértices `U`? quais os vértices que pertencem a esse "poço"?<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1: é o mesmo que determinar a menor distância considerando as distâncias unitárias =)</sup>
<sup>2: tomei a terminologia de *poço* emprestado dos autômatos; na teoria dos autômatos, um *poço* é um estado que, do qual, é impossível ir para um estado de aceitação</sup>

Existem outros muitos problemas que são resolvidos considerando-se apenas as adjacências, mas creio que a lista é muito mais extensa do que eu sou capaz de lembrar.

### Adjacências e cliques

Um clique é um grafo em que **todos** os vértices são ligados uns com os outros (retirando a auto-ligação). Ou seja, uma matriz de adjacências de um clique de 3 vértices é isto:

```py
0  1  1
1  0  1
1  1  0
```

A única mudança que pode haver é se existe alguma aresta que tem origem e destino no mesmo vértice, então na diagonal principal vai haver o valor verdade para essa ligação.

Quando se trata de uma matriz indicando as distâncias entre pontos em um plano (como a matriz existente [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291802/64969)), então temos um clique, pois **sempre** é possível sair de um ponto e chegar no outro. Para casos assim, a matriz de adjacências é redundante, sendo preferível usar a matriz de distâncias.

Comment: Olhe que problema interessante eu bolei: "*Tenho duas matrizes A e B quadradas de mesmo tamanho cheias de números. Devo decidir se é ou não possível transformar A em B por meio de alguma sequência qualquer de operações de permuta, onde em cada operação, eu posso permutar as linhas i e j desde que também permutando as colunas i e j.*" - Esse problema é provavelmente NPI, vez que o problema do isomorfismo de grafos é reduzido a ele ao transformar os dois grafos em matrizes de adjacência.

Comment: Nessa resposta, você só está esquecendo o caso das arestas paralelas, onde ao invés de booleano temos um inteiro não-negativo. De qualquer forma, já tem o meu +1 garantido fácil.

Comment: @VictorStafusa adicionar essa observação sobre arestas paralelas está no meu _roadmap_ desta resposta, mas acabou que como a prioridade para tal é baixa, ainda estou devendo... e muito interessante sua observação do NPI, isomorfismo de matrizes xD