# Como implementar o método "avaliar()" e "sucessor()" do algoritmo Subida de Encosta?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Estou tentando implementar o algoritmo Subida de Encosta (Hill Climbing) e este algoritmo deve retornar a sequencia das cidades considerada *boa* (com a menor distancia entre as cidades) do problema do caixeiro viajante com base em uma matriz de adjacência, no entanto, estou tendo dificuldade na implementação dos métodos `avaliar()` e `sucessor()`, não sei qual abordagem eu deveria tomar para que esses métodos funcionem da forma esperada.

A implementação esta sendo em JavaScript:

```
let matrizAdjacente = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 0, 5, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 8, 0, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 2, 1, 0, 6, 3],
    [4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4],
    [3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0]
];

let sequenciaCidades = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

let solucaoInicial = function() {
    return [4, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2];
}

let avaliar = function(estado) {

}

let sucessor = function(atual, novo) {

}

let hillClimbing = function() {
    let novo = null;
    let atual = solucaoInicial();
    let valorAvaliadoAtual = avaliar(atual);
    let valorAvaliadoNovo = 0;

    while (1) {
        novo = sucessor(atual, novo);
        valorAvaliadoNovo = avaliar(novo);

        if (valorAvaliadoNovo < valorAvaliadoAtual) {
            atual = novo;
            valorAvaliadoAtual = valorAvaliadoAtual;
        } else break;
    }

    return atual;
}
```

Este algoritmo consiste em examinar os sucessores do estado atual e seguir para o primeiro estado que for maior que o atual. Porém, é necessário implementar os métodos `avaliar()` e `sucessor()`, o método sucessor ira fazer uma troca entre os estados e o método avaliar vai retornar um valor dada uma sequencia.

## Pergunta

Sendo assim, como eu poderia implementar o método `avaliar()` e `sucessor()` do algoritmo Subida de Encosta?

Comment: O que representam os valores do array `sequenciaCidades` ? Cada cidade não teria o seu posicionamento x,y e distancia calculada através de distância euclidiana ou distância *manhattan* ?

Comment: @Isac em relação a isso eu fiquei na dúvida (não foi contextualizado no exercício), mas provavelmente são as cidades que estão ligadas com base na solução, acho que não seria necessário este array.

Comment: O `avaliar` é um dos argumentos da meta-heurística. Em cima disso, o _hill climbing_ toma a decisão de continuar ou de voltar um passo e tentar de novo

Comment: A propósito, essa matriz é a matriz de distâncias, não [a de adjacências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290748/64969). XD

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado no exercício estava marcado como matriz de adjacência xD

Answer (score 3):

Se eu entendi direito, o método `sucessor()` te dá uma lista de cidades para ser avaliada pelo método `avaliar()`, que deve devolver o custo da sua solução, ou seja, a distância que seria percorrida se visitarmos as cidades em uma determinada ordem e se essa distância for melhor da que a que temos atualmente, usaremos essa nova sequência como nossa solução ótima, dessa forma, tudo que `avaliar()` avaliar precisa fazer é percorrer a lista somando as distâncias da matriz D de distâncias (ou adjacência, como preferir) sendo que

```
D[x][y] = distância entre x e y
```

Suponha que você tem a sequência `[2,1,3]`, a sua distância total é portanto
`D[2][1]+D[1][3]` ou seja, o custo de ir da cidade 2 até a cidade 1 e depois da cidade 1 até a cidade 3, essa lógica pode ser implementada com um loop for em cima da lista de cidades devolvida por `sucessor()`.

Já o trabalho do método `sucessor()` é usar uma lista anterior de cidades para gerar uma nova candidata a solução, isso pode ser feito de diversas maneiras, dependendo da especificação do problema, como se trata do PCV, a sugestão mais simples é adicionar a primeira cidade não visitada que você encontrar ao fim da lista desde que ela possa ser alcançada da ultima cidade, suponha que você tem 6 cidade (1 a 6) e sua lista seja algo assim: 
`[4,2,3]`, a próxima cidade não visitada é a cidade 1, se na sua matriz `D[3][1] > 0` (ou seja, existe um caminho de 3 até 1) sua nova lista ficaria `[4,2,3,1]`, caso não exista nenhuma cidade sem visitar, você verifica se pode voltar a primeira cidade (restrição do problema).