# Verificar se o grafo é conexo

Tags: java, grafo

Alguém me sabe dizer como posso implementar um método que me verifique se um grafo não direcionado é conexo e, caso não o seja, devolva os seus componentes conexos?

```
public void connectComps(){
    ArrayList<LinkedList<Estacao>> css = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Estacao, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<>();
    for(Estacao est : mapaEstacoes.vertices()){
        visited.put(est, false);
    }
    for(Estacao v : mapaEstacoes.vertices()){
        if(visited.getOrDefault(v, Boolean.FALSE)){
            LinkedList<Estacao> aux = GraphAlgorithms.BreadthFirstSearch(mapaEstacoes, v);
            css.add(aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá ana, você precisa postar parte do código para o pessoal da comunidade poder te ajudar, tente escrever algo! iremos te ajudar

Comment: Olá @LuizAugusto, achas que este método faz o que pretendo?

Comment: desculpa a demora, mas acredito que sim, ele está retornando algum erro ?

Comment: @analopes, o seu grafo é direcionado ou não direcionado? Caso não esteja acostumada com esses termos: se há a ligação entre as estações `A--B`, então existe necessariamente a ligação `B--A`? Ou existem casos em que existe `A--B` porém não existe `B--A`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é não direcionado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Como a dúvida se trata de grafos não direcionados, estou usando isso como premissa em toda a minha resposta. Tudo que eu escrever vale para grafos não direcionados, exceto se você encontrar alguma referência externa que demonstre o contrário. Não tomarei o cuidado aqui para explicitar aquilo que vale para grafos direcionados.

Vamos começar definindo o que é um componente conexo? Isso servirá de base para eventual código e, também, para por um denominador comum a quem chegar aqui.

Um componente conexo é composta por um vértice e todos os demais vértices que ele consegue alcançar. Como isso é feito? Bem, podemos ver isso recursivamente:

1. seja o vértive `V` um vértice de interesse; por definição, `V` está no alcance de `V`, portanto ele pertence a um componente conexo
2. todas as arestas que contenham `V` e apontam para outros vértices `Ui` aumentam o alcance de `V`, portanto todos os `Ui` estão, também, no alcance de `V`
3. saindo de cada `Ui` através de seus vértices, chegamos aos `Tij`, que estão no alcance de `Ui` e, portanto, no alcance de `V`

Eu particularmente faria a navegação para determinar o alcance de um vértice através de uma busca em profundidade, não uma busca em largura. Por quê? Porque com uma busca em profundidade eu tenho um pico de memória menor na maioria dos casos (o contrário pode acontecer em grafos esparsos, onde a busca em profundidade pode ocupar mais memória) e porque é mais fácil de implementar.

Como eu faria essa busca? Bem, depende muito de como está estruturado o seu grafo. Eu gosto muito da [matriz de adjacência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290748/64969), mas não parece ser seu caso. Vou fingir que o objeto `mapaEstacoes` tenha um método `List<Estacao> vizinhos(Estacao e)` que retorna todos os vizinhos de `e`. Tentei pensar em algum jeito de tornar o meu código o mais semelhante ao que você postou, entretanto, como o seu não é recursivo e eu não entendi o uso nem necessidade da variável `css`, não consegui.

Basicamente, vou buscar todas os componentes conexos de um grafo. Vou mapear essos componentes conexos em identificadores sequenciais e mapear cada estação para um componente  conexo. Portanto, terei um `Map<Estacao, Integer>` que identificará, para aquela estação, qual o seu componente conexo.

A busca vai se iniciar passando-se um vértice (representando um componente conexo inédito) e o identificador do componente conexo. Conforme vou alcançando novos vértices, garantidamente eles seguem uma dessas duas propriedades: (a) eles já estão no componente conexo em questão, (b) eles ainda não foram visitados. Vou indicar que um vértice não foi visitado *ainda* quando a consulta ao mapa de vértice para identificador do componente conexo resultar em `null`.

```
public static Map<Estacao, Integer> buscarComponentesConexos(GrafoMisterioso mapaEstacoes) {
    Map<Estacao, Integer> relacaoComponentesConexos = new HashMap<>();
    int idComponenteConexoInedito = 0;

    for (Estacao v: mapaEstacoes.vertices()) {
        if (relacaoComponentesConexos.get(v) == null) {
            determinaComponenteConexo(v, idComponenteConexoInedito, mapaEstacoes, relacaoComponentesConexos);
            idComponenteConexoInedito++;
        }
    }
    return relacaoComponentesConexos;
}

private static void determinaComponenteConexo(Estacao v, int idComponenteConexo, GrafoMisterioso mapaEstacoes, Map<Estacao, Integer> relacaoComponentesConexos) {
    // se eu cheguei aqui, então devo marcar o vértice passado como pertencente ao componente conexo
    relacaoComponentesConexos.put(v, idComponenteConexo);

    // percorre os vizinhos...
    for (Estacao u: mapaEstacoes.vizinhos(v)) {
        // se o vizinho u ainda não foi visitado, visite-o
        if (relacaoComponentesConexos.get(u) == null) {
            determinaComponenteConexo(u, idComponenteConexo, mapaEstacoes, relacaoComponentesConexos);
        }
    }
}
```

Com isso, a partir de um grafo, conseguimos determinar para todos os seus pontos quais sao seus componentes conexos. Não exatamente os componentes conexos, mas quase...

Um grafo é dito conexo se ele contiver apenas um único componente conexo. Como posso descobrir isso? Bem, vamos usar um `stream` para verificar se há algum índice maior que zero?

```
Map<Estacao, Integer> relacaoComponenteConexo = buscarComponentesConexos(mapaEstacoes);
OptionalInt qualquerOutro = relacaoComponenteConexo.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).filter(v -> v > 0).findAny(); // estou considerando que o sequencial 0 sempre é usado para o primeiro componente conexo
boolean grafoConexo = !qualquerOutro.isPresent();
```

E se for necessário buscar cada componente conexo? Bem, nesse caso, precisamos inverter o mapeamento. Agora, devo mapear de um índice para uma lista de vértices:

```
Map<Estacao, Integer> relacaoComponenteConexo = buscarComponentesConexos(mapaEstacoes);
Map<Integer, List<Estacao>> = relacaoComponenteConexo.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(es -> es.getValue(),
              Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Obrigado @Jefferson, foi uma ótima ajuda!!

Comment: @analopes, eu cometi um engano ao estipular a quantidade de memória, porém o corrigi na minha edição. Há casos em que a busca em largura ocuparia menos memória do que uma busca em profundidade