# Definição da notação "Big O"

Tags: algoritmo, matemática

Em discussões acerca de performance de algoritmos, é muito comum o uso da notação ***Big O***:

> *O(1)*, *O(n)*, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

É fácil encontrar a definição científica desta notação e é fácil encontrar algumas definições mais informais em inglês.

O que eu peço aqui é uma definição informal desta notação, que seja imediatamente útil até mesmo para o menos versado em matemática.

Vou tentar formular um exemplo para trazer a definição do *Big O* para o âmbito prático:

> Estudando as implementações de lista **ArrayList** e **LinkedList** (Java), [diz-se](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742) que uma das diferenças entre elas é que o método *ArrayList.get(int index)* é **O(1)** enquanto o método *LinkedList.get(int index)* é **O(n)** mas, na prática, **o que a notação *Big O* está indicando neste caso?**

É claro que outros exemplos práticos são bem vindos.

Comment: Tenho que confessar que a definição "científica" é a mais simples e *precisa*  que conheço. Qual a dificuldade que você está tendo com ela?

Comment: A pergunta é boa mas não vou me arriscar responder porque não á fácil acertar o alvo dela, o foco dela não é o conteúdo e sim a forma. Para quem não conhece tem uma pergunta famosa no SO sobre isto. E mesmo traduzir uma dessas respostas eu não sei se resolveria. Não sei se esyá tão simples assim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Comment: Possível é, só não acho que eu deva fazer.

Comment: Relacionado: ["O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/215)

Comment: Este é o tipo de questão que traz água na boca :D.

Comment: @bigown não vai responder, só porque a pergunta tem quase o seu nome?

Comment: O big O significa que a função (número de operações) é limitada: Por exemplo: O(e^n), significa que existe um número (alfa) que limita essa função: o número de operações é sempre inferior a alfa*e^n. A análise O() não leva em consideração o valor alfa, só diz que ele existe. O(2.e^n) = O(e^n) (fatora-se a constante que se junta a alfa). Alguns algorítmos são bastante otimizados, mas algumas vezes é possível minimizar o valor alfa.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Eis uma definição informal (e visual).

A ideia da notação *Big-O* é descrever o comportamento geral (também chamado de assintótico, pois é o comportamento no limite conforme os dados crescem) do algoritmo em termos do crescimento do número de operações conforme cresce o número de elementos processados (a quantidade de itens é descrita, genericamente, por `n`).

A ideia é usar a letra **O** seguida de uma função sobre `n` que descreva esse crescimento do algoritmo. Quanto mais rapidamente crescer o número de operações para processar os itens, "pior" é o desempenho do algoritmo (pois ele executa mais instruções e, portanto, demora mais - é "mais complexo").

Os gráficos abaixo (recriados rapidamente no Excel) ilustram as curvas de crescimento mais comuns. O primeiro tem uma visão geral, e o segundo é uma visão menor (eixo Y com menos valores) para exibir mais claramente as "melhores" curvas de crescimento: **O(1)** e **O(log n)**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desses gráficos é possível perceber que:

- Em um algoritmo de complexidade **O(n!)** (fatorial) o número de instruções executadas cresce muito rapidamente para um pequeno crescimento do número de itens processados. Dentre os ilustrados é o pior comportamento para um algoritmo, pois rapidamente o processamento se torna inviável. É o caso da implementação inocente do [Problema do Caixeiro Viajante](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caixeiro-viajante) ou de um algoritmo que gere todas as possíveis permutações de uma lista, por exemplo ([fonte desse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556053/2896619)).
- Um algoritmo de complexidade **O(2<sup>n</sup>)** (exponencial) também é bem ruim, pois o número de instruções também cresce muito rápidamente (exponencialmente), ainda que numa taxa menor do que o anterior. É o caso de algoritmos que fazem busca em árvores binárias não ordenadas, por exemplo.
- Um algoritmo de complexidade **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** (quadrático) é factível, mas tende a se tornar muito ruim quando a quantidade de dados é suficientemente grande. É o caso de algorítmos que têm dois laços (`for`) encadeados, como, por exemplo, o processamento de itens em uma matriz bidimensional.
- Um algoritmo de complexidade **O(n log n)** (sub-quadrático ou super-linear) é melhor do que o quadrático, sendo geralmente até onde se consegue otimizar algoritmos que são quadráticos em sua implementação mais direta e inocente (*naïve*). É o caso do algoritmo de ordenação [*QuickSort*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), por exemplo (que tem essa complexidade no caso médio, mas que ainda assim é quadrático no pior caso).
- Um algoritmo de complexidade **O(n)** (linear) é aquele cujo crescimento no número de operações é diretamente proporcional ao crescimento do número de itens. É o caso de algoritmos de busca em uma matriz unidimensional não ordenada, por exemplo.
- Um algoritmo de complexidade **O(log n)** (logaritmo) é aquele cujo crescimento do número de operações é menor do que o do número de itens. É o caso de algoritmos de busca em árvores binárias ordenadas (*Binary Search Trees*), por exemplo (no caso médio, no pior caso continua sendo linear).
- Um algoritmo de complexidade **O(1)** (constante) é aquele em que não há crescimento do número de operações, pois não depende do volume de dados de entrada (`n`). É o caso do acesso direto a um elemento de uma matriz, por exemplo.

Assim, na sua pergunta final:

> o que significa dizer que `ArrayList.get(int index)` é **O(1)**
>   enquanto que `LinkedList.get(int index)` é **O(n)**?

Pode-se entender o seguinte:

1. Ambas as estruturas de dados armazenam listas de `n` elementos, e ambos seus métodos `get` são usados para acessar um elemento de posição `index`.
2. `ArrayList.get(int index)` tem complexidade **O(1)** porque provavelmente faz acesso direto à posição de memória do elemento (tal como uma matriz unidimensional via operador `[]`) ou usa [uma tabela de dispersão (*hash table*)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) para localizá-lo rapidamente. Ou seja, faz o acesso com `1` única operação.
3. `LinkedList.get(int index)`, por outro lado, precisa navegar item a item a partir do primeiro item para acessar o item desejado. Isso se deve à estrutura de uma lista ligada ter apenas o ponteiro para o primeiro elemento, que aponta para o próximo, e este aponta para o próximo, e assim sucessivamente. Como no pior caso todos os itens precisarão ser acessados (se o item desejado é o último, isto é, `index = n`), a complexidade do algoritmo é **O(n)**. Ou seja, faz o acesso com `n` operações.

Comparar as duas estruturas de dados *apenas* pela complexidade desse método `get` é errado, pois muito embora o acesso a um item seja mais rápido com a primeira, a exclusão ou adição de um item no meio da lista é mais rápida com a segunda - uma vez que não é necessário copiar/mover `n-1` elementos, bastando modificar as ligações (ponteiros) entre os itens. Assim, em geral essa comparação precisa ser efetuada tendo-se em mente o uso mais amplo que certa estrutura de dados terá em outro algoritmo.

A fonte original dos gráficos é o site http://bigocheatsheet.com/, que aliás tem matrizes de comparação da complexidade na notação *Big-O* de diferentes estruturas de dados e algoritmos.

> Nota: Geralmente, ao usar a notação Big-O, refere-se à complexidade do
>   algoritmo em termos do tempo de execução (relacionado ao número de
>   instruções executadas). Mas, essa mesma analogia pode ser efetuada para descrever
>   a complexidade do algoritmo em termos de espaço (como o espaço de
>   armazenamento cresce conforme cresce o número de dados de entrada). No
>   link referenciado acima pode-se perceber, por exemplo, que as matrizes
>   indicam a complexidade em tempo (*Time Complexity*) e em espaço (*Space Complexity*) 
>   para as estruturas de dados e algoritmos *usando a mesma notação*.

Comment: Por isto eu não respondi, como eu poderia concorrer com isto? :) Interessante ter feito dois gráficos porque o primeiro dá uma ideia errada que as complexidades que mais encontramos são muito próximas, mas é um problema de escala visual.

Comment: É, vou apagar já que não serve mais

Comment: Muito bem explicado, parabéns pela didática!

Comment: Simplesmente sensacional! Foi o único que me fez entender de uma vez por todas essa bagaça.

Comment: O cara explicou em 5 min de leitura o que o professor na faculdade não explicou em várias aulas... sua explicação, em notação Big-O é O(1), parabéns e obrigado! rs

Comment: Explicação excelente. Obrigado, Parabéns!

Answer (score 21):

É meio difícil dar uma resposta informal para este tipo de conteúdo, uma vez que ele requer um conhecimento de limites de funções, mas vou tentar mesmo assim:

Dadas duas funções não negativas **f(n)** e **g(n)**, cujo **n** tende ao infinito, dizemos que **f = Ο(g)**, quando, não importando o quanto **n** cresça, **g(n)** sempre será maior ou igual a **f(n)**.

**Exemplo**

Se **f(n) = n²** e **g(n) = n³**, para todo **n** positivo, **n³** sempre será maior que **n²**, ou seja, **f = O(g)** ( **n² = O(n³)** ).

**Observações**

- Se **f(n) = 3n³** e **g(n) = n³** podemos dizer que **f(n) = n³** e que **f = O(g)**, pois normalmente as constantes são omitidas.
- Podemos dizer também que a função **g(n)** pode ser expressa como o termo de maior potência em **n** da função **f(n)**, ou seja, se **f(n) = n^5 + n^4 + 6**, podemos dizer que **g(n) = n^5**, que é o termo de maior potência em **n** de **f(n)** e também podemos dizer que **f = O(g)**, ou seja, **n^5 = O(n^5)**.

**Levando para a complexidade de algoritmos:**

Se tivermos um array com **n** elementos e quisermos achar o 3º elemento (**n = 3**), nós deveríamos percorrermos **3** elementos no vetor até achá-lo, logo, uma função para achar o **n**ésimo elemento do vetor seria **A(n) = n**, dessa forma, podemos dizer que **g(n) = n**, o que implica que **A = O(g)**, ou seja, **A = O(n)**.

De maneira geral isto quer dizer que, não importa o tamanho do vetor, o **"máximo de operações"** que serão realizadas em uma busca no vetor será de ordem **n**.

Espero ter ajudado e não ter confundido ninguém :p

Answer (score 18):

Definição em uma frase:

- Serve para comparar **quanto de um recurso** é usado por um **algoritmo que processa uma coleção**, quando o número de elementos dessa coleção tende a ser muito grande.

Analogia com hash-code:

- Pra quem já ouviu falar em código-hash... Big-O é como se fosse um código-hash ordenável. Dois valores distintos possuem ordenação relativa. Dois valores iguais não possuem ordenação relativa.

Destacando:

- o recurso medido, geralmente é **tempo de CPU** ou **memória ocupada** (ou algo relacionado... tal como número de operações)
- pode-se medir o Big-O em diferentes circunstâncias: casos **mais favorável**, casos **medianos**, casos **menos favoráveis**
- a entrada do algoritmo é uma coleção de tamanho variável (com `n` elementos)
- a comparação de notações Big-O só é válida para coleções com muitos elementos
- geralmente algoritmos tentam equilibrar os recursos de **tempo de CPU** e **memória ocupada**, então não há algoritmo melhor, e sim mais apropriado para cada situação

Exemplos:

- **O(n)** é sempre menor que **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, quando **n** cresce além de um certo valor. Mesmo que se multiplique o primeiro, ainda assim essa afirmação não muda: **O(n*10000000)** = **O(n)** < **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.
- Se um algoritmo processa uma coleção usando memória **O(n*log(n))** então ela ocupa menos memória que outro algoritmo equivalente que usa **O(n)**. Portanto, se memória for um recurso escaço, é melhor usar o primeiro. Como são equivalentes, provavelmente o primeiro usará mais CPU e o segundo menos.
- Para poucos elementos (e.g. 10, 100... depende do algoritmo) não é possível usar a notação Big-O para avaliar nada. Nesses casos será preciso analisar o recurso durante a execução. Um algoritmo cujo tempo de CPU seja **n<sup>2</sup>** é mais rápido que um **1000*n** até **n = 999**, que é mais rápido que um **O(1)** cuja constante é **10.000.000**.
- Não é possível comparar dois algoritmos cujos Big-O sejam iguais. Mais uma vez é necessário ter em mão a fórmula exata, ou medir manualmente. Um algoritmo **10*n** é melhor que um **100*n**, mas ambos possuem **O(n)**.
- Tem vezes que se está interessado no pior caso de um algoritmo, que é quando este recebe um input que causa o pior desempenho. Por exemplo, [algoritmos amortecidos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis)<sup>(em Inglês)</sup> usam estratégias de memória para agilizar operações sucessivas... entretanto esses algoritmos apresentam variações que podem se tornar muito ruins, não sendo compatíveis com requisitos de alta-performance. O objetivo nesses algoritmos é melhorar o Big-O do caso mais comum.
- Outros algoritmos requerem um Big-O constante, para todos os casos. Muito usado na produção de hardwares. Um exemplo muito interessante são as [sorting networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network): algoritmos de ordenação de **O(1)** invariáveis.

Comment: E o negativo foi por... ???

Comment: Redes de ordenação demoram a profundidade do circuito. Normalmente é `O(log^2 N)`, sendo `N` o tamanho da entrada. Possivelmente a complexidade de passos do hardware seja muito mais rápido do que o de software, por isso a sensação de `O(1)`

Comment: E sendo chato, a complexidade é dado em relação ao processamento da entrada, não em relação a uma coleção. Mas isso é só pedantismo e chatice minha mesmo

Comment: O(1) das redes de ordenação está mais pro caráter invariável do hardware... não dá para variar N depois de implementado, pelo menos é isso que eu quis dizer. Sobre a coleção, acho que eu quis dizer que é algo de tamanho variável... de fato uma entrada de tamanho variável, tal como uma coleção. Mas nem sei se vale a pena editar.