# Análise de complexidade

Tags: java, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a análise de complexidade desse código em Java:

```
public static int cont;

public static int recursive(int base,int numb,ArrayList<Integer> lista){
    if(lista.size()>base) return 0;
    if(numb<0 || numb>base-1) return 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> newArray=new ArrayList<Integer>(lista.size()+1);
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
        newArray.add(lista.get(i));
    newArray.add(numb);
    cont++;

    recursive(base,numb-2,newArray);
    recursive(base,numb-1,newArray);
    recursive(base,numb+1,newArray);
    recursive(base,numb+2,newArray);
    return cont;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int base=11;
    ArrayList<Integer> test=new ArrayList<Integer>(base);

    for(int i=1;i<11;i++){
        recursive(base,i,test);
    }
    System.out.println("Números validos com digitos repetidos:"+cont);
}
```

Não consigo fazer a análise desse algoritmo. Eu devo criar uma variável `instrução` por exemplo, e dar um `instrução++` em cada `if`, atribuição, entrada no `for` ou já que esse algoritmo tem tempo de execução constante dizer que ele é O(1)? Ou ainda, só contar quantas vezes a recursão é chamada?

Comment: Relacionado: [Definição da notação “Big O”](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/3117)

Answer (score 1):

Na analise de complexidade de algoritmos devemos nos adentar as estruturas logicas:

Condicionais;
Repetições;
Entradas - Saídas;
Recursividade;
Chamada de outras Funções;

Basicamente falando, para toda estrutura que possua uma estrutura de repetição, seja `while`, `for`, `do`, etc (não importa a linguagem, Java, VB, Delphi, PHP, etc...) o algorítimo recebe recebe a classificação O(n^2) onde n é a quantidade de entrada e ou saída de interação nesse código.

Se possuirmos um for encadeado por exemplo:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
    }
}
```

A complexidade do algoritmo seria O(2n^2)

Para estruturas condicionas como `if`, `case`, etc somamos mais um na nossa analise, exp:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(i > 10){
    }
}
```

A complexidade do algoritmo seria O(1+n^2)

---

Hoje estou com pouco tempo, amanha edito melhor a resposta(com livros que usava para a materia de analise de complexidade de algoritmos) para formentar melhor minhas resposta, e para analisar melhor o seu algoritmo