# Gerando novos objetos utilizando objetos já existentes

Tags: java, objetos, combinações

Estou com dificuldade de fazer isto.

Supondo que eu tenha dois objetos do tipo **Pessoa**, que tem os atributos nome e emprego.

> P1 (nome=João, emprego=Taxista)
>
> P2 (nome=Maria, emprego=Programador)

Então eu gostaria de gerar as combinações possíveis desses dois objetos, claro sem erros de atributos, por exemplo um objeto ter por exemplo o nome Taxista.

A saída que eu precisaria no caso seria.

> P3 (nome=João, emprego=Programador)
>
> P4 (nome=Maria, emprego=Taxista)

Como posso fazer isso? Existe bibliotecas que me permitam?

**EDIT**

Um exemplo de código seria mais ou menos assim:

```
...

Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("João","Taxista");
Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Maria", Programador;

List<Pessoa> listaDePessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>;
listaDePessoas.add(p1);
listaDePessoas.add(p2);

List<Pessoa> novaLista = new ArrayList<Pessoa>;

novaLista = geraCombinacoes(listaDePessoas); //esse seria o método por exemplo.
```

Ai ao imprimir essa lista a saída seria:

> (João, Taxista)
>
> (Maria, Programador)
>
> (João, Programador)
>
> (Maria, Taxista)

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você está querendo. De que combinações você está falando? Coloque algum código mostrando onde quer chegar.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua dúvida... Pelo que me parece, você precisa de um objeto do tipo `Pessoa` e um objeto do tipo `Emprego`, onde a Pessoa poderia ser instanciada com diferentes nomes (João, Maria, etc) e poderia estar relacionada a algum Emprego (Programador, Taxista, etc).

Comment: Olá @bigown, explicando melhor, vamos supor que eu tenha uma lista com 2 objetos que são instâncias da minha classe pessoa, no caso fazem parte dessa lista objetos p1 e p2. Quero passar essa lista como parâmetro para um método, e ele me retorne as combinações possíveis, que citei acima, a combinação seria entre os atributos dos objetos para criar novos objetos. Vou por como código, pra ver se fica melhor de entender.

Comment: É um algoritmo de combinação simples, correto? Voce quer que todos tenham todas as profissoes?

Comment: Isso @cantoni, quero que todos tenham todas as profissões, e outros atributos tmb, se existirem outros atributos, eles também entram na combinação.

Comment: Certo. Fiz um algoritmo aqui apenas com esses dois atributos. É tao simples que acho que nao é isso que vc quer. É um algoritmo quadratico (um for dentro do outro). Se quiser eu posto. Já a versão para atributos arbitrários precisa usar reflection.

Comment: @cantoni, pode postar, qualquer ajuda é válida, qualquer coisa eu tento desenvolver mais, já é um começo! Mas realmente, onde eu vou realmente utilizar eu tenho uns 6 atributos. Coloquei só 2 para facilitar a explicação.

Comment: Coloquei um código para exemplificar melhor. Não sei se deu pra entender melhor. No caso, todas as pessoas tem que ter todas as profissões. No caso se tivesse um atributo chamado: endereço. Todas as pessoas teriam que ter todos os empregos e todos os endereços, no caso, todas as combinações possíveis.

Comment: Você quer algo genérico ou vão sempre ser esses 6 atributos?

Comment: Por hora serão só esses 6 atributos, mas pode ser que no futuro venha a ter que mudar. Algo genérico seria ótimo, mas se ficarem só os 6 atributos, continua sendo ótimo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O algoritmo abaixo funciona para tres atributos. Para uma quantidade arbitrária uma solução mais elegante é utilizar reflection de forma a descobrir esses atributos *on-the-fly*. Caso os atributos sejam sempre os 6 citados no comentário e a quantidade de objetos seja pequena, complete com mais 3 for aninhados e resolva o problema, seja ele qual for.

```
class Pessoa {

    public Pessoa(String nome, String emprego, String endereco) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.emprego = emprego;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    String nome;
    String emprego;
    String endereco;

    public String toString() {
        return nome +  " - " + emprego + " - " + endereco;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Joao","Programador","ACD"));
    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Jose","Analista","DFSD"));
    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria","Gerente","ASEW"));
    pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Pedro","Tester","VCVC"));

    List<Pessoa> resultado = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

    for(int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < pessoas.size(); j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < pessoas.size(); k++)
                resultado.add(new Pessoa(pessoas.get(i).nome, pessoas.get(j).emprego, pessoas.get(k).endereco));                              

    for(int i = 0; i < resultado.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(resultado.get(i));
    }
}
```

**Atualização**

Acho importante mencionar a complexidade do algoritmo acima. Para três atributos a complexidade é **O(n * n * n)** ou **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**. Cada atributo acidionado acrescentará mais um loop e, portanto, somará + 1 no expoente. Assim, com 6 atributos a complexidade é de **O(n<sup>6</sup>)**.

Generalizando, a complexidade é **O(n<sup>m</sup>)**, onde **n** é o número de pessoas e **m** o número de atributos.

Enfim, esse é um exemplo clássico de um algoritmo que não escala bem. Dependendo do tamanho de **n** e **m** pode ficar inviável executá-lo. De qualquer maneira, não há muito o que fazer, já que é preciso gerar todas as combinações.

para saber mais sobre complexidade veja essa bela resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/3084

Comment: Estou no celular agora @cantoni, amanhã quando eu testar darei uma resposta. Muito obrigado pela disposição. Obrigado!