# Existe alternativa para o RemoveAt()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, desempenho, estrutura-de-dados

Estou usando Entity Framework em um projeto ASP.NET MVC onde tenho uma simples lista de strings e preciso remover apenas o primeiro item.

Usei o seguinte comando:

```
minhaLista.RemoveAt(0);
```

Bem, mas usando uma ferramenta de performance do Visual Studio, pude perceber que em uma lista muito grande o processo consome bastante processamento.

Existe alguma alternativa que consuma menos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem que analisar o que você pode perder. A busca ou acesso por índice na estrutura mostrada pelo Ono Sendai é péssima (não que a resposta dele seja ruim, pelo contrário), se isso não é importante, vá nela.

Se o acesso for importante tem que achar outra estrutura. Pode ser que tenha que repensar totalmente o que está usando, o erro pode estar em outro lugar. Sem contexto é difícil dizer.

Uma coisa que pode fazer se puder mudar a estrutura é usar um *array*. Aí pode usar o [`ArraySegment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Você pode "criar" um segmento onde o primeiro elemento não está presente, você não apaga o dado, mas fica com uma estrutura onde aquele elemento não é mais acessado e os índices são obviamente reposicionados. Então se você pega um segmento começando no elemento 1, este elemento passará ser o 0 na nova variável. O acesso continua fácil e rápido como é no `Array` ou `List`, não copia nada e consegue o que deseja.

Outras soluções podem ser possíveis se algumas condições puderem ser atendidas.

```
var novoArray = new ArraySegment<Cliente>(meuArray, 1, meuArray.Length - 1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/ArraySegment.cs).

Agora tem o [`Span`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é quase certo que seja a melhor solução em todos os sentidos.

Comment: bigown muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Mas por que exatamente a resposta do lbotinelly seria péssima?

Comment: Eu não disse que a resposta dele seria péssima, ela é ótima, tanto que disse para usar, **desde que possa conviver com acesso com velocidade péssima**. A lista ligada tem complexidade de acesso  O(N), quanto que uma lista ou *array* tem complexidade O(1). Ou seja, o acesso direto deste, mesmo no pior caso, é quase instantâneo, basta uma operação simples. A lista ligada no pior caso tem que percorrer toda a lista para achar alguma coisa. Isto vale para o acesso pelo índice ou pelo valor. Eu não sei o que é melhor para seu caso, até porque não conheço seu caso.É possível que não seja nem a minha

Comment: Opa, agora ficou bem mais claro. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu não conhecia a notação O, mas graças ao seu comentário dei uma pesquisada aqui e agora estou um pouco mais por dentro (com o dedinho mindinho do pé na porta de entrada na verdade), mas gostaria de saber onde foi que você conseguiu a informação de que a List tem complexidade O(n) e o Array tem O(1). Isso seria porque o Array é unidirecional e a List multidirecional?

Comment: É uma informação conhecida. Uma lista comum se comporta exatamente como um *array*, então eles são iguais. Além disto costuma ter na documentação. Saber o Big O é fundamental para escolher a estrutura de dados ou algoritmo certo a usar. Uma tabela genérica simplificada (pode não valer para a implementação específica) http://bigocheatsheet.com/ Melhor resposta no site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101 Note que existem truques que pode fazer os compromissos mudarem. Uma lista pode ter a inserção O(N) ou O(1) dependendo do truque e o estado que ela está.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues O ponto do bigown é perfeito no que tange à performance. Se sua lista existe para expressar uma fila FIFO (First In, First Out) então um LinkedList é a melhor opção. Porém se você for iterar na lista de maneira não-serial o LinkedList não é a melhor opção.

Answer (score 7):

Uma instância de `List<>` utiliza, internamente, um *array* para manter as referências aos membros da coleção. Este precisa ser manipulado/redimensionado quando você insere ou remove um item.

Para operações de inserção/remoção, uma `LinkedList<>` é em torno de 100 vezes mais rápida do que uma `List<>`, pois sua mecânica interna apenas referencia itens com os membros mais próximos.

Quando um item é removido, as referências de apenas 2 membros (se o membro retirado estiver entre dois) são atualizadas.

[Fonte da estimativa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880851/what-is-the-performace-difference-in-using-listt-vs-linkedlistt-say-in-the).

Documentação da classe [`LinkedList<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) na MSDN.