# Obter valores do ArraySegment

Tags: c#, .net, array

Ao criar um `ArraySegment`, gostaria de obter o novo *array* criado, mas ao usar:

```
meuSegmento.Array;
```

o *array* original é retornado e não o segmento criado.

```
string[] meuArray = {"stack", "overflow","em", "português"};
var meuSegmento = new ArraySegment<string>(meuArray, 2, (meuArray.Length - 1));
string[] arraySegmentado = meuSegmento.Segmento; //Quero o seguimento criado: { "em", "português" }
```

Comment: meuSegmento.Array era pra estar certo, basicamente conforme mostra aqui http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraysegment

Comment: Primeiro que isso o segundo elemento deveria ser `new ArraySegment<string>(meuArray, 2, (meuArray.Length - 3));`, já que o segundo parâmetro é relativo a quantos elementos a partir do index 2 tu queres pegar.
Segundo para percorrer o ArraySegment só utilizando um for da seguinte forma: `for(var i = segmento.Offset; i < segmento.Count+ segmento.Offset; i++)`. Então, a real utilidade do ArraySegment seria mais para consultas LINQ.

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman, na verdade não, o que o `meuSegmento.Array` retorna, segundo o seu link de referência, é, justamente, o vetor original.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar não entendi, porque a referência dele pra criar o ArraySegment é o vetor original também, ou seja, o meuArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
string[] meuArray = {"stack", "overflow","em", "português"};
var meuSegmento = new ArraySegment<string>(meuArray, 2, (meuArray.Length - 2));
string[] arraySegmentado = meuSegmento.ToArray();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/y4De4G). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YaH1Am). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Segment.cs).

Mas aí fará algo que provavelmente [estava querendo evitar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112530/101). Não existe almoço grátis. Como eu disse lá, talvez a necessidade exija uma estrutura de dados completamente diferente.

Talvez tenha que conviver com a performance baixa. Nem todo problema pode ser resolvido como desejamos. Provavelmente exista uma estrutura adequada, só precisa ver se compensa o trabalho de implementá-la se ela não estiver pronta para a linguagem.

Talvez o problema seja outro e um total replanejamento seja necessário.

Comment: o ToArray() só está disponível na versão do .Net Framework 4.5 em diante, ou também pode ser usado na versão 4? Tentei aqui, mas não tive sucesso!

Comment: Existe desde o 3.5.