# Qual a complexidade de cada uma dessas funções?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Lista circular simples implementada em C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_no{
    float info;
    struct s_no* proximo;
} no_t;

no_t* cria (){
    return NULL;
}

no_t* insere (no_t* l, float v){
    no_t* p = (no_t*) malloc(sizeof(no_t));
    p->info = v;
    if (l == NULL){
        l = p;
        p->proximo = l;             
    }else{
        no_t *aux = l;
        while (aux->proximo != l){
            aux = aux->proximo;
        }
        aux->proximo = p;
        p->proximo = l;
        l = p;      
    }
    return p;
}

void imprime (no_t* l){
    if (l){
        no_t* q = l;
        do{
            printf("%f\n", q->info);
            q = q->proximo;
        }while (q != l);    
    }
}

void libera (no_t* l){
    no_t* q = l;
    while (q->proximo != l){
        no_t* t = q->proximo;
        free(q);
        q = t;
    }   
}

no_t* retira_inicio(no_t* l, float v){
    if (l == NULL)
        return l;
    if (l == l->proximo){
        free(l);
        return NULL;
    }       
    no_t *p = l;

    while (p != l){
        p = p->proximo;
    }

    no_t *aux = l;

    p->proximo = aux->proximo;

    l = aux->proximo;
    free(aux);
    return l;
}

no_t* retira(no_t* l, float v){
    no_t* ant = NULL;
    no_t *p = l;

    if (l == NULL)
        return l;
    if (p->info == v){

        return retira_inicio(l, v);
    }
    ant = p;
    p = p->proximo;
    while ((p != l) && (p->info != v)){
        ant = p;
        p = p->proximo;
    }
    if (p == l)
        return NULL;
    ant->proximo = p->proximo; 
    free(p);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar um contexto a sua pergunta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando tem um laço andando pelos elementos de uma estrutura de dados já é um grande indício que ela é [linear - O(n)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101). Pode ser linear modificada, por exemplo poderia ser O(n / 2) se você só quer pegar os itens pares (tecnicamente isso não é bem Big O).

Se tiver um laço dentro de outro ela já passa para quadrática - O(n<sup>2</sup>), o que não é o caso.

Claro que é possível ter um laço e a complexidade ser logarítmica - O(log n), depende de como o andamento dos passo se comporta.

Ou o laço não estar aplicado aos elementos, o que poderia deixar a complexidade constante - O(1), bem raro.

Não fiz uma análise profunda e posso ter me enganado, mas parece que todas são lineares. Listas ligadas costumam ter esta complexidade na maioria dos algoritmos aplicáveis (não todos).