# Complexidade de Algoritmos

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Todo algoritmo com complexidade que envolva um "log", tem recursividade envolvida? Tipo: O(n log n). Se não, quando terá "log" em alguma complexidade?

Comment: Explique melhor isso aí.

Comment: acho que esse exemplo não fez muito sentido a pergunta.

Comment: Geralmente os algoritmos que têm complexidade com log(n) é porque envolve busca binária (divide and conquer). Muitos que tem recursividade envolvem essa técnica. Mas não, existem algoritmos com log(n) que não são recursivos, por exemplo encontrar um elemento em um vetor ordenado.

Comment: Olá @SérgioMucciaccia no seu caso você deu um exemplo de algo que poderia ser implementado de forma recursiva, acho que a ideia da pergunta é descobrir algo que não seja possível de fazer de forma recursiva e ainda sim tenha complexidade log(n) ...

Comment: Existe uma implementação de um algoritmo que tem log na complexidade e não tem recursividade envolvida. Logo a afirmativa como foi feita é falsa, pois nem todo algoritmo satisfaz obrigatoriamente essa condição. Bom, isso foi o que eu entendi da pergunta. Agora com a sua interpretação realmente, qualquer algoritmo com log envolvido pode ser implementado com recursividade, então a afirmativa seria verdadeira. Pra mim se pode ser implementado sem recursividade então não tem recursividade envolvida (pode ter mas não necessariamente tem). Mas ai já é questão da interpretação de cada um.

Comment: Um algoritmo O(log n) ou O(n log n) provavelmente é do tipo "dividir e conquistar", que *PODE* ser implementado de forma recursiva, não quer dizer que deva ou precise ser.

Answer (score 2):

O que exatamente é dizer que temos algo com complexidade `log n` ?

Vamos dizer que você tenha uma árvore balanceada com 32 - 1 elementos.

[image: Árvore com 4 níveis]

Essa árvore tem 4 níveis, se você quiser adicionar um novo nível, vai praticamente dobrar seu tamanho (64 - 1 elementos) porém seu tempo de busca cresce a uma razão muito baixa comparada a isso (razão logarítmica), por que agora na pior das hipóteses ao invés de usarmos 4 passos para encontrar o resultado teremos que fazer 5 passos. Comparado com as outras razões de complexidade é um resultado muito bom ([essa pergunta/resposta é uma boa referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-big-o)), aqui você pode ter uma ideia da [complexidade dos algoritmos mais populares](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

---

Agora indo ao ponto da pergunta `log(n)/log(i)` é uma solução com relação à recorrência.

```
f(n) =  f(n/i) + c
```

Acontece toda vez que uma função que pode ser escrita recursivamente onde o tamanho do parametro é dividido por uma constante em cada iteração, como em:

```
funcao(entrada, n){
 //faça algo aqui
 retorne funcao(entrada, n/constante);
}
```

Então então dizemos que a complexidade `θ(log(n))`.

Exemplos:

- Quando você busca em uma [árvore balanceada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_AVL): comece pela raiz, se o valor de `n` for gual retorne o nodo (constante), caso contrário se for menor vá para o lado esquerdo da árvore (tamanho/2), se for maior vá para o lado direito (tamanho/2).
- Exponenciação: `a^n`: caso n = 1 então retorne `a`, caso contrário `a^(n/2)` (eleve `a` à metade de `n`) = b (tamanho `n/2`), multiplique `b` por `b` e volte ao inicio.

[**Traduzida de SO - en**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940819/when-does-a-bigoh-notation-olog-n-occurs)

---

[Fonte 1 + Imagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly)

[Fonte 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152890/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-n-complexity)