# Menor número de movimentos de um cavalo até uma dada casa no Xadrez

Tags: python, lógica

Em um tabuleiro de Xadrez em qualquer casa possuo um Cavalo (representado em vermelho) e terei somente uma outra peça (representada em verde) que o cavalo deve ir até ela:

[image: Um tabuleiro de xadrez com apenas duas peças: uma verde na posição 6G e uma vermelha na posição 4C]

Devo utilizar o caminho mais simples e levar em consideração o movimento do cavalo (em L) e contabilizar os movimentos até chegar no ponto determinado:

Como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: A mesma imagem anterior com dois caminhos enumerados com 1 e 2 respectivamente, um indo da posição da peça vermelha até a posição 5E e outra indo da 5E até a posição da peça verde]

Como posso fazer isso usando python? Tenho em mente que tenho que usar matriz e uma lista como entrada de posição, mas não sei como continuar.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Dado o tamanho do tabuleiro, o [caminho mais curto de Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) não traz vantagens significativas em relação a um [*Breadth-first search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), que é simplesmente uma busca que parte da raíz, e depois vai explorando cada subnível.

Num tabuleiro muito grande, uma busca dessas seria problemática, pois o número de passos e a estrutura para armazenar os nós e o trabalho da busca é exponencial.

Acontece que no caso prático, que é um tabuleiro 8 × 8, as possibilidades são muito limitadas, então em parte dos casos o BFS acaba achando o destino em até menos tempo do que levaríamos para organizar os nós para aplicar o caminho curto de Dijkstra.

O BFS é praticamente uma busca por força-bruta, mas que fica bem otimizada neste caso, com a eliminação das casas já visitadas.

### Ilustrando um pouco melhor

```
C       = cavalo
*       = destino
×       = casas já visitadas, eliminadas da busca, não vão pra lista
numeros = casas que verificaremos no passo atual
          (vão ser os pontos de partida do próximo passo)
?       = casas da lista armazenada no passo anterior, que estamos processando
```

Num primeiro momento, fariamos a busca nas casas numeradas a seguir:

```
· · · · · 1 · 6 
· · · · 2 · · · 
· · · · · · C · 
· · · · 3 · · · 
· · * · · 4 · 5 
· · · · · · · · 
· · · · · · · · 
· · · · · · · ·
```

Como não encontramos o destino:

- guardamos os 6 possíveis destinos em uma lista.
- marcamos os 6 destinos como visitados

Em seguida "movemos" o cavalo para cada uma das casas do passo anterior, e repetimos o procedimento, sempre eliminando as casas já visitadas:

```
· · · · · C · ?   · · 2 · · × 2 ?   · · × · · × × ? 
· · · 1 ? · · 1   · · · × C · · ×   · · · × × 3 · × 
· · · · 1 · × ·   · · 2 · × · × ·   · · × · × · × · 
· · · · ? · · ·   · · · 2 ? 2 · ·   · · · × C × · · 
· · * · · ? · ?   · · * · · ? · ?   · ·[3]· · ? 3 ? 
· · · · · · · ·   · · · · · · · ·   · · · 3 · 3 · · 
· · · · · · · ·   · · · · · · · ·   · · · · · · · · 
· · · · · · · ·   · · · · · · · ·   · · · · · · · ·
```

Por acaso, no cenário da pergunta, encontramos o destino já no passo 2, "subpasso" 3. Nem precisamos testar as últimas casas (subpassos 4, 5 e 6).

O importante aqui é notar que apesar da natureza exponencial do algoritmo, o limite do tabuleiro e o fato de eliminarmos as casas já visitadas tornam a solução um bocado simples (e sempre resolvida numa etapa só). Mesmo que alguns casos levem mais alguns passos, no segundo deles já eliminamos quase metade do tabuleiro.

### Vamos ao código?

Se quiser ir direto pra versão que apenas conta o número de movimentos necessários, veja ao final da resposta. Para facilitar o entendimento do algoritmo fiz uma versão mais complexa que retorna os passos dados, não apenas a contagem.

Confesso que não tenho experiência com Python, provavelmente cometi uma série de deslizes de estilo, e talvez tenha ignorado otimizações óbvias, mas espero que o algoritmo, que é o que nos importa, tenha ficado bem fácil de se acompanhar.

Se tirar os comentários e *debugs de print*™ de dentro da função, vai notar que mesmo com a minha inexperiência, o código ficou extremamente enxuto:

<sub><sup>(eu coloquei os *prints* justamente para que quem for testar possa aferir a eficiência do algoritmo)</sup></sub>

```
def vaiCavalo( origemX, origemY, destinoX, destinoY ):
    # criamos uma matriz 8x8 preenchida com False
    # para anotar as casas ja testadas
    casasTestadas = [[False]*8 for i in range(8)]

    # todos os movimentos possiveis do cavalo
    movimentos = [[-1,-2],[-2,-1],[-2,1],[-1,2],[1,2],[2,1],[2,-1],[1,-2]]

    # o primeiro passo e a origem do cavalo
    # X, Y e caminho percorrido ate entao (vazio no comeco)
    passos = [[origemX, origemY,[]]]

    while True:
        proximosPassos = []
        for passo in passos:
            print("Cavalo atualmente em [", passo[0], ",", passo[1], "], vindo de", passo[2])

            # vamos testar todos os movimentos possiveis a partir deste passo
            for movimento in movimentos:
                x = passo[0]+movimento[0]
                y = passo[1]+movimento[1]

                # armazenamos o caminho feito ate chegar aqui
                caminho = list(passo[2])
                caminho.append([passo[0],passo[1]])

                # o cavalo chegou ao destino, retornamos o caminho completo
                if x == destinoX and y == destinoY:
                    print("  PRONTO! Chegamos em [", x, y, "]")
                    caminho.append([x,y])
                    return caminho

                # senao, armazenamos a posicao para a proxima rodada
                elif 0 <= x < 8 and 0 <= y < 8 and not casasTestadas[x][y]:
                    print("  Destino nao encontrado em [", x, y, "], coordenadas na pilha")
                    proximosPassos.append([x,y,caminho])

                    # vamos descartar novas tentativas partindo daqui
                    casasTestadas[x][y] = True

        # todos os passos realizados, vamos para os seguintes
        passos = proximosPassos

print("\nCaminho feito:", vaiCavalo(3, 2, 3, 3))
```

Veja o cavalo em ação no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/5c2SpA)**.

### O mesmo código, sem firulas

Para comparação, segue versão simplificada e reorganizada do código acima.

Quase a mesma coisa, basicamente sem os comentários e *prints*, e com algumas coisas *inline*, mas ainda retornando todos os passos:

```
def vaiCavalo( origem, destino ):
   casasTestadas = [[False]*8 for i in range(8)]
   passos = [origem+[[]]]

   while True:
      proximosPassos = []
      for passo in passos:
         for movimento in [[-1,-2],[-2,-1],[-2,1],[-1,2],[1,2],[2,1],[2,-1],[1,-2]]:
            x,y = passo[0]+movimento[0], passo[1]+movimento[1]
            if [x,y] == destino:
               return passo[2]+[[x,y]]
            if 0 <= x < 8 and 0 <= y < 8 and not casasTestadas[x][y]:
               proximosPassos.append([x,y,passo[2]+[[x,y]]])
               casasTestadas[x][y] = True
      passos = proximosPassos
```

Também no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Xv17p6)**.

E, finalmente, como pede a pergunta, apenas a contagem:

```
def vaiCavalo( origem, destino ):
   casasTestadas = [[False]*8 for i in range(8)]
   passos = [origem+[0]]

   while True:
      proximosPassos = []
      for passo in passos:
         for movimento in [[-1,-2],[-2,-1],[-2,1],[-1,2],[1,2],[2,1],[2,-1],[1,-2]]:
            x,y = passo[0]+movimento[0], passo[1]+movimento[1]
            if [x,y] == destino:
               return passo[2]+1
            if 0 <= x < 8 and 0 <= y < 8 and not casasTestadas[x][y]:
               proximosPassos.append([x,y,passo[2]+1])
               casasTestadas[x][y] = True
      passos = proximosPassos
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
movimentosNecessarios = vaiCavalo([1,1],[1,2])
```

E, é claro, mais um **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rANtZK)**.

Vale a pena uma lida **[nesta versão](http://ideone.com/fRCVDu)** do algoritmo acima, com um formato bem mais Acadêmico, deixada gentilmente pelo colega @JJoao, que fez uma implementação com `queue`/`deque`. Ficou bem elegante o código, por sinal.

#### Nota:

Não faz parte do problema, mas é interessante notar que o cavalo não se move em "L" de fato. O "L" é uma forma de facilitar para o aprendiz entender aonde é que o cavalo pode ir. O cavalo se move direto para o destino, como qualquer outra peça. Apenas acontece da "linha reta" dele não coincidir com o alinhamento do tabuleiro.

[image: Linha reta do cavalo]

Comment: Bacco só mais uma questão: eu esperava um queue em vez de uma pilha (como uma pilha parecia-me que acabaria por ser depth-first)

Comment: E eis outra grande resposta. :) +1. P.S.: Eu ri alto com o "vaiCavalo". hahahaha

Comment: @bacco, em http://ideone.com/dfLaQb simulei uma fila (funções inqueue, dequeue, if(q) ) e fiz uma reescrita do teu algortimo com queues. Embora quase igual, é próxima da forma genérica de Breath-first de graphos.

Comment: @JJoao grato, acho interessante até para eu conhecer melhor algo de quem tem experiência. Eu fui por um caminho mais simplório até porque queria fazer tudo autocontido (sem import, inclusive), e retornar o caminho feito era um dos objetivos, apesar de não estar na pergunta. Vou ler seu código com calma, e aprender os conceitos, muito grato! Depois faço uma referência na resposta, caso você não queira referenciar na sua.

Comment: só um disclaimer: eu não tenho experiência de python (a nivel de scripting, eu gosto mesmo é de Perl) estou agora a aprender (daí o visitar perguntas de python ☺,  e tentar experimentar alternativas)

Comment: @JJoao tem algumas coisas na sua sintaxe que eu gostei um bocado, e provavelmente teria adotado se eu tivesse pensado um pouco melhor. A idéia de pegar dx e dy diretamente fica realmente mais legível, por exemplo. Tem vários detalhes interessantes que eu gostei. Pra falar a verdade, entendi que seu foco foi a representação acadêmica do BFS, mas o que eu mais gostei foram os detalhes em torno :) - Confesso que meu código acima foi meu primeiro algoritmo em Py, o resto foi basicamente coisa muito elementar com PyQt, só pra saber a "cara" do treco.

Comment: Eu estou na mesma circunstância... confesso que desconhecia quase tudo (por exemplo `0 < x <= 8` ) ou o `[False * 8]` que evidentemente roubei para a minha solução :) . Aparentemente em python o principio geral de "se fosse eu a desenhar a linguagem como que sintaxe escolheria?" vai funcionando...

Answer (score 25):

Um possível algoritmo envolve a minimização da distância entre o cavalo e a peça-alvo até capturá-lo. Tente fazer assim:

1. Na posição atual, o cavalo tem apenas um número limitado de casas para as quais ele pode ir. Obtenha essas casas (sugestão: varra a vizinhança considerando os "retângulos" formados pelo L do movimento).
2. Calcule a distância de cada uma dessas casas até a casa da peça-alvo (sobre distâncias, [leia essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166732/73), qualquer uma é válida como heurística, mas a euclidiana gera resultados melhores). Ordene-as da menor para a maior distância.
3. Itere sobre essa lista ordenada (isto é, da menor para a maior distância). Se a distância da casa atual da iteração for 0, você chegou na solução. Senão, se for menor do que 2, desconsidere<sup>*</sup> a casa e vá para a próxima (pois pular para ali não vai ajudar, já que vai ficar próximo demais do alvo, sem alcançá-lo). Caso contrário, você encontrou a melhor jogada no momento, então mova o cavalo para essa casa e volte ao passo 1 (repetindo até encontrar a solução).

Você vai precisar usar alguma lista auxiliar para verificar se uma "jogada" já foi feita, de forma a evitar loops infinitos de repetição. Certamente esse não é o melhor algoritmo, mas pode ao menos te ajudar a ter um caminho inicial para resolver o seu problema.

> <sup>*</sup> Como o colega @JJoao [bem
>   comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169418/menor-n%c3%bamero-de-movimentos-de-um-cavalo-at%c3%a9-uma-dada-casa-no-xadrez/169438?noredirect=1#comment351816_169438),
>   há de ter cuidado com situações restritivas, como as em que todas as
>   opções disponíveis estão muito próximas (distância menor do que 2) e
>   ainda assim não se chegou ao alvo. Nesse caso, uma boa heurística pode
>   ser inverter o comportamento, e assim tentar se afastar do alvo nas
>   próximas 2 jogadas (de forma a criar mais liberdade de movimento).
>   Vale relembrar que esse algoritmo que eu propus é bastante heurístico
>   e serve principalmente pra te ajudar a compreender o problema. Ele
>   **não é** a melhor implementação. Você já recebeu outras sugestões (em outras respostas), e uma das melhores abordagens envolve a busca em um
>   grafo do espaço de estados do jogo (ou, mais eficientemente ainda, diretamente no tabuleiro [considerando as casas como nós do grafo e as arestas conectando os movimentos possíveis do cavalo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170616/73)).

Comment: Luiz Vieira, a estrutura geral do problema parece-me boa (+1), mas neste caso (saltos de cavalo) a distancia pode ser um pouco significativa. O ponto 3 parece-me que tem algumas condições demasiado restritivas: Por exemplo origem=1A, destino 2B:  [1A, 2C, 1E, 3D, 2B]  obriga a passos intermédios a uma distancia de 1

Comment: @JJoao Sim, você tem toda a razão. Eu fiz uma edição para incluir essa sua observação. Obrigado pela informação! :)

Comment: Luiz Vieira, claramente ver o tabuleiro como um grafo ou uma árvore de soluções permite eficiências muito maior, e está implicito da tua proposta inicial. Na minha solução, a opção de criar um grafo explicito foi principlamente porque eu estou a aprende python e nunca tinha experimentado o igraph. -- decisão muito científica :)

Comment: @JJoao Sem sombra de dúvida usar um grafo é mais eficiente. Aliás, eu não conhecia o igraph, por isso gostei também da sua resposta. Mas eu só tentei uma abordagem puramente heurística porque achei que era mais fácil para o AP entender o problema e a sua resolução.

Answer (score 15):

Estratégia proposta:

- ver este problema como procurar caminho num grafo: nós = posições no tabuleiro; ramos = saltos do cavalo;
- calcular a lista de todos os saltos de cavalo (=ramos) -- lista em compreensão;
- com base nela construir o grafo (=g)
- procurar o caminho mais curto nesse grafo

ou seja

```
from igraph import *

ramos=[ ( a*10+b , (a+dx)*10+b+dy )
    for a in range(1,9)                        ## 1 .. 8
    for b in range(1,9)                        ## a .. h
    for dx,dy in [(1,-2),(2,-1),(1,2),(2,1)]   ## delta do movimento do cavalo
    if 0 < a+dx <= 8 and 0 < b+dy <= 8 ]       ## nao sai borda-fora

g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(89)
g.add_edges(ramos)

print(g.get_shortest_paths(43, to=67, mode=OUT, output="vpath"))
```

Por preguiça traduziu-se as abcissas para números (4C => 43 e  6G => 67).
Executando dá:

```
[[43, 55, 67]]
```

**Update** : explicação adicional (\thanks{Luiz Vieira})

Desculpem, admito que o cálculo dos ramos ficou bastante críptica.

- Na realidade o modulo igraph usa como numeração de vértices números
  inteiros contíguos (eu queria pares de coordenadas). Se usarmos simplesmente
  um inteiro seguido para cada vértice, o cálculo dos saltos e a leitura do
  caminho final fica complicada de ler...
- A solução escolhida foi, durante a criação dos ramos, considerar
  cada vértice como um par ordenado (exemplo (6,7))
  e no final convertê-lo para inteiro, justapondo os dígitos (6*10+7).
  "ramos" fica com : `[(13, 21), (14, 22), (15, 23), (16, 24), ...]`
- Isto leva a que o conjunto dos vértices varia de 11 até ao 88 mas que não
  estejam a ser usados os vértices contendo "0" ou "9" (daí a estranha
  declaração de 89 vértices...)
- Tratando-se de um grafo não orientado, basta considerar metade dos
  saltos possíveis (daí que o delta de salto - só contenha 4 pares que
  sobem no tabuleiro)
- A condição "if" da lista em compreensão é para garantir que o
  cavalo não salte para fora do tabuleiro

Se necessário, instalar python-igraph.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Já ganhou o meu +1! Mas, se me permite o comentário: a preguiça foi ruim. A criação da lista de arestas (a variável `ramos` e a explicação de por que são 89 vértices) é parte importante do entendimento. Poderia explicar ela com um pouquinho mais de detalhe pra ajudar o AP e outros leitores futuros (talvez postar um exemplo do conteúdo gerado?). Nesse caso, eu realmente acho que essa resposta é a merecedora da aceitação e da recompensa. :)

Comment: Show! Se eu pudesse dava mais um +1. :) @GuilhermeLima, sugiro aceitar (e premiar) esta resposta.

Comment: @LuizVieira, eu estava a ver se me safava com uma resposta de magia negra perguiçosa: obrigado por não deixares passar :)

Answer (score 3):

Não sou expert em python, mas tenho uma pequena noção de teoria de grafos. Este tipo de problema pode ser resolvido utilizando o [Algoritmo de Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra). Segundo a Wikipedia, ele é utilizado para o seguinte:

> Um exemplo prático do problema que pode ser resolvido pelo algoritmo de Dijkstra é: alguém precisa se deslocar de uma cidade para outra. Para isso, ela dispõe de várias estradas, que passam por diversas cidades. Qual delas oferece uma trajetória de menor caminho?

Eu fiz uma pesquisa rápida na internet e achei um código capaz de te ajudar [neste link](https://gist.github.com/econchick/4666413). Não testei ele, então não posso te dizer se funciona ou não. Mas fica a sugestão de pesquisa.

Answer (score 1):

Levando em consideração um pouco do que todos falaram cheguei a isso:
Gostaria da opniao e se estaria correto a logica que usei:

```
distancia = {}
caminho = {}

def movimento():
    inicio = 3,2
    fim = 8,8

    fila = [inicio]
    distancia[inicio] = 0
    caminho[inicio] = 1

    while len(fila):
        atual = fila[0]
        fila.pop(0)
        if atual == fim:
            print "Possivel ir em %d movimentos"%(distancia[atual])
            return

        for movimento in [ (1,2),(2,1),(-1,-2),(-2,-1),(1,-2),(-1,2),(-2,1),(2,-1) ]:
            prox_mov = atual[0]+movimento[0], atual[1]+movimento[1]
            if prox_mov[0] > fim[0] or prox_mov[1] > fim[1] or prox_mov[0] < 1 or prox_mov[1] < 1:
                continue
            if prox_mov in distancia and distancia[prox_mov] == distancia[atual]+1:
                caminho[prox_mov] += caminho[atual]
            if prox_mov not in distancia:
                distancia[prox_mov] = distancia[atual] + 1
                caminho[prox_mov] = caminho[atual]
                fila.append(prox_mov)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    movimento()
```

> Possivel ir em 5 movimentos

Answer (score 1):

Sem responder a pergunta, mas tentando contribuir com o tópico, eu fiz uma função que inicializa os movimentos do cavalo, tornando as próximas etapas mais rápidas

## Calcula Destino para o cavalo a partir de uma coordenada [l,c]

```
#dadas as direçoes em X e em Y e a chave k=[1,2]
def  R(c,l,i=-1,j=-1,k=2):
    #c=Origem.Coluna, l=Origem.Linha
    #i,j=[-1,1]=[move p traz ou p cima,move p frente ou p baixo]
    m=l+i*k #Destino.Linha
    n=c+j*(3-k) #Destino.Coluna
    if m in xrange(8)and n in xrange(8):
        return m,n
    else: 
        return () #O cavalo está no canto

def  Init_Map():
    A=xrange(8)
    B=[-1,1]
    matrix={}
    for c in A:
        for l in A:
            matrix[l,c]= [R(c,l,i,j,k1)  for i in B for j in B for k1 in [1,2]]
    return matrix
```

---

**`MAP=Init_Map()`**

---

```
#A variável map ficará na memoria com todos movimentos do cavalo possíveis-
print MAP
```

{
 - (0, 0): [(1, 2), (2, 1)], 
 - (0, 1): [ (2, 0), (1, 3), (2, 2)], 
 - (0, 2): [(1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 4), (2, 3)], 
 - (0, 3): [(1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 5), (2, 4)], 
 - ...]}

```
    #· · · · · 1 · 6 
    #· · · · 2 · · · 
    #· · · · · · C · 
    #· · · · 3 · · · 
    #· · * · · 4 · 5 
    #· · · · · · · · 
    #· · · · · · · · 
    #· · · · · · · · 

#Estando o cavalo em [2,6] ou em qualquer coordenada[l,c] basta fazer
print 'C[2,6]=', MAP[2,6]
```

C[2,6]= [(1, 4), (0, 5),  (0, 7), (3, 4), (4, 5),  (4, 7)]

Answer (score -1):

Eu já fiz algo parecido num trabalho final de curso, era um mapa de biblioteca que tinha uma origem, que seria o computador onde estava sendo acessado o sistema, e o destino o livro na prateleira. Mas da pra usar a mesma ideia que tive, é simples mas funcionou.

É o seguinte, construa uma matriz 8x8 representando seu tabuleiro, na posição de origem coloque 1, no destino e nas outras posições deixe com 0.

A partir daí, enquanto a posição de destino estiver com 0, faça o movimento dos cavalos a partir de 1 e coloque 2 nas posições possíveis. Guarde as posições numa estrutura de mapa, onde o 2 é a chave e as posições você guarda uma lista delas na parte do valor... depois pegue essa lista das posições 2 e movimente o cavalo colocando 3 e guardando e assim vai.

Uma hora o destino estará preenchido, e aí é só fazer o caminho reverso, por exemplo o destino ficou com 3, procure pelos 2 que podem chegar até ele e depois pelo 1.

Comment: Voce poderia colocar um código em python para fazer isso

Answer (score -2):

```
p=(5, 3)
s=(1, 1)
def f(x,y):x=abs(x);y=abs(y);s=x+y;return(.9+max(x/4,y/4,s/6)-s/2+(s==1or x==y==2))//1*2+s
print(int(f(s[0]-p[0],s[1]-p[1])))
```