# Há alguma maneira mais otimizada de "multiplicar" uma string sem usar repetição?

Tags: javascript, string

Estou criando um algoritmo em JavaScript, e já estou achando ele muito pesado.
Agora preciso de uma string "multiplicada" N vezes. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso sem usar uma repetição.

Por exemplo, para o algoritmo retornar "palavra " 5x em uma única string:

```
var str = "palavra "
i = 0
j = 3;

while ( i < j){
    str = str+"palavra ";
    i++
}
return str
// o script retorna "palavra palavra palavra palavra palavra"
```

Esse tipo de algoritmo irá ser executada diversas vezes no programa, é importante que seja mais otimizado, se possível.

Comment: Por definição não tem como, o que pode ser feito é usar uma função que faça isto por você, conforme a resposta do Isac mostra.

Comment: Que seria `mais otimizado`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, pode usar o método [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) de `string`, que recebe como parâmetro a quantidade de vezes a repetir.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var str = "palavra ";
console.log(str.repeat(5));
```

Assim como indicado pelo amigo @LeoCaracciolo não funciona no Internet Explorer (como já seria de esperar). Se precisar de compatibilidade especifica para essa versão pode usar o *polyfill* que está na pagina da [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).

### Performance

Já sabemos que `.repeat()` é bem mais curto, mas e será que a performance é diferente em termos de velocidade de execução ?

É de facto, o `repeat` é bem mais eficiente, embora só se note para quantidades grandes de repetições. Por isso se analisarmos os dois lado a lado para `5` repetições por exemplo, o tempo de execução é basicamente o mesmo:

**Comparando para 5 repetições**:

```
Código 1 - `repeat`                      |  Código 2 - concatenação

var resultado = str.repeat(repeticoes);  |  var resultado = "";
                                         |  for (var i = 0; i < repeticoes; ++i){
                                         |      resultado += str;
                                         |  }
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Resultado: 100%                          |  Resultado 97%
```

Aqui dá para ver que na vez que eu executei, o código de concatenação normal foi mais rápido 3%.

[Veja este teste no jsben](http://jsben.ch/qXvTW)
<sub>Cada teste pode variar ligeiramente, por isso é aconselhável que corra o teste algumas vezes para ter uma ideia mais realista da comparação</sub>

**Comparando para 5000 repetições**:

```
Código 1 - `repeat`                      |  Código 2 - concatenação
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Resultado: 1%                            |  Resultado 100%
```

[Veja estes resultados também no jsben](http://jsben.ch/zmZqv)

Aqui já vê uma diferença bem grande na execução dos dois.

Este [mesmo teste no jsperf](https://jsperf.com/repeat-vs-concatenation/1) dá resultados idênticos com descrição de quantas vezes executou. Na minha máquina obtive:

```
Código 1 - `repeat`                        |  Código 2 - concatenação
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Resultado: 0%                              |  Resultado 100% mais lento
Execuções: 2,951,175                       |  Execuções: 12,281
```

Quando olhamos para a quantidade de execuções vemos que é uma diferença abismal.
Como é possível que seja assim tanto ? Tem a ver com o algoritmo em si.

**Algoritmo**

Ao contrário do que poderíamos pensar, o algoritmo base para o `repeat` não é ir concatenando palavra a palavra até formar o resultado pretendido, em que isso teria uma complexidade de `O(N)` sendo o `N` o número de repetições.

A solução utilizada tem complexidade `O(log2(n))`, que pode ser descrito da seguinte forma:

- Apenas o último bit da variável que tem o número de repetições é interpretado
- Quando o ultimo bit é `1` concatena a palavra ao resultado
- Em cada passo descarta o `ultimo` bit da variável repetições e "dobra" a palavra. Se a palavra era `"palavra "`, passa a ficar `"palavra palavra"`

Esta lógica faz com que precise de bem menos concatenações, pois a palavra que está a ser concatenada vai aumentando.

Confuso ? Um exemplo de execução para `"palavra ", 5` seria:

```
        | num(bin) | str                                | resultado  | ação
inicio  | 5(101)   | "palavra "                         |  ""        |   
passo 1 | 5(101)   | "palavra "                         | "palavra " | concatena, descarta o `1` dobra `str`
passo 2 | 2(10)    | "palavra palavra "                 | "palavra " | não concatena, descarta o `0` e dobra `str`
passo 3 | 1(1)     | "palavra palavra palavra palavra " | "palavra " | concatena, descarta o único bit, e dobra `str`
final   | 0(0)     |  ...                               | "palavra palavra palavra palavra palavra "
```

Neste pequeno exemplo de execução a palavra foi concatenada uma vez no inicio, depois foi dobrada duas vezes, ficando `"palavra palavra palavra palavra "` e só no fim foi concatenada de novo com o `resultado` formando o resultado pretendido.

**Implementação**:

```js
function stringRepeat(str, num) {
  num = Number(num);

  var result = '';
  while (true) {
    if (num & 1) {
      result += str;
    }
    num >>>= 1;
    if (num <= 0) break;
    str += str;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(stringRepeat("palavra ", 5));
```

[Fonte deste código](http://2ality.com/2014/01/efficient-string-repeat.html)

### Conclusão

Sempre que tiver funções nativas que fazem o que pretende deve utiliza-las pois não só elas são bem mais curtas a nível de extensão de código, como podem ser muito mais performáticas, devido a utilizarem algoritmos que nem está a imaginar!

Comment: Nossa, bem simples e eu não conhecia. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Seria bom informar a compatibilidade dos navegadores, parece não funcionar no IE

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim é verdade, Obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Há uma forma bem mais rápida de multiplicar uma string: `5*string` (multiplica por 5) rss :P

Comment: @dvd em Python isso funciona. https://ideone.com/lXm0RG

Comment: @dvd, não funciona com javascript?

Comment: @Bacco Jesuis!! rs

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Claro que não funciona né! :p

Comment: @DVD veja essa linha `casasTestadas = [[False]*8 for i in range(8)]`  Nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170854/70 - Usei a multiplicação pra fazer 8 x 8 variáveis false. Só não fiz [[false]*8]*8 diretamente, com receio de gerar um array por referência, por isso o range.

Comment: @Bacco Não entendo nada de Python... pra mim é um tipo de .. rss

Comment: Esse código demonstra o "problema": https://ideone.com/ZL3Xl5 - Quando o 2o nivel de array é gerado, são criadas 8 referências para o mesmo array de 8 ítens, e não 8 clones independentes. Ao mudar um deles, isso reflete nos outros 7 ponteiros. Com a sintaxe do range, são "executadas" 8 criações.

Answer (score 0):

**Restou a duvida do que seria `que seja mais otimizado`.**

> Seria talvez no significado do contexto abaixo?

Por que `otimizar` nossos Sites é tão importante? Simplesmente porque nenhum usuário gosta de perder tempo esperando o carregamento das páginas. É extremamente irritante.

> Para tanto, basta rodar os exemplos abaixo e tirar as próprias conclusões

```js
var timer = function(name) {
    var start = new Date();
    return {
        stop: function() {
            var end  = new Date();
            var time = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            console.log('Timer:', name, 'finished in', time, 'ms');
        }
    }
};

function repeat(s,n) { return Array(n+1).join(s); }

var t = timer('Benchmark'); // <-- START BENCHMARK
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
repeat("boo", 40);
t.stop();  // <-- STOP BENCHMARK
```

```js
var timer = function(name) {
    var start = new Date();
    return {
        stop: function() {
            var end  = new Date();
            var time = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            console.log('Timer:', name, 'finished in', time, 'ms');
        }
    }
};

var repeat = function(str, count) {
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= count;)
        array[i++] = str;
    return array.join('');
}

var t = timer('Benchmark'); 
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
repeat("boo", 40);
t.stop();
```

Comment: Sim, já estou usando um timer para testar o tempo de execução.
O algoritmo é bem extenso, pois trata-se de uma espécie de pequeno programa online, onde o usuário insere certos dados e recebe um arquivo completo com eles. Outrora, para um mesmo efeito demorava 15 minutos (isso mesmo, 15 minutos, muita coisa), fiz algumas modificações incluindo essa do 'repeat' e agora está demorando 2 minutos. Uma redução de 87%. Ainda acho muito, 2 minutos, e estou trabalhando para melhorar ainda mais...