# Melhor performance para poucos acessos: HashMap ou TreeMap?

Tags: java, desempenho, estrutura-de-dados, map

Eu costumo usar bastante a estrutura `java.util.HashMap<K,V>` mesmo para escopos pequenos com poucas entradas (até umas 50). Mas andei me perguntando se a estrutura `java.util.TreeMap<K,V>` não seria melhor para essa situação, levando em consideração que o `HashMap` é implementado sobre uma *hashtable* em que o cálculo do *hash* é potencialmente caro, em termos de tempo de processamento? Já a `TreeMap` é implementada sobre árvore e faz operações com ponteiros, o que potencialmente levaria a uma melhor performance (tempo de escrita/leitura).

Isso faz sentido? Para simplificar podemos considerar aplicações sem concorrência.

Comment: São usos diferentes. `TreeMap` foi idealizado para quando você quer percorrer o mapa seguindo uma ordem natural, como a alfabética no caso de chaves `Strings`. `HashMap` é percorrido em ordem aleatória e quando não há excesso de colisões costuma ser rápido, como é dito na resposta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para poucos acessos tanto faz. Performance é um problema mesmo quando se faz em volume muito grande.

De fato a quantidade de entradas pode fazer diferença. Não é tão simples responder preto no branco, é cinza mesmo. Se eu te falar para medir achará como é o desempenho com aqueles dados, não para qualquer caso. A arquitetura que está rodando e a infraestrutura disponível pode dar diferença.

[Tabelas *hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101) tem o problema da coincidência de valores calculados e o que era [complexidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101) O(1) pode virar um O(n), ainda que esse é um caso extremo que não acontecerá de fato.

Outra questão é que o cálculo do [*hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356435/101) depende do dado que está sendo usado como chave, então o tempo total não é tão constante assim (a constância dita é sobre a busca, não a preparação dela), muito menos dá para antecipar sem saber qual é ele.

Na maioria dos casos ele deve ser mais rápido.

A árvore tem complexidade O(log n) e para poucos dados o logaritmo de N tende ser muito próximo de 1, sem ter o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) do cálculo. De fato ele pode ser mais rápido, mas na prática é difícil que seja.

No [SO tem uma resposta com testes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23608250/221800), talvez possa pegá-lo para testar com seus dados, lá claramente a `HashMap` ganhou.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Com `HashMap` você terá **O(1)** para acesso na maioria das vezes. Depende do número de colisões, e que devido ao baixo número de dados não será o caso.

Enquanto com o TreeMap para acesso é **O(log n)**, tendo em vista que utiliza uma árvore binária balanceada.

Se a ordenação dos dados para busca não for essencial acredito que **HashMap** seja mais rápido nesse caso.