# Diferença entre HashMap e TreeMap

Tags: java, hashmap, map

Quais as principais diferenças entre `HashMap` e `TreeMap`? Em relação ao uso, em quais situações é recomendado o uso de cada uma?

Comment: [Isto pode te ajudar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444359/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hashmap-and-a-treemap). Veja o retorno do [Sírius] e [TM.]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) é uma estrutura de dados baseada em espalhamento através de uma função de cálculo *hash* de uma informação chave do objeto a ser colocado na coleção de dados. Você tem sempre uma chave que é calculada e um valor associado a ela. O acesso é sempre feito pela chave. A forma de acesso é sempre muito rápida e pode, na maioria dos casos ter complexidade de tempo de acesso qualquer constante (O(1)). Não pode ter chaves duplicatas e não mantém um ordem específica, é considerada não ordenada.

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) é uma coleção de dados parecida com a `HashMap` onde o acesso aos elementos tem complexidade de tempo de acesso logarítmico (O(log n)), o que é muito próximo do tempo constante mesmo em grandes volumes, e ao contrário do `HashMap`, não corre o risco dos piores casos serem bem lentos. Permite chaves duplicatas e mantém uma classificação das chaves. Se precisa de pelo menos uma dessas duas características deve escolhê-la.

Veja mais em [Melhor performance para poucos acessos: HashMap ou TreeMap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179852/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).