# Como melhorar o desempenho de meu código com "for"?

Tags: algoritmo, loop, desempenho, estrutura-de-dados, otimização

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < 20; $j++) { 
        for ($p=0; $p < 40; $p++) { 
            echo $vaar[$i][$j][$p];
        }
    }
}
```

Acredito que um código que contém um `for` dentro de outro é um algoritmo ineficiente, minha pergunta é existe uma maneira de percorrer minha variável `$vaar`, sem ser utilizando esses 3 `for`? em diversos sistemas acabei optando por esse tipo de escrita de código pois não sabia outra maneira de otimizar meu *script*.

Comment: Depende do que deseja, se deseja pegar um item especifico poderia simplificar muito ou se deseja exibir todos mesmo não tem o que fazer, o desempenho é sempre relativo, geralmente se não tem nenhuma operação dentro de cada loop, exceto exibir será rápido, mesmo com 3 fors.

Comment: Se a sua variável é tridimensional e você quer imprimir todos os valores, é desse jeito mesmo. Mas os loops são curtos, você está tendo algum problema de performance?

Comment: na realidade preciso complementar minha pergunta então, pois eu apenas exemplifiquei em micro escala, mas no meu problema real, são 4 fors e cada um faz alguma coisa com os valores dos vetores

Comment: Bom, o desempenho disso vai depender do tamanho do vetor e das operações que você faz com cada item. Mas se precisa acessar todos os itens, precisa aninhar os `for` mesmo, não tem outro jeito.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neste exemplo não tem muito o que fazer. Você quer mostrar 8000 itens, não importa o que faça terá que imprimir 8000 itens e isso é custo alto.

Talvez em uma estrutura diferente, que você não tem, poderia ter um ganho mínimo se conseguisse acessar de forma plana, mas nem compensaria. E PHP não é linguagem para isso. O ganho seria marginal. Isso é uma complexidade linear O(n), não importa o que faça.

A complexidade parece ser pior por causa da multiplicação aparente, mas na verdade a estrutura tem todos os itens do *array* todo, as dimensões são apenas partições do todo, a complexidade tem que ser medida pelo todo.

Se tivesse que pegar um item dentre esses 8000 aí teria bastante o que fazer, podendo até conseguir complexidade constante O(1). Mas é possível que precisaria usar uma estrutura diferente, mas não é algo que o PHP seja bom. Dependendo do requisito e das garantias da estrutura, se não der O(1), poderia dar complexidade logarítmica O(log n).

O(1) e O(log n) são ótimos para grandes volumes (para pequenos pode ser até pior na prática), mas muitos algoritmos só podem ser feitos em O(n) mesmo. Qualquer coisa que exija o acesso ao todo terá no mínimo complexidade linear, não importa o que faça. A não ser, é claro, que os dados possam ser obtidos de forma procedural, mas aí não está acessando dados de uma estrutura e sim calculando o resultado baseado em uma fórmula. Mesmo se isso fosse possível no algoritmo da pergunta ainda seria linear.

Se tem 1000 x 1000 x 1000 x 1000 itens, você tem 1 trilhão de itens para avaliar em algoritmo que precisa de todos eles, não tem o que fazer, computador e matemática não fazem milagre.

Se tiver um algoritmo quadrático O(n<sup>2</sup>) costuma ser ruim, mas nada não administrável até uma certa quantidade de itens (milhares ou até milhões). Ficará ruim, mas dá para trabalhar. Tem muitos estudos para evitar chegar aqui porque "muitos" problemas parecem ter essa necessidade.

Começa ser um problema em complexidade exponencial O(2<sup>n</sup>) onde apenas 100 itens produzirá um algoritmo que precisa fazer 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376 (mais de 1 nonilhão) operações. Isso é brutal. Para dar um parâmetro um processador faz menos de 1 bilhão de operações muito simples por segundo. Em qualquer coisa realista um computador levaria anos ou séculos para processar isso. Você não conseguiria pensar no número com 1000 itens.

Só a complexidade fatorial O(n!) é pior que isto, onde em cada passo aumenta a distância do passo. Aí o que comece mais tranquilo, rapidamente se torna inviável. 100 daria 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000. É perto de um [googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol).

[image: Complexidade de algoritmo]

Tirando as complexidades que devem ser evitados de todas as formas possíveis dá para ver melhor as diferenças entre o que realmente acontece.

[image: O(1) O(log n) O(N) O(n log n)]

Ver [Big O](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101) de onde tirei as imagens.

Provavelmente acredita que laços aninhados são um problema porque acredita em "boas práticas", ou seja, acha que existem regras que sempre seguidas resolvem todos os problemas. Na verdade tudo depende de contexto.

Você até pode melhorar muito ligeiramente a performance se fizer a estrutura ficar plana (uma dimensão) porque teria um laço. Isso não diminuirá a complexidade do algoritmo, mas trará um ganho mínimo. Otimizações não devem dar ganhos mínimos, a não ser em casos muitos específicos. Os ganhos com a redução da complexidade são muito mais importantes, e nesse caso não tem como reduzir a complexidade, nem mesmo aceitando alguma outra desvantagem, a não ser que tenha algo no conjunto de dados que permita alguma otimização específica, o que é muito raro ocorrer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 12):

Aprofundando [a resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268308/64969), na questão de complexidade.

Complexidade assintótica é muita coisa, mas não é tudo. Complexidade assintótica depende de variáveis, ela é anotada de acordo com a entrada. Então, esse valor pode ser "falsificado" dependendo de como você pega essa variável.

Peguemos o seguinte laço, que lê as propriedades de um cubo:

```
elementos = d*d*d;
for (i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
  x = i % d;
  y = (i/d)%d;
  z = (i/d)/d;
  imprime(cubo[x][y][z]);
}
```

Então o seu algoritmo roda em tempo linear, correto? Bem, roda linear sobre a variável `elementos`, mas como você recebe um cubo, é muito mais provável que sua preocupação seja com `d^3`.

> Aqui, um algoritmo que seja quadrático na quantidade de elementos (como um algoritmo ordenação mais simples) tornaria a vida do programa que percorre o cubo de dados **muito** mais complicado.

O que aconteceu aqui foi que a complexidade foi "falsificada" para se assemelhar a ser linear. Algumas pessoas acabam fazendo coisas semelhantes para reduzir a "complexidade aparente" da operação.

No caso, o @Maniero demonstrou na resposta que, para cada elemento percorrido, você faz `o(1)` operações. Isso significa que, no conjunto de elementos de tamanho `n` é um algoritmo linear. Porém, analisando sob a perspectiva de dados armazenados num cubo de informação, o tamanho `n` é `o(d^3)`.

---

Para se ter uma ideia de como olhar para a variável distinta afeta a complexidade, olha esse exemplo:

> some dois números (base arbitrária), `N` e `M`, cada um com `n` dígitos

A soma tem complexidade `o(n)`, mas também `o(log N)`. ( Fonte: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations )

Como aqui o número de dígitos para representar um número é o logaritmo desse número na base sendo representada, isso deve ser levada em consideração. Fica muito mais sincero e visível você falar que o custo da soma é linear na quantidade de dígitos.

---

Você pode obter ganhos consideráveis usando a localidade espacial. Não sei como foi implementado essa sua matriz, mas se ela foi implementada como um *jagged array* (um vetor, que por sua vez cada elemento contém um vetor, este último contendo cada elemento um vetor de números, cada um com seu tamanho individual), é de se esperar que esses dados não estão contíguos. Se não estão contíguos, então eles podem estar espalhados na memória de memória aleatória, e isso não é bom.

Por que não é bom? Porque você terá uma garantia menor do uso da localidade espacial das suas variáveis. Como uma otimização do processador que usa *caches* em diversos níveis, normalmente são carregadas para o *cache* as últimas variáveis usadas (localidade temporal) e suas vizinhas (localidade espacial), já que é muito provável usar uma região de memória próxima. E o que possivelmente eu não tenho com *jagged arrays*? Regiões de memória próximas entre os dados.

Para tentar ter um ganho significativo em relação a isso, poderíamos iterar na matriz da seguinte forma:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < 20; $j++) { 
        for ($p=0; $p < 40; $p++) { 
            echo $vaar[$i*20*40 + $j*40 + $p];
        }
    }
}
```

Ou então:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10*20*50; $i++) { 
     echo $vaar[$i];
}
```

Nesse caso aqui, linearizamos a matriz. Assintoticamente essa iteração continua sendo cúbica, pois é impossível algo mais rápido que percorra todos os elementos de um cubo. Porém, agora, estamos lidando com dados consecutivos, dados que estarão contíguos na memória.

Como os dados estão contíguos, ao carregar para a *cache* L1 o vetor na posição, digamos, 10, o processador pode colocar logo na *cache* os valores do vetor entre 5 e 14 (inclusive). Assim, a quantidade de acessos à memória principal diminui. Com menos acessos à memória principal, rodamos mais rápido. Sem falar que a quantidade de desreferenciamento é menor.

Em um *jagged array*, cada olhada no índice da matriz é um desreferenciamento, e desreferenciamento é carregar a variável para a memória e pedir para o processador carregar a região apontada por ela.

Por exemplo, para fazer `$vaar[$i][$j][$p]`:

- pegue o endereço apontado por `$vaar`
  (carregar variável em memória)
- pegue o valor `$i`
  (carregar variável em memória)
- adicione `$i` casas a `$vaar`
- carregue o valor em memória obtido na soma
  (desreferenciamento de endereço)
- pegue o valor `$j`
  (carregar variável em memória)
- adicione `$j` casas à variável carregada da memória anteriormente
- carregue o valor em memória pelo endereço obtido por essa nova soma
  (desreferenciamento de endereço)
- pegue `$p`
  (carregar variável em memória)
- adicionar `$p` casas à variável carregada da memória
- carregue o valor em memória obtido pelo endereço obtido nessa nova soma
  (desreferenciamento de endereço)

Como as variáveis estão no mesmo contexto, temos que é muito provável que, por localidade temporal, carregar essas variáveis não envolva acessar a memória principal. Mesmo assim, para cada `$i` ou `j` diferente, será necessário carregar o novo vetor de vetor que está sendo referenciado. É provável que eles estejam espalhadas na memória.

Compre com a iteração mais simples da linearização da matriz: `$vaar[$i]`

- pegue o endereço apontado por `$vaar`
  (carregar variável em memória)
- pegue o valor `$i`
  (carregar variável em memória)
- adicione `$i` casas a `$vaar`
- carregue o valor em memória obtido na soma
  (desreferenciamento de endereço)

Pronto, com apenas um único desreferenciamento, a variável está carregada em memória agora. E como estamos lidando com uma informação contígua, o próximo número estará próximo e portanto operável rapidamente.

Se for fazer algo do tipo, lembre-se de que:

- para acessar a posição `$i,$j,$p` do cubo, faça a seguinte conta: `$vaar[$i*20*40 + $j*40 + $p];`
- sua equipe de manutenção terá facilidade de ler esse código?

  - caso não, talvez o ganho de performance não compense a nova possível "ilegibilidade" do código

Comment: O que seria "assíntota"?

Comment: Na palavra "[assíntota](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assintota?wprov=sfti1https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assintota?wprov=sfti1)" tem link. Segundo o WolphramAlpha: dada uma curva (a) que se torna arbitrariamente próxima de outra curva (b), se diz que (a) é assíntota de (b). Lembrando que linhas são casos especiais de curvas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado muita boa resposta, mas não ficou claro pra mim se está confirmando o que eu disse, em um ponto específico, ou se está contestando, o que é normal. Provavelmente porque seu exemplo é o inverso. Você diz que a complexidade de `elementos` parece linear, mas não é, o que eu concordo, o `n` é o que está se avaliando. No exemplo da pergunta eu digo o oposto, de certa forma. O `n`, que é o que importa é a multiplicação das múltiplas dimensões, mas parece que é individualmente cada uma das dimensões analisadas...

Comment: ... é claro que a complexidade é x * y * z, mas ele é que forma o N real. É isto que quis dizer, é sobre o N real disfarçado, apesar de seu exemplo mostrar a forma inversa de como ele pode ficar "oculto"?

Comment: @Maniero a intenção era confirmar o que você fala, para `n` no meu contexto sendo o tamanho da dimensão do cubo. Realmente a minha escolha de nomes não ficou boa, vou alterar para tentar deixar no mesmo contexto que os nomes na sua resposta.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado achei os nomes normais, sei lá, se pode melhorar, é que pelo modelo uso ser inverso passou a impressão de ser que estava dizendo o oposto que eu, embora achei que não, até pela sua bagagem matemática forte. Lembrando que a complexidade sempre considera a estrutura de dados e o algoritmo. Em um algoritmo de acesso indexado, por exemplo, poderia ser O(1), O(logN), O(N) ou até algum outro, onde N ainda é a multiplicação das dimensões, dependendo da implementação, esta do PHP até onde sei é O(1), aí obviamente não importa o N.