# Notação Big O - Complexidade O(log n)

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Tenho algumas perguntas acerca dessa complexidade, qual base é usada nesse logaritmo, 2 ou 10? e por quê? Buscando no google vi alguns comentários falando que a base não importava.. O logaritmo está profundamente ligado a essa complexidade ou ele é utilizado apenas para dar uma ideia do quão pouco a complexidade cresce a medida que `n` aumenta?

Última pergunta, sabendo apenas que, enquanto `n` cresce exponencialmente, a busca cresce apenas linearmente, seria o suficiente para entender todos os outros casos de complexidade envolvendo logaritmo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Definição da notação "Big O"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836/defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-nota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-big-o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A base realmente não importa muito, porque um logaritmo de uma base pode ser convertido para outra base multiplicando-se por uma constante. Por exemplo: log<sub>2</sub> 10 = log<sub>10</sub> 10 / log<sub>10</sub> 2 (sendo que log<sub>10</sub> 2 é uma constante), e a notação "Big O" existe justamente para que possamos desprezar constantes.

Em se tratando de computadores, você pode pensar em termos de logaritmo base 2, porque casa bem com algoritmos no estilo "dividir e conquistar", como procura numa árvore binária, onde dobrar o número de elementos aumenta a árvore em apenas 1 nível.

Dificilmente importa o trabalho absoluto que um algoritmo exerce para um certo valor de "n". O que importa é a proporção entre diferentes valores de "n", por exemplo n=10 e n=1000000. Se você fizer log(1000000)/log(10), o resultado é sempre igual a 6, não importa a base do logaritmo, então qualquer que seja a base, O(log n) expressa corretamente a ideia de que n=1000000 custa apenas seis vezes mais trabalho que n=10 para um algoritmo O(log n).