# Desempenho entre indexOf() e o .get() do hashmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, desempenho

Estou com um problema de desempenho da minha aplicação e estou achando que pode ser os diversos `.get()` que eu dou, desta forma estou cogitando transformar esses *hashmaps* para *arrays* e usar o `indexOf()` pra fazer as buscas, vocês acham que há ganho em desempenho usando `indexOf()` em vez de `.get()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `get()` do mapa tem [complexidade O(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101) e o [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) do *array* tem complexidade O(n), portanto não dá nem para comparar, tamanha a diferença de performance, e mudar para o *array* piorará muito, a não ser que a pergunta não esteja clara e queira fazer outra coisa, ou esse *hashmap* na verdade é formado por números em sequência, aí o *array* fica natural.

Se tem problemas de performance precisa descobrir onde é, não adianta ficar especulando, só sabendo exatamente onde é o problema que pode procurar a melhor solução.

Comment: Complementando: Acho que vale a pena ler a *thread* [Definição da notação “Big O”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/99718)