# Qual a complexidade do algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou aprendendo a calcular a complexidade de algoritmos, usando a notação Big-O, porém estou com dificuldades no algoritmo abaixo:

```
a=0
for(int i = n; i>0; i -=2){
    for(int j = i+1; j<=n;j+=1){
        a++;
    }
}
```

Se puderem me explicar como resolver, eu agradeço.

Comment: Por ser dois loops, um dentro do outro, a complexidade deve ser O(n2), mas não entendo do assunto. Tem essa pergunta que pode lhe ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cada loop em lote, costumamos assumir um fator na notação assintótica e é claro que o impulso nos leva a crer que casos como esse são `O(n*n)=O(n²)`, como se cada loop aplicasse um fator linear, mas há vezes que não é assim.

Por exemplo, aplicar o quicksort em loops (e não recursões) resulta num comportamento predominantemente `O(n*log(n))`, mesmo podendo implementar com dois loops e no pior caso sendo `O(n²)`. Mais ainda, o mergesort em loops bem implementado sempre é `O(n*log(n))`, quer seja com dois loops em lote, quer seja com três. Sendo assim, vamos analisar.

No loop de `i`, encontramos que ele executa 1x se `n=1` ou `n=2`, 2x se `n=3` ou `n=4`, daí em diante linearmente, pois caminha de duas em duas unidades por ciclo até uma fixa condição de parada. Se `n<=0`, executa 0x. Quer dizer, o número de ciclos do loop de `i` é `max(0,ceil(n/2))`, para simplificar é entendido como `n/2`.

Já no loop de `j`, o número de vezes que executa é simplesmente (n-i)x, pois na primeira ele executa 0x, na segunda, 2x, na terceira, 4x e daí em diante, até o fim dos loops em 'i' que reduzem esse índice de dois em dois. O número de ciclos em `j` é `n-i`.

Sendo assim, a série é `n+(n-2)+(n-4)+...+3+1` (se `n` for ímpar) ou `n+(n-2)+(n-4)+...+4+2` (se `n` for par). Isso resulta nas duas fórmulas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando `n` é par ou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando `n` é ímpar.
Ambos resultam na mesma fórmula assintótica, que é a da complexidade do algoritmo: `O(n²)`.