# Qual a diferença entre "Big O", "Big Theta" e "Big Omega"?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Pra que serve cada um destes "Big O", "Big Theta" e "Big Omega" e quando usar cada um para descrever a complexidade de um algoritmo?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Definição da notação “Big O”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/5878)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso é uma polêmica já discutida antes de [outra pergunta que eu respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33330/101) e algumas pessoas disseram que estava errado. E estava mesmo, para acadêmicos. Sim, os acadêmicos definem isto de uma forma diferente de como as pessoas usam no dia a dia da programação (pelo menos por alguns, algumas pessoas dizem que isso serve pra nada, devem ser as mesmas pessoas que depois precisam recorrer a soluções complexas porque tudo está lento), então é complicado, esses conceitos sofrem preconceito de todo lado :) Você não falou que definição deseja, porque provavelmente não sabe que existe essa diferença. Eu vou de engenheiros pragmáticos.

Leia [O que é assíntota?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268409/101).

[**Big O**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) é o pior caso de um algoritmo, você faz uma análise de quantos passos no máximo algo será usado para completar a tarefa, por isso costumamos dizer que está calculando o tempo máximo que o algoritmo executará, ainda que isto não sirva para medir tempo de verdade, apenas uma proporção.

Algumas pessoas acham que é possível calcular o tempo exato. E até dá, mas é impraticável na maioria das situações e só pode ser ideia de acadêmico fazer isso, você tem que conhecer todos os detalhes de implementação e implantação para chegar neste número que acaba sendo irrelevante, até porque ele é mais facilmente observável. Por outro lado se você não sabe como seria o comportamento básico dele, até porque sem isso não saberá como consertar algo que está demorando muito, tudo pode acontecer.

O **Big Omega** é o melhor caso que aquilo executará, mas normalmente não é uma informação relevante fora da academia, existem exceções (provavelmente quando usa tempo real).

O **Big Theta** quer saber a complexidade média de execução (não é que seja a média aritmética mesmo, ela fica entre as medidas anteriores, mas é algo que gera um valor menos previsível), então ele espera que esteja ente os dois conceitos anteriores. Em muitos casos a média (real) é o que queremos saber de verdade principalmente se a média ou próximo disto é o que mais acontecerá.

Já expliquei antes, se leu os *links*, que existem algoritmos que o Big O estrito de muitos algoritmos são bem ruins, por exemplo a busca em uma tabela *hash* tem Big O real O(N), em geral até um pouco mais que isso, mas pouco, talvez um O(N+k) ou O(N+M) onde M é um número baixo que precisa ser calculado por outra fórmula. Em muitos casos o que se usa como Big O é na verdade o Big θ, ou algo próximo disso. Em outros só ignoram as exceções que pode acontecer (o exemplo que citei agora tem complexidade constante na maioria dos casos, em alguns tem um custo um pouco maior, que pode sim chegar em ser linear, mas que na prática nunca acontece, então se ignora isto para maioria das análises, mas não pode em todas, então estão errados os acadêmicos e os "pragmáticos demais").

Existem alguns algoritmos que até tem a mesma complexidade, mas só quando os analisamos de forma superficial, o que pra efeitos práticos é suficiente, então o Big θ aproximado ocorre bastante, e ninguém dá a menor pelota pra ele.

Então quando for olhar para a [tabela desse site](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/), não ache que está usando Big O de verdade, nem outro Big, ali tem uma aproximação pragmática do que é importante para a maioria das análises que engenheiros fazem. Se tiver consciência que é uma simplificação está usando bem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho o assunto de complexidade confuso.

Comment: è menos confuso se deixar de lado o academismo e se concentrar no uso típico de Big O.

Comment: O Big Theta é usado para descrever que o algoritmo sempre terá a mesma complexidade independente do tamanho de n?

Comment: Não, isso nem faz sentido, se isso fosse verdade não teria diferença de complexidade e nada disso importaria.

Comment: Voltando novamente para o Big theta, ele pode ser usado quando Big O e o Big Omega tem a mesma complexidade?

Comment: Se eles tiverem a mesma complexidade os 3 terão porque não tem nada no meio, tudo é igual, não tem espaço para variação.