# Dúvida em análise de algoritmos

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou com dificuldades para conseguir provar se 
`f(n)=Omega(g(n))`, então `g(n) = O(f(n))`.

Como seria essa comprovação?
Com cálculo e com teoria?

Comment: Nesse site eles falam sobre a parte matemática, não sei se te ajuda: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213591/prove-that-if-fn-in-ogn-then-gn-in-omegafn

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como provar a ordem assintótica de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236960/como-provar-a-ordem-assint%c3%b3tica-de-um-algoritmo)

Comment: Também vale a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411911/64969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando O como limite superior de F(n)

Considerando Omega como limite inferior de G(n)

Temos:

```
F(n) = Omega (G(n)) -> F(n) <= G(n)
G(n) = O(F(n))      -> G(n) >= F(n)

F(n) <= G(n) <=> G(n) >= F(n)
```

Logo   `F(n) <= G(n)` equivale a `G(n) >= F(n)`

https://www.ime.usp.br/~song/cursos/complex/complex.html