# Como pegar o único valor diferente dentro de um array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo

Vi muitas questões mostrando como pegar valores únicos em um array, mas nenhuma resolveu meu problema. Recebo um array, como este:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
```

Quero determinar o valor único dentro dele, que, nesse caso, é: `2`.

Tenho um código que resolve o problema com valores pequenos, mas, com valores muito grandes, ele falha.

Segue o código:

```
function findUniq(arr) {
  var result;
  arr.forEach((value, index, self) => {
    var lengthAll = []; 
    self.map(x => {
      if(x === value) {
        lengthAll.push(x);
      }
    })
    if (lengthAll.length === 1) {
      result = lengthAll[0];
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Como melhorar o desempenho com valores grandes?

Comment: E se tiver dois valores únicos? Por exemplo, em: `[1, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: No meu problema, sempre tem um único valor diferente.

Comment: "mas, com valores muito grandes, ele falha" - qual é a falha?

Comment: Não sei exatamente. É um kata do codewars. Nos testes randômicos, que são com valores grandes algumas vezes, ele ultrapassa o limite de 12 segundos de processamento e quebra

Comment: @ViniBrasil, a falha é o tempo excessivamente longo, que ocorre algoritmos quadráticos que performam sobre um número grande de elementos. Se tiver 1e5 elementos, serão feitas 1e10 iterações, o que é um absurdo e demoraria bem mais do que precisa para esse tipo de problema.

Comment: A noite eu publico uma resposta, mas por ora os testes de carga estão aqui: https://jsbench.me/awkpdlrj0d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que você está complicando bastante utilizando o `Array.prototype.map` aí. Você não precisa, de fato, de mapear o array para resolver esse problema. Parece que você está utilizando o `Array.prototype.map` como um substituto de `Array.prototype.forEach`, o que é um uso impreciso.

Além disso, a solução proposta na pergunta tem complexidade de tempo quadrática, o que significa que, para cada elemento do array, uma varredura completa será feita. Por exemplo, para um array de 100 elementos, 100<sup>2</sup> iterações serão performadas.

Para saber mais sobre esse tipo de medida, veja [Definição da notação “Big O”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/69296).

---

Até onde entendo, não há como resolver esse problema com menos que O(n).

Isso significa que, para um array qualquer, você deve, necessariamente, percorrer cada elemento para verificar se há algum membro garantidamente único.

Resolvendo com um mapa e somente uma varredura para cada elemento do array original, tem-se algo como:

```js
function findUniqueElement(arr) {
  const map = new Map();

  for (const el of arr) {
    // Para cada elemento do array original, criamos um
    // registro no mapa `map` para determinar sua frequência:
    map.set(el, (map.get(el) || 0) + 1);
  }

  // Para cada elemento (sem repetição) do mapa, verificaremos
  // e retornaremos o primeiro único encontrado:
  for (const [entry, count] of map.entries()) {
    if (count === 1) return entry;
  }

  return undefined;
}

console.log(findUniqueElement([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])); //=> 4
console.log(findUniqueElement([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4])); //=> 3 (somente o primeiro único é retornado)
console.log(findUniqueElement([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])); //=> undefined
```

A complexidade do algoritmo acima aproxima-se O(2n) (considerado linear), o que é bem melhor que O(n<sup>2</sup>) (quadrática).

Vale lembrar que essa solução retorna somente o primeiro elemento único encontrado. Se a ocorrência de mais um valor único for possível, uma alternativa é retornar um array:

```js
function findUniqueElements(arr) {
  const map = new Map();

  for (const el of arr) {
    map.set(el, (map.get(el) || 0) + 1);
  }

  const uniqueElements = [];
  for (const [entry, count] of map.entries()) {
    if (count === 1) uniqueElements.push(entry);
  }
  return uniqueElements;
}

console.log(findUniqueElements([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4])); //=> [3, 4]
console.log(findUniqueElements([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])); //=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa função retorna o primeiro valor único no array, e retorna null caso nenhum seja único.

```js
function findUniq(arr) {
  let uniq = {};

  //Para cada elemento do array é criado um index no objeto 'uniq' e incrementado a quantidade de vezes que esse elemento aparece.
  arr.forEach(a => uniq[a] = uniq[a] ? uniq[a] + 1 : 1);
  
  //Com o objeto de contagem pronto, é possivel iterá-lo até encontrar o primeiro elemento que possui apenas uma recorrência
  for (i in uniq)
    if (uniq[i] === 1)
      return i

  //caso nenhum elemento possua apenas uma recorrência, um valor nulo é retornado
  return null;
}

console.log(findUniq([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: Seria legal adicionar uma explicação de como o algoritmo funciona. Agregaria valor a resposta.