# Dificuldade em entender a resolução de um problema

Tags: javascript, array, funções, arraylist

Meu problema é o seguinte; estava resolvendo alguns exercícios da plataforma hacker rank e me deparei uma questão que me solicitava identificar o único valor em uma array que não se repetia.
Não consegui pensar em alguma logica pra resolver o problema e resolvi pesquisar, achei então algumas resoluções para o exercício porém não entendi a logica por trás dos códigos, poderiam me ajudar a entendê-los ?

Por esse primeiro código ter um texto de apoio consegui entender parcialmente. Entendi que o método `.filter` cria um novo array caso passe no teste realizado pela função de ordem superior, sendo assim essa função de ordem superior seria a `function(value)`?, também não entendi o porquê ela está dentro dos parênteses, ela é o parâmetro do  método `.filter`?. Olhei na documentação sobre esses métodos `.indexOf` e o `.lastIndexOf` mas nao consegui entender exatamente como eles funcionam dentro desse código.

```
function lonelyInteger(a) {
  let unique = a.filter(function(value){
    return a.indexOf(value) === a.lastIndexOf(value)
  })
  
  return unique[0];
}
```

Já esse segundo código fico bastante abstrato pra mim, não entendi o porque das `{}`  na variavel `counts`, por que `result` está solto daquele jeito em baixo do `let counts = {}` e a lógica dos laços `for` nao fez sentido pra mim.

```
function lonelyinteger(a) {
    // Write your code here
    
    let counts = {},
        result;
    
    for(let i in a) {
        
        let num = a[i];
        counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
        
        for(let j in counts){
        
            if(counts.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
                
                if(counts[j] === 1){
                    result = j;    
                }    
            }
        }
    }
       
    return result;
}
```

Sei que minhas duvidas são básicas, mas não quero recorrer a forma mais facil de só fazer o Ctrl C + Ctrl V, quero realmente entender como faço para resolver a questão.

Fonte:

1º código: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/javascript-algorithm-lonely-integer-4397cd8b6ffc

2º código: aba de discussão do próprio exercício no site Hacker Rank

Comment: A primeira solução verifica se o índice da primeira ocorrência de um número é igual ao indice da última ocorrência, caso seja igual, a conclusão é que esse número aparece uma única vez no array e portanto, ele é único. Quanto a perfomance, ele verifica todos os números e para cada número executa `indexOf` e `lastIndexOf`, está executando portanto em O(n^2).

Comment: O segundo código começa bem ao criar o objeto `counts` para funcionar como um `set` dos números do array. Utiliza de forma, no mínimo, temerária um `for ...in` para percorrer todos os números da array e caso o número não seja uma chave de `counts`, ele adiciona com o valor 1, caso já tenha sido incluido atualiza o valor para 2 (de uma forma não tão fácil de ler), depois faz um segundo for para percorrer todos os elementos de `count`, transformando uma solução que poderia ser O(n) em O(n^2). Ao final, a chave cujo valor é igual a 1 é armazenada em `result`.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/511385/69296