# Como faz para não exibir os valores repetido JAVA

Tags: java

Boa noite, eu consegui fazer com que exiba todos os valores junto com os repetidos e somente os repetidos, eu queria saber como faço para exibir somente os números que não foram repetidos. Ex: 1,2,3,2,4 = 1,3,4

Agradeço desde já. Esse foi o código que fiz:

```
   int[] vetor3 = {4,6,2,2,8,2,0}; 
   int aux = 0;
   for (int  i = 0; i < vetor3.length; i++){
   for (int j = i+1; j < vetor3.length; j++){
   if (vetor3[j] == vetor3[i]){
   System.out.println("Vai: " +vetor3[j]);
   }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente a sua solução imprime apenas os números que se repetem, para imprimir os números que não são repetidos no `vetor`, você precisará percorrer o seu `vetor`, então verificar se uma posição específica se repete e imprimi-la ou não dependendo do caso. Ou seja, você precisaria de uma lógica para verificar se um determinado número está no vetor e outra para imprimir os valores, depois teria que juntá-las.

**Verificando se um número está ou não no vetor**

Para verificar se um número está ou não no vetor, você precisa percorrer todo seu vetor e comparar todas as posições com o número até encontrar um valor repetido. Você pode fazer isso usando a seguinte lógica:

```
int a = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    if (a == vetor[i]) // Se esse if ativar entao o numero 7 ta no vetor
}
```

**Imprimindo os valores do vetor**

Agora devemos fazer outra lógica para imprimir os números do vetor. O código para impressão seria o seguinte:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(vetor[i]);
}
```

O código acima imprimiria todos os valores, para não imprimir os repetidos, devemos unir os dois códigos. A união entre eles ficaria assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    boolean repetiu = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
        if (vetor[i] == vetor[j] && i != j) { // verificando repeticao
            repetiu = true; // numero repetiu
            break; // se repetiu ao menos uma vez, entao nao eh necessario
            // percorrer todo o vetor
        }
    }

    if (!repetiu) System.out.println(" " + vetor[i] + " ");
}
```

O código acima verifica se um elemento existe no vetor, isto é, se temos `vetor[3]`, então ele verifica se o número dentro de `vetor[3]` existe no vetor, se existir, então a variável `repetiu` será `true` e o `print` não será ativado, caso contrário, o número irá ser impresso na tela. Observe que a expressão `i != j` serve para impedir que o número seja comparado com ele mesmo (se isso ocorresse, então a variável `repetiu` seria sempre `true`). Caso alguma parte não tenha ficado clara, você pode fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%c3%a9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%c3%a1-lo) para compreender melhor a lógica.

Veja o código funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/3pomGL).

Answer (score 1):

Depende.

**Se a ordem dos elementos é importante**, ou seja, se eles devem ser impressos na mesma ordem em que aparecem no array, você pode usar a solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/516586/112052), mas lembrando que é um [algoritmo quadrático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/112052): para cada elemento do array, ele percorre todo o array novamente: nos elementos que são repetidos, o *loop* interno é interrompido no meio, mas para os que não se repetem, todo o array é percorrido novamente (quando há muitas repetições, o algoritmo seria próximo ou abaixo do sub-quadrático; no melhor caso, em que todos os elementos são iguais, seria linear; no pior caso, em que nenhum - ou a maioria - não se repete, é quadrático).

Claro que para arrays pequenos a diferença é insignificante (afinal, [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/)), mas comece a trabalhar com arrays maiores e isso começa a fazer uma diferença considerável.

Sendo assim, uma alternativa melhor seria percorrer o array apenas uma vez, e ir mantendo uma contagem dos elementos. Depois, eu imprimo somente os que tiveram a contagem igual a 1. Para isso usarei um `Map`, e para manter a ordem os elementos, um `LinkedHashMap` (que mantém os elementos na ordem em que foram inseridos). Para isso você vai precisar importá-los:

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

Depois é só fazer:

```java
int[] vetor = {4, 6, 2, 2, 8, 2, 0};
Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new LinkedHashMap<>(vetor.length);
for (int n : vetor) { // para cada elemento do array
    if (!counter.containsKey(n)) { // se não está no map, adiciona
        counter.put(n, 1);
    } else { // se já está, atualiza a contagem
        counter.put(n, counter.get(n) + 1);
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counter.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() == 1) { // imprime somente se a contagem for 1
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Ou seja, eu percorro o array apenas uma vez, para criar o `Map` contendo as quantidades de cada elemento, e depois percorro o map, imprimindo os que ocorreram apenas uma vez. Não é mais um algoritmo quadrático, e sim linear, mas tem o custo de manter o `Map` (não tem jeito, em computação tudo é [*trade-off*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff)).

---

Mas **se a ordem não for importante**, ou seja, eu só quero saber os elementos que ocorrem uma vez, mas não preciso retorná-los na mesma ordem em que ocorrem no array, uma alternativa é primeiro ordenar o array. Depois, basta ver se um elemento é igual ao seu antecessor e predecessor (tomando o cuidado de não verificar o antecessor do primeiro, nem o predecessor do último):

```java
Arrays.sort(vetor); // ordena o array
for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    if ((i == 0 && vetor[0] != vetor[1]) // se é o primeiro, e não é igual ao segundo
        // ou, se é o último, e não é igual ao penúltimo
        || (i == vetor.length - 1 && vetor[vetor.length - 2] != vetor[vetor.length - 1])
        // ou, se não é o primeiro nem o último, e é diferente do anterior e do próximo
        || (vetor[i] != vetor[i + 1] && vetor[i] != vetor[i - 1])) {
        System.out.println(vetor[i]);
    }
}
```

Neste caso, a ordenação é - segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) - O(nlogn), o que já é melhor que o algoritmo quadrático. Depois de ordenar, percorremos o array uma única vez, verificando seus elementos.

Apesar de não ser linear, não há o gasto de se criar um `Map`. Mas há o efeito colateral de se ordernar o array original (que nem sempre pode ser o desejado - eu já disse que em computação tudo é *trade-off*? Você tem que escolher o que faz mais sentido em cada caso, e claro, testar com os dados reais para saber se usar um algoritmo ou outro faz alguma diferença significativa). De qualquer forma, as opções estão aí.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, você pode converter numa `stream` e usar o metodo `distinct` para "filtrar" os repetidos.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      String[] array = {"a", "b", "a", "c"};

      Arrays.stream(array)
        .distinct()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Saída:

a
b
c

Você pode usar o `filter` com uma lógica pra remover os duplicados, com o `frequency` que retorna a quantidade do mesmo:

```java
Arrays.stream(array)
  .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), i) < 2)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Saída:

b
c

Comment: Eu entendi e consegui fazer desta forma que você falou, obrigado pela dica, mas você sabe como faria para não mostrar os números repetidos, "A , B, C, A" = "B, C" tipo assim?

Comment: Desculpa @TantoFaz tinha entendido errado.