# Quais maneiras de medir o desempenho de um algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo, desempenho

Caso eu tenha, por exemplo, alguns algoritmos de ordenação(Merge sort, Quick sort, Bubble sort...) de que maneira(s) posso saber a eficiência de cada um?

Comment: Relacionado: ["O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/215) e ['Definição da notação “Big O”'](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/215). Mas há muito mais em se determinar a "eficiência" na prática do que essas análises (elas são um bom começo).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, um algoritmo não é "eficiente" ou "ineficiente", ele possui apenas um número de passos proporcional ao tamanho das suas entradas. A *implementação* desse algoritmo é que vai possuir uma eficiência, seja em memória, em tempo, em consumo de energia, etc. O que você pode fazer é avaliar o algoritmo sob diversas **métricas** e então tentar correlacionar essas métricas com o custo computacional correspondente (ex.: quanto mais etapas tem o algoritmo, mais instruções a CPU terá que executar).

A principal métrica é - como já citado - o número de passos que o algoritmo vai executar em relação ao "tamanho" da(s) sua(s) entrada(s). Para entender isso, recomendo a leitura da pergunta ["O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/215). Essa análise é um primeiro passo para determinar a eficiência, mas está longe de ser uma análise completa (a título de exemplo, o QuickSort - pior caso `O(n^2)` - costuma ter um desempenho melhor no caso médio que vários algoritmos com pior caso `O(n*log(n))`).

Outra métrica é a [Localidade de Referência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localidade_de_refer%C3%AAncia) - sobretudo se o volume de dados for alto, o acesso aos recursos necessário para implementar o algoritmo (ex.: memória, tanto primária quanto secundária) tem influência significativa na performance. Se um algoritmo possui um padrão de acessos que se encaixa bem na arquitetura utilizada (ex.: um algoritmo que acessa dados próximos uns dos outros, numa arquitetura que faz uso pesado da cache) então sua implementação deve ser mais eficiente que outro que possua um padrão de acesso irregular, ainda que o número de passos seja o mesmo.

(outro exemplo do caso acima são algoritmos que funcionam melhor se a entrada estiver ordenada; muitas vezes ordenar a entrada e depois usar o algoritmo acaba com um desempenho melhor do que só usar o algoritmo - o custo extra da ordenação acaba compensado pelo custo inferior do algoritmo, fazendo com que a performance global seja melhor)

Há diversos outros fatores a serem considerados, esses já mais ligados à implementação do algoritmo do que ao algoritmo em si - os padrões de desvio do algoritmo (ver [*Branch Prediction*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction)), a possibilidade de paralelização (seja em múltiplos núcleos da CPU ou talvez via GPU), a presença ou não de seções críticas (i.e. se a implementação precisa ser [*thread-safe*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) ou não), etc. Alguns deles podem ser avaliados *a priori*, outros somente *a posteriori* (implementei, e ficou lento, vamos agora descobrir por que).

Por fim, resta então implementar de fato e **medir** a eficiência real da implementação num determinado ambiente (por exemplo via *profiling*, como [sugerido por Shura16](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98709/215)). Sempre lembrando de [usar as estatísticas corretamente](http://zedshaw.com/archive/programmers-need-to-learn-statistics-or-i-will-kill-them-all/) de modo a determinar sob que circunstâncias o algoritmo se comporta de um jeito ou de outro (ex.: "se tudo mais for igual, mas o sistema tiver mais memória, o que acontece?"), descobrir por que ("aqui ele fica lento porque o SO não para de fazer *swap*") e determinar se a culpa é do algoritmo ou da implementação ("ah, o algoritmo usa uma pilha, mas minha implementação de pilha está com um problema").

Comment: +1 pelo Branch Prediction. A pergunta mais votado do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Answer (score 4):

Existem duas grandes formas de quantificar a eficiência de um algorítimo, o método empírico e o método analítico.

Essas formas podem variar de acordo com o aspecto de eficiência que deseja medir. Você pode avaliar a quantidade de memória usada pelos algorítimos ou então a intensidade do uso do processador, porém pela forma com que colocou a pergunta provavelmente quer classificar quanto ao tempo de execução dos algorítimos(método mais utilizado).

**Método empírico**

Tempo de execução do código na prática. Para este método existem diversas formas de medir, algumas delas dependem da linguagem de programação que está utilizando.

**Método analítico**

Representar através de uma ordem de grandeza o tempo de execução do algorítimo. Esse método independe da máquina que está sendo utilizada, do sistema operacional ou da quantidade de programas em execução porque para medir a grandeza somente o código é utilizado. [Notação BigO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-big-o).

Answer (score 1):

Vou recomendar então o uso de ferramentas de Profiling.
Cada linguagem tem suas ferramentas, podendo ter ferramentas genéricas.

Alguns IDE's costumam ter uma ferramenta embutida, mas todas elas exibem um relatório sobre o desempenho de um programa.

Answer (score 1):

calculo speedup
SU(p) = Ts/Tp(p)
SU=speedUp
Ts= tempo serial
Tp=tempo paralelo
p = n de processos

calculo eficiencia
E(p)=SU(p)/p

Se SU > 1 a versão paralela reduziu o tempo de execução (ficou mais rápido que a seqüencial) 
Se SU < 1 a versão paralela aumentou o tempo de execução (ficou mais lenta que a seqüencial)