# Proposta do Clojure?

Tags: característica-linguagem, programação-funcional, clojure

Recentemente ouvi falar dessa linguagem de programação, o [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure). Ela utiliza-se apenas de funções, não é tipada, e aparenta ser bem complexa.

Esse é um exemplo de função que recebe um parâmetro e faz a multiplicação desse parâmetro por ele mesmo.

```
(defn square [x] (* x x))
```

Pelo que vi também, não é necessário o uso de vírgula para separar os valores.

Será que vale a pena investir tempo para aprender [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure)? Pesquisando, achei muito pouco sobre ela e ainda não entendi a sua proposta real.

---

Caso tenham interesse encontrei um [compilador](http://www.tryclj.com/) online!

Comment: Ao que deu unlike, poderia falar uma maneira de melhorar a pergunta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se vale a pena investir é algo pessoal e cada um tem que decidir por conta própria analisando seus objetivos. Se quer saber se ela é popular, não é, como todo linguagem funcional, o que talvez seja uma pena. Entre as funcionais ela nem é das mais populares, nem das menos populares. Seu uso é mais comum em meio acadêmico e aplicações específicas, mas pode ser usada com maior ou menor sucesso para todo tipo de aplicação. Eu sempre costumo dizer que aprender linguagens novas não causa mal algum, pelo contrário, sempre ajuda o programador entender melhor a computação e resolver problemas de formas mais adequadas.

Parece já saber que a linguagem é **funcional** (há [comparação com OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101) e [com imperativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101)) que é um dos [paradigmas básicos existentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). Entendendo o objetivo desse paradigma já entende boa parte do objetivo de [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure).

Ela tenta usar uma sintaxe mais "limpa" e declarativa, então tudo parece funções (sequer tem laços), por exemplo `* x x` é a chamada da função de multiplicação que passa como argumentos a variável `x` 2 vezes. Em outras linguagens mais imperativas a sintaxe usaria um operador *infix* e seria escrito assim: `x * x`. Algumas pessoas preferem entender como `Multiply(x, x)`. Note que os parênteses têm função primordial ([*s-expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)). Essa ideia vem da linguagem **[Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))**. Essa sintaxe costuma permitir códigos bem concisos e expressivos.

Como a maioria das linguagens funcionais ela preza pela [imutabilidade de estado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101), mas não tenta ser pura (estado pode ser mudado sob certas regras) e realmente não é tipada, mas pode usar tipos opcionalmente (*gradual type*), com isso ela facilita a **concorrência** usando [*software transactional memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). Ela possui extensibilidade (limitada) de sintaxe, e as funções são de primeira classe, portanto elas são tratadas como se fossem dados. Ela possui polimorfismo.

Obviamente ela tenta resolver alguns problemas que seus criadores acreditam que outras linguagens funcionais possuem.

A linguagem costuma **rodar em cima da JVM** (principalmente), [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), JavaScript, entre outros *hosts*, se beneficiando do que essa infraestrutura pode oferecer.

[Site oficial](https://clojure.org/). Lá [tem um *rationale*](http://clojure.org/about/rationale).

Andou famosa por aqui porque o Nubank adotou quase pra tudo. Duvido que tinha motivo técnico, quase sempre é gosto do CTO disfarçado.

Em geral a pessoa consegue justificar tecnicamente, mas nunca é um ganho expressivo e não costuma considerar os prejuízos. Mas pode ser "esperteza" em certo sentido. Você força as pessoas trabalharem do seu jeito porque ninguém tem experiência com a linguagem, terá que seguir as receitas de bolo criadas ali. A pessoa fica com menos opção de emprego se concentrando em uma tecnologia que ninguém mais usa e tenderá sair menos que em outros lugares. Ou seja, seria uma decisão política.

Me lembro de um caso de software que foi feito em Scala. Tinha zero motivos técnicos para escolher essa linguagem, foi só gosto da pessoa que fez. A pessoa abandonou o projeto, aí saíram correndo atrás de alguém para continuar. Ou não achavam gente boia ou gente cara. Só prejuízo.

Recentemente uma importante *startup* brasileira teve que comprar a empresa que cuida de Clojure para não ficar sem suporte da linguagem que escolheram.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bom, aproveitando a deixa, existe um livro em inglês que é free e pode ser acessado [Aqui](http://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/)

Comment: O Uncle Bob gosta de Clojure https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2019/08/22/WhyClojure.html

Comment: @Piovezan motivo absurdamente errado pra adotar uma linguagem. Por isso que eu acho ele sobrevalorizado. Curiosamente é uma linguagem mais fácil de aplicar OO do que a maioria que se diz OO por aí :D