# Quais são as desvantagens de objetos imutáveis?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, programação-funcional

É notório as vantagens dos objetos imutáveis, como: são mais confiáveis, pois eles nunca são alterados; são thread-safe, pois não têm problemas com sincronização quando várias threads alteram o mesmo objeto; podem ser cacheados e não têm espaços de estado complexos que mudam ao longo do tempo, pois são estáticos; etc.

Mas se os objetos imutáveis oferecem mais benefícios que a programação oposta, são considerados mais confiáveis e proporcionam um programa mais simples e coeso, por que a maioria dos desenvolvedores e projetos continuam criando objetos mutáveis?

**Atualizado**

Algumas desvantagens podem ser encontradas [neste link do próprio site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103460/o-uso-de-imutabilidade), mas ainda gostaria de saber o que leva a maioria dos desenvolvedores e projetos não adotarem a prática da criação de objetos imutáveis se os mesmos, teoricamente, são a solução para a maioria dos bugs problemáticos com impacto em produção.

**Atualizado 2**

Gostaria de saber também quais padrões de modelagem de software, *OO* ou *funcionais*, facilitam o uso da imutabilidade.

Comment: Como li em um livro uma vez: mais importante que saber como algo funciona é saber como ela não funciona.

Comment: Oi, gente. Esse espaço é pra responder perguntas. Se não for ajudar, não atrapalhe. Achei muito pertinente a sua dúvida. Concordo com o Anderson. Dá uma olhada nesse link.https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_imut%C3%A1vel