# Princípios de Encapsulamento

Tags: java, encapsulamento, clone

Estou estudando para o exame de certificação Java Programmer SE 7 I.

Utilizo o SelfTest Kaplan (recomendado pela própria Oracle).

Me deparei com a seguinte pergunta:
(vou deixar tudo em inglês propositalmente. Para não traduzir e acabar omitindo informação).

> Given:
>
> ```
> public class Pedometer {
>      private double stride;
>      private double[] measurements;
> }
> ```
>
> Which code fragment is a method that meets good encapsulation
>   principles?
>
> ```
> a) public void getStride(double stride) {
>     stride = this.stride;
> } 
>
> b) public void getStride(double stride) {
>     this.stride = stride;
> } 
>
> c) public double[] getMeasurements() {
>     return this.measurements;
> } 
>
> d) public double[] getMeasurements() {
>     return measurements.clone();
> }
> ```

Repsondi a opção **c**, embora tenha achado a opção **d** bem interessante.

Quando fui ver o resultado vi que de fato, a opção correta era a **d**.

Por que?

Não estou questionando o funcionamento do método `clone()` e nem questionando que clonar um objeto seja "melhor", mas questionando: **por que essa implementação não é comum?**

Já trabalhei em diversos projetos Java e nunca vi um *getter* assim.

O Eclipse, por exemplo, não gera os *getter* s dessa forma (`ggas`).

Nem mesmo o `lombok` faz essa implementação.

---

Explicação da resposta pelo Kaplan:

> Explanation: The following code fragment is a method that meets good
>   encapsulation principles:
>
> ```
> public double[] getMeasurements() {
>     return measurements.clone(); 
> }
> ```
>
> In this code fragment, the accessor method uses the `clone` method to
>   return a copy of the `measurements` field, rather than a reference to
>   the field itself. Accessor methods should return copies of field
>   objects. A copy of a field will prevent other classes from modifying
>   fields directly and will require going through mutator methods.
>
> The two versions of the accessor method `getStride` do not meet good
>   encapsulation principles. Neither method returns the value of the
>   `stride` field as expected, but instead modifies the `stride` field like a
>   mutator method. Also, the statement `stride = this.stride;` overwrites
>   the `stride` parameter, rather than assigning the `stride` parameter to
>   the `stride` field as expected.
>
> The accessor method `getMeasurements` that returns a direct reference to
>   the `measurements` field object does not meet good encapsulation
>   principles. Accessor methods should not return direct references to
>   field objects. Direct access will allow other classes to modify fields
>   directly without going through mutator methods.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Acho que na resposta já está bem explicado o porquê de fazer dessa forma. Apesar de nunca ter visto também acredito que a explicação faz muito sentido

Comment: @Sorack editei a pergunta e deixei a dúvida em negrito. Se essa é a forma correta de implementar, por que não implementamos assim?

Comment: Acho que este é um dos exemplos do que diferencia alguém que programa em Java e alguém que programa e é certificado. Tem coisas que a gente só aprende estudando para a certificação. Eu acho que faz muito sentido essa implementação, tanto que normalmente quando você importa classes de um WS, elas já vem com um `setter` e `getter` diferenciado para `List`, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendo. É que por outro lado, se utilizarmos o `clone()` para todos os _getter_ s de todas nossas classes, será criada uma quantidade enorme de objetos. Imagine que para cada `getAtributo()` seja criado um novo objeto? Quantas vezes fazemos isso em nossos sistemas? Várias!

Comment: Mas veja bem, isso não inclui tipos primitivos. Portanto não é pra tudo que isso é utilizado, entende? Eu acho que é um pouco questão de arquitetura também...

Comment: Concordo. Tipos primitivos não entram nessa conta. Mas ainda assim acho que a quantidade será bem maior do que referenciando o atributo diretamente.  Concordo também que é um quesito de arquitetura, mas gostaria de uma resposta concreta que diga o motivo de não utilizarmos assim. Juro, eu **nunca** vi um _getter_ dessa forma. Se estou implementando errado, quero me corrigir para fazer o certo.

Comment: Eu até entendo porque não é comum, porque é mais ou menos raro precisar retornar um *array* inteiro que é um membro de um objeto. Eu até aceito a premissa. Mas sinceramente potencialmente destruir a performance da aplicação para conseguir algo de benefício duvidoso, e pior ainda, não é óbvio que terá uma performance ruim, é algo que me faz pensar que a certificação do Java não vale nada ou tem peso negativo. É a ideologia se sobrepondo ao pragmatismo.

Comment: Não digo que não faça sentido fazer isto nunca, mas no exemplo dado eu não faria porque eu não tenho informação suficiente pra tomar uma decisão que pode comprometer a execução da aplicação. Talvez seja só culpa da pergunta ser muito mal feita, o que põe em xeque a validade da certificação da mesma forma. Tipos primitivos são "clonados" automaticamente, mas é garantido que ele é pequeno e tem semântica de valor.

Comment: É verdade que o Java nunca entendeu por completo a função de ter tipos por valor e por referência, por isso fez com que quase todos fossem por referência, mesmo quando por valor faça mais sentido semanticamente. Talvez não veja porque a maioria dos programadores são mais pragmáticos, ainda bem.

Comment: Acho que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103490/59479) do @bigown em uma pergunta sobre imutabilidade clareia um pouco as idéias

Comment: Te dar uma resposta precisa sobre o porquê de **não fazer** é muito difícil, já que cada desenvolvedor deve ter uma razão que o levou a fazer dessa forma (é mais fácil responder o porquê fazer assim). Para mim, a razão de não fazerem dessa forma é que por mais que Java seja uma linguagem orientada a objetos, os programas ainda são, de certa forma, escritos em um modo procedural. Se você parar para analisar a maioria dos *JavaBeans*, eles não passam de *structs* glorificadas.  continua...

Comment: Eles não contém nenhum lógica, não verificam se os valores passados são válidos, não garantem que vão estar em um estado consistente e tudo que foi "encapsulado" é exposto. No fim das contas, não faria a menor diferença se seus atributos fossem públicos e seus métodos não existissem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me baseando nos comentários feitos na pergunta e em algumas pequisas, tomo como resposta que:

> Fazer *getters* com `clone()` é de fato a melhor/correta implementação. Com tudo, é preciso analisar caso a caso pois pode-se acarretar na criação de vários objetos, podendo até sobrecarregar o *Garbage Collector*.
>
> Fazer *getters* retornando a referência direta do atributo, segundo a literatura, não é uma boa prática de encapsulamento porque ao retornar a referência direta você permite que sejam feitas modificações no objeto através da variável atribuída com o retorno do *getter*.

Comment: O .Net também funciona dessa mesma forma?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues é uma boa pergunta. Eu **acho** que sim

Answer (score -4):

No caso é pq funciona como se fosse um backup.
Não interfere no objeto principal e vc não enfrentará uma classe que no meio da interposição possa modificar o objeto principal.

---

Por exemplo, vc pode ter um objeto  private String nome;
O java não se importa que vc faça
public String getNome(){

return this.nome +"outro nome";
}
Ele vai deixar concatenar e de fato quebrará o princípio do encapsulamento.

É a mesma idéia do Object. Assing do JavaScript.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).