# Variável do laço foreach

Tags: c#, variáveis, característica-linguagem, foreach

Quando utilizamos um laço de repetição `foreach`, a variável local que criamos para receber o conteúdo da lista em questão é passado por valor ou referência?

Ex:

```
foreach (var item in listItems)
{
   //TODO
}
```

A variável `item` recebe o conteúdo por valor ou referência?

Comment: cada vez que é feito um loop, a variável `item` recebe um dos itens presentes na `listItems`. Não entendi bem tua pergunta

Comment: certo @ItaloRodrigo mas a informação é recebida por Valor ou por Referência?

Comment: Acredito que seja passada a referencia do objeto da lista.

Comment: Milton, não é sempre por valor. Somente será por valor se a lista for um tipo primitivo - vide minha resposta. Se for uma lista tipo complexo, será por referencia.

Comment: @Articuno É sempre valor.

Comment: Nao é por valor, por valor significa uma cópia dos dados, e não é o que ocorre.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O item é por valor, por isso nem é permitido alterar seu valor.

Só tem um detalhe, se o item for um objeto por referência esse valor que estou falando é ponteiro e não o objeto em si, então pode modificar  o objeto normalmente, só não pode mudar a referência constante na coleção, ou seja, não pode mudar o objeto como um todo para um novo, mas pode modificar o existente.

Existe uma [proposta para dizer que o item deve ser por referência](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/461) e trazer todas as consequências boas e ruins disto.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var lists = new List<List<int>> { new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 } };
        foreach (var item in ints) {
//          item = 9; //não compila
        }
        foreach (var item in lists) {
            item[0] = 9;
        }
        foreach (var item in lists) {
//          item = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 }; //não compila
        }
        foreach (var lista in lists) {
            foreach (var item in lista) {
                WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9WuEDK). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pnJKLU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/ForEachRef.cs).

Veja [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). E também: [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Também irá ajudar [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

Há muita confusão entre programadores, e especialmente no mundo .NET, sobre o uso de memória, por isso seria interessante aprofundar os conceitos sobre tipos por valor e referência, onde eles são alocados, o que pode se fazer com ele, e sobre [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) que geralmente as pessoas associam a tipos por valor (que alguns chamam de primitivos, mas esse conceito não existe em C#), mas esses tipos podem ser imutáveis, ou associam que tipos por referência são mutáveis e eles podem ser imutáveis, veja mais em [O uso de imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101).

Comment: Então o `item` irá se comportar de acordo com o tipo da coleção.

Comment: Sim, depende do tipo dos itens da coleção. O que não muda nada em relação a outros aspectos da linguagem. Tudo é valor na linguagem, a diferença é que tipos por valor tem o seu objeto de forma direta, e os tipos por referência tem como seu valor um ponteiro para um objeto externo, ou seja de forma indireta. Não é possível mudar um valor sem mudar a identidade, mas é possível mudar um objeto referenciado e manter a identidade, desde que sua composição permita assim, um exemplo do que não é assim é a *string*. Alterar uma caractere nela altera a identidade e referência,

Comment: portando não permite alterar seu valor dentro do `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

Depende do tipo que é a lista.

Se for uma lista do tipo complexo - `class` - será por referência.

Se for uma lista de tipo primitivo - `string`, `int`, `bool`, `decimals`, etc - será por valor. Porém, não poderá alterar o valor essa variável, por se tratar de uma variavel de iteração do `foreach`.

## TL;DR;

Isso se deve ao fato que, variáveis primitivas são alocadas em memória diferente dos tipos complexos. Existem dois tipos de memória que deve-se preocupar enquanto desenvolve:

- **Memória Stack**: Memória de acesso rápido e de alocação de valores simples;
- **Memória Heap**: Memória de acesso não tão rápido, para alocação de valores complexos;

Quando se cria uma variável de tipo primitivo - int, long, string, decimal, float, double, etc - essa fica enderessada à um endereço na memória *stack*, e esse endereço possui alocado um **valor** simples.

Quando se instancia um objeto à uma variável - `new class();` - ocorre o seguinte: a variável irá fazer referencia à um endereço na memória *stack*, mas esse endereço irá fazer **referencia** à um endereço na memória **heap**, e lá é onde estará todos os valores do seu tipo complexo.

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando vc faz um `foreach` em uma lista de tipo complexo, ocorre que é criada uma nova variável na memória *stack* chamada `item` essa apenas tem sua referencia alterada para os itens da lista. Sendo assim, o `foreach` é por **referência**.

Mas se for uma lista de tipo primitivo, isso não é possível, e vc acaba fazendo o `foreach` for **valor**.

Espero ter esclarecido tudo nessa questão. Se algo mais faltou, comente. :)

## Simplifação

Fazer um loop como o abaixo:

```
foreach(var item in list) 
{ 
    /* aqui vai seu código */ 
}
```

É **quase** o mesmo que fazer (esse *quase* é relevante):

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
     var item = list[i];
     /* aqui vai seu código */ 
}
```

Mas o `foreach` é muito mais elegante. :)

## Documentação Microsoft - foreach-in (C# reference)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Comment: Quem negativou, que se pronuncie, por gentileza.

Comment: Não foi eu em quem negativou, mas sua resposta está errada ou no mínimo faltam detalhes. Mesmo que seja uma classe, será por valor, o que acontece é que este valor equivale ao ponteiro do objeto. Ou seja, é **um valor**, porém este valor **é a referência**. Por este motivo é possível modificar o objeto, mas não é possível trocá-lo usando um `= new Algo()` ou `= null`, por exemplo.

Comment: Acabei de elaborar minha resposta. Veja se melhora a defesa.