# Atributo ou campo privado e getter e setter na programação orientada a objetos em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

Na programação orientada à objetos em Java, quando eu crio um atributo ou campo privado quaisquer, sem seus respectivos métodos `getter` e `setter` tem que definir o atributo como `final` ou não necessita?

Por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private int idade;
    private double salario;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String endereco, int idade, double salario) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.salario = salario;
    }

}
```

Nessa classe a cima como vocês veem, nela não possui os métodos `getter` e `setter` dos respectivos atributos ou campos, nesse caso seria necessário defini-los como `final`?

Comment: Não é obrigatório. A keyword `final` é utilizada para definir um valor que não poderá ser alterado ( e por consequência deverá ser inicializado juntamente com o objeto ). Se você deseja ter um atributo privado e no entanto ele é variável em seu valor. não há a necessidade de declará-lo como `final`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente o **campo** não deve ser `final`. Pode ser, mas raramente faz sentido, e nunca quando tem um *setter*. O `final` determina que o valor não poderá ser alterado depois de inicializado no construtor. É o que deseja? O campo será [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101) quando faz isso, e aí um *setter* não terá função alguma, a não ser que faça nele algo completamente sem sentido já que o que o normal seria mudar o valor do campo associado a ele.

[O que chama atributo na verdade chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Eu sei, a culpa não é sua, todo mundo ensina errado mesmo. Em inglês os termos corretos são *getter* e *setter*.

E aproveito para dizer que nem sempre esses métodos devem ser usados, ao contrário do que muitos falam por aí. Sim, para ser 100% orientado a objeto deve usar, mas o que as pessoas não falam é que nem sempre você tem benefícios fazendo isso e sempre tem algum malefício, precisa decidir se vale a pena. Há uma pergunta onde eu *linko* várias perguntas sobre o assunto, dê uma navegada lá: [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

A pergunta original tinha outros problemas conceituais, programação tem muito a ver com conceituar as coisas corretamente, especialmente em orientação a objeto que é organizar os conceitos de forma que faça sentido.

Comment: _"raramente faz sentido"_ Já eu acho que frequentemente faz sentido o campo ser `final`, e atribuo esse modificador sempre que possível. Deixa mais clara a semântica do campo, se o campo só precisa receber valor uma vez, no construtor, eu o defino como `final`.

Comment: A propósito, peguei essa "mania" de uma recomendação no SOen para definir um objeto `synchronizationLock` como `final`. Posso até estar repetindo cegamente uma "boa prática", mas a recomendação foi tirada do livro _Effective Java_, então acabei considerando válida para o caso geral.