# Como fazer cálculos com instâncias de uma classe, ou com até com novas instâncias?

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer uma operação com duas, ou mais, instâncias de uma classe. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```js
class myClass{
  constructor(a){
    this.a = a
  }
}

var myObj1 = new myClass(2)
var myObj2 = new myClass(3)

//log esperado: {"a": 5}
console.log(myObj1 + myObj2)

//log esperado: {"a": 6}
console.log(new myClass(1) + new myClass(5))
```

Comment: Ate onde eu sei não, objetos não são números, você provavelmente vai ter que fazer um método para acessar a variável a e soma-la.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já dito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/464656/112052), o JavaScript não suporta sobrecarga de operadores, então o jeito é ter um método na sua classe que soma os valores e retorna outro objeto com o resultado:

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  // soma o valor deste objeto com o valor de obj e retorna outro objeto com o resultado
  add(obj) {
    return new myClass(this.a + obj.a);
  }
}

var myObj1 = new myClass(2);
var myObj2 = new myClass(3);
var myObj3 = new myClass(10);

console.log(myObj1.add(myObj2)); // { "a": 5 }
console.log(new myClass(1).add(new myClass(5))); // { "a": 6 }

// somando vários de uma vez
console.log(myObj1.add(myObj2).add(myObj3).add(new myClass(1))); // { "a": 16 }
```

De forma similar, se você quisesse implementar as outras operações (subtração, multiplicação, etc), teria que ter um método para cada:

```
subtract(obj) {
  return new myClass(this.a - obj.a);
}

multiply(obj) {
  return new myClass(this.a * obj.a);
}

etc...
```

---

Um detalhe é que cada chamada de `add` cria uma nova instância, ou seja, `obj1.add(obj2)` retorna um novo objeto, e tanto `obj1` quanto `obj2` permanecem inalterados.

Isso quer dizer que em uma chamada encadeada como `obj1.add(obj2).add(obj3).add(obj4)`, são criados vários objetos intermediários, que só são usados para fazer a chamada seguinte.

Mas também é possível fazer com que o método `add` modifique a própria instância:

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  add(obj) {
    this.a += obj.a;
    return this;
  }
}

var myObj1 = new myClass(2);
var myObj2 = new myClass(3);
var myObj3 = new myClass(10);

// myObj1 é modificado pelas chamadas de add()
myObj1.add(myObj2).add(myObj3).add(new myClass(1));
console.log(myObj1); // { "a": 16 }
```

Assim, `myObj1.add(myObj2)` soma os valores de `myObj1` e `myObj2`, e modifica o próprio valor de `myObj1`. Eu fiz com que o método retorne `this` (a própria instância), pois assim continua possível encadear várias chamadas de `add` - e cada uma delas vai atualizando o valor de `myObj1`, que no final terá o resultado de todas as operações.

---

Ou seja, você pode escolher entre modificar a própria instância ou retornar uma nova. Qual delas usar? [Depende](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/112052).

---

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Answer (score 3):

Não tem como.

JavaScript não permite a sobrecarga de operadores, então não tem como você implementar um comportamento diferenciado para o operador `+`.

Relacionado a isso, o método `valueOf`, que é um método de `Object`, é como o JavaScript recupera o valor do seu objeto para utiliza-lo em operações aritméticas.

Se você implementar a sua classe da seguinte maneira:

```
class myClass{
  constructor(a){
    this.a = a
  }

  valueOf() {
    return this.a
  }
}
```

Até será possível comparar a grandeza dos seus objetos:

```
var myObj1 = new myClass(2)
var myObj2 = new myClass(3)

console.log(myObj1 > myObj2) // false
console.log(myObj1 < myObj2) // true
```

No entanto se você utilizar o operador `+`, o seu resultado será apenas `5`, e não `{'a': 5}`