# Como calcular a complexidade desse algoritmo?

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Gostaria de uma explicação de como calcular a complexidade do algoritmo abaixo. Não consegui entender muito bem por usar teoria dos grafos.

```
FUNCTION PageRank (G, iterarion)
    d = 0.85
    oh = G
    ih = G
    N = G
    for all p in the graph do
        opg[p] = 1 / N
    end for
    while iteration > 0 do
        dp = 0
        for all p that has no out-links do
            dp = dp + d * (opg[p] / N)
        end for
        for all p in the graph G do
            npg[p] = dp + ((1-d)/N)
            for all ip int ih[p] do
                npg[p] = npg[p] + ((d*opg[ip])/oh[ip])
            end for
        end for
        opg = npg
        iteration = iteration - 1
    end while
end function
```

A imagem abaixo ajuda a visualizar melhor o algoritmo com suas respectivas linhas.

[image: PageRank]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33319/o-que-%c3%a9-a-complexidade-de-um-algoritmo)

Comment: Esse é um algoritmo distinto das demais perguntas. Então não existe uma possível duplicata @Francisco

Comment: Coloquei o algoritmo. A imagem ajuda a visualizar melhor cada linha, por isso optei por coloca-la, uma vez que há operações matemáticas que podem ficar complexas de serem visualizada @diegofm

Comment: @diegofm eu não alterei a edição, apenas coloquei o pseudocódigo e deixei a imagem. Só foi isso de alteração que eu fiz

Comment: Entendi, de qualquer forma, fica a dica quando adicionar código de mais de uma linha, use o `{}` que ele formata melhor :)

Comment: A complexidade de tempo do algoritmo é o quanto ele leva para processar as instruções para uma **entrada média**, também tem a **melhor entrada** e a **pior entrada**. No caso, você precisa ponderar o peso de cada operação (normalmente cada operação aritmética pequena tem peso 1) e, se ela tem repetição, quantas vezes repete. Postarei uma resposta completa mais tarde

Comment: Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado. Estarei aguardando :)

Answer (score 1):

Este algoritmo é `O(i * n^2)` considerando o pior caso (um [grafo completo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafo_completo)), onde:

- `n` é a quantidade de nodos no grafo
- `ì` é o valor da variável `iteration`

Isso acontece porque o maior aninhamento de laços é:

- para cada valor em 1..iteration

  - para cada p em G

    - para cada ip nos vizinhos de p