# Função de complexidade

Tags: java, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou com dúvidas de como fazer uma análise de função de complexidade desse código Java

```
package exercicio_2_ed;

public class Potencias {
public void calcular( int[] numeros ){
    for( int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++ ){

        System.out.println( "Potências de " + numeros[i] );

        for( int j = 1; j <= 5; j++ ){
            System.out.println( numeros[i] + "^" + j + " = " + (int) Math.pow( numeros[i], j) ); 
        }

    }
}
}
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para calcular.

Comment: Quer saber a complexidade usando o Big O, no caso, assintótica?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo!

Comment: Pergunta respondida! Espero que minha resposta ajude você a entender melhor complexidade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33319/o-que-%c3%a9-a-complexidade-de-um-algoritmo)

Comment: Não é duplicata. As questões são diferentes.

Comment: Vinnicius, caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas, mas é bom que depois de resolvida você marque alguma para fechar o assunto. Saiba mais em ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de simplesmente dar o resultado da complexidade do seu exemplo vamos primeiro entender como funciona e como devemos calcular. Então vamos lá!

Para calcular a complexidade de um método ou algoritmo de forma eficiente vamos utilizar a notação Big O, ou, complexidade assintótica, que por definição é:

> “Sejam f(n) e g(n) funções mapeando números inteiros (tamanho da
>   entrada) em reais (tempo de execução). Dizemos que f(n) é O(g(n)) se
>   existe uma constante real c > 0 e uma constante inteira n0 ≥ 1 tais
>   que f(n) ≤ cg(n) para todo inteiro n ≥ n0.”

Dentro da complexidade assintótica temos vários tipos de função. Abaixo eles estão ordenados do melhor (constante) para o pior (exponencial):

- Constante → 1
- Logarítmica → log n
- Linear → n
- n-log-n → n log n
- Quadrática → n²
- Cúbica → n³
- Polinomial → n^k
- Exponencial → a^n

Na imagem você pode ver as taxas de crescimento das funções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observações:

- É muito importante entender os principais tipos de função de complexidade 
  pois é com base neles que iremos definir a complexidade de nossos 
  algoritmos. Porém, chega disso e vamos ao que interessa.
- A notação O determina que uma função f(n) é "menor ou igual a" outra
  função g(n), descontando-se um fator constante, a medida que n cresce
  para infinito.
- Um algoritmo A com complexidade O(n²) nunca terá um tempo de execução
  superior a n², para uma determinada entrada n, mesmo no pior caso.

Regras para definir a complexidade assintótica:

1. Função polinomial: sempre considerar o maior grau.

   - 5n^4 + 3n³ + 2n² + 4n + 1 é uma O(n^4).
2. Constantes e multiplicadores são eliminados.

   - 4n³ é O(n³) -> Não me interessa a constante, a longo prazo vai ser
     irrelavante.
3. Função mista: sempre considerar o termo de maior complexidade.

   - 5n² + 3n log n + 2n + 5 é O(n²). Nesse caso a complexidade de uma n² é muito maior que a de uma log n, por isso eliminamos a mesma.
4. Sempre considerar a representação mais simples.

   - 4n² + 2 log n é O(n²), o que, sem dúvidas é melhor que O(n² + log n).

Entendida as regras podemos ver alguns exemplos (inclusive o seu).

**Exemplo 1**

```
public static int sumNumbers(int n1, int n2) {
  int result = n1 + n2;
  return result;
}
```

Para o exemplo 1 temos operações constantes por todo o método, logo, possui complexidade constante O(1).

**Exemplo 2:**

```
// Retorna true se não existe elemento duplicado no vetor.
public static boolean unique1(int[ ] data) {
  int n = data.length;
  for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
     for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
         if (data[j] == data[k])
             return false;
  return true;
}
```

Para o exemplo 2 temos uma complexidade de O(n²).

> Observação: Uma dica, sempre que tiver um `for` dentro de seu método
>   ele será executado n vezes, logo, já teríamos uma complexidade O(n).
>   Se temos um `for` dentro de outro, temos uma complexidade de O(n²),
>   pois estamos executando n * n. Porém, sempre se atente a detalhes,
>   isso não é garantido, cada método é um caso.

Para o seu exercício teremos uma O(n), com um `for` segundo executando n vezes operações internas com complexidade constante.

*Nota: Caso fique na dúvida sobre a operação [Math.pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418731/java-math-powa-b-time-complexity) saiba que ela possui complexidade O(1).*

Para montar essa resposta me baseei no livro de Goodrich e Tamassia, Estrutura de Dados & Algoritmos em Java. Recomendo a leitura.

Comment: Na verdade, é `O(n)`, pois o `for` interno só é executado 5 vezes `for( int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)`. Olha lá o algoritmo novamente.

Comment: Realmente Henrique, acabou passando despercebido que o for é interno era executado somente 5 vezes! Obrigado pelo aviso!