# Como otimizar o tempo desse código?

Tags: c, c++

Criei o código abaixo para resolver o problema [Cofre](https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p1/2017/f1/cofre/),  da OBI de 2017. Ele funciona, porém em 60% dos casos ele excede o tempo limite, como faço para otimizá-lo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N, M, pAnt, pAtual, resp[10]={0};
    cin >> N >> M;
    int seq[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin >> seq[i];
    }
    cin >> pAnt;
    resp[seq[pAnt-1]]++;
    for(int i=1;i<M;i++){
        cin >> pAtual;
        if(pAnt<pAtual)
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                resp[j]+=count(seq+pAnt, seq+pAtual, j);
        else
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                resp[j]+=count(seq+pAtual-1, seq+pAnt-1, j);
        pAnt = pAtual;
    }
    cout << resp[0] << " " << resp[1] << " " << resp[2] << " " << resp[3] << " " << resp[4] << " ";
    cout << resp[5] << " " << resp[6] << " " << resp[7] << " " << resp[8] << " " << resp[9] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No lugar de para cada algarismo você contar quantas vezes ele ocorre no intervalo não seria mais prático varrer o intervalo uma única vez e incrementar cada ocorrência do algarismo?

Answer (score 1):

**Criar algoritmos é diferente de criar códigos**, pois para se criar um algoritmo e bem otimizado, você deve ser um bom matemático e saber bem do funcionamento como um todo de computação.

**Sobre a Complexidade de Tempo**

> Em ciência da computação, a complexidade de tempo de um algoritmo quantifica a porção de tempo tomada por um algoritmo para rodar em função do tamanho da entrada do problema. A complexidade de tempo de um algoritmo é comumente expressada usando a notação **big O**, que suprime constantes multiplicativas e outros termos de menor ordem. Quando expressada dessa forma, a complexidade de tempo é dito ser descrita **assintoticamente**, i.e., como o tamanho da entrada vai para o infinito. Por exemplo, se o tempo requisitado por um algoritmo em todas as entradas de tamanho n é no máximo **5n³ + 3n**, a assíntota da complexidade de tempo é **O(n³)**.

**Sobre o Tempo de Processamento**

> **Medir o tempo gasto por um algoritmo:**
>
> - Não é uma boa opção
> - Depende do compilador
> - Pode preferir algumas construções ou otimizar melhor
> - Depende do hardware (GPU vs. CPU, desktop vs. smartphone)
>
> **Diferentes entradas podem ter custo diferente**
>
> - Melhor caso
> - Pior caso
> - Caso médio

[FONTE OFICIAL: WIKIPEDIA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo#Tabela_de_complexidade_de_tempo_comum)

**NOTA:**

> Você pode ler mais sobre este assunto [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33319/o-que-%C3%A9-a-complexidade-de-um-algoritmo) e também para saber os melhores algoritmos criados em relação complexidade de tempo, acesse a fonte oficial acima.