# Como contar elementos repetidos numa lista de tuplos?

Tags: python, lista, tupla

```
listaAnimais=[('leao', 'Simba'), ('javali', 'Pumba'), ('leao', 'Scar'), ('hiena', 'Banzai'), ('leao', 'Mufasa')] #especie,nome
dicEspecies={}

for especies,nome in listaAnimais:
    dicEspecies[(especies)]=(listaAnimais.count(especies))

print(dicEspecies)
```

Resultado obtido:

```
{'leao': 0, 'hiena': 0, 'javali': 0}
```

Resultado desejado:

```
{'leao': 3, 'hiena': 1, 'javali': 1}
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Eu editei sua pergunta para que ela atenda às normas do site. Para melhorar suas perguntas futuras, leia esse manual: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa usar a lista inteira dentro do `for loop` já que você só precisa do primeiro elemento das tuplas. Um solução seria criar uma sub-lista a partir da primeira e só então fazer a iteração. Veja:

```
listaAnimais=[('leao', 'Simba'), ('javali', 'Pumba'), ('leao', 'Scar'), ('hiena', 'Banzai'), ('leao', 'Mufasa')] #especie,nome
lista_especies = [t[0] for t in listaAnimais]
dicEspecies={}

for especie in lista_especies:
    dicEspecies[(especie)]= lista_especies.count(especie)

print(dicEspecies)
```

Output:

```
{'leao': 3, 'javali': 1, 'hiena': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

O jeito mais fácil é usar um `Counter`, classe da biblioteca padrão `collections`.

Ele aje como um dicionário e pode ser inicializado com uma lista, ou, nesse caso, uma expressão geradora:

```
from collections import Counter

# especie,nome
listaAnimais = [
    ('leao', 'Simba'),
    ('javali', 'Pumba'),
    ('leao', 'Scar'),
    ('hiena', 'Banzai'),
    ('leao', 'Mufasa'),
]

# Criar um contador, o inicializando com a primeira string
# de cada elemento em `listaAnimais`
dicEspecies = Counter(animal[0] for animal in listaAnimais)

print(dicEspecies)
# Counter({'leao': 3, 'javali': 1, 'hiena': 1})
```

Por trás dos panos, essa solução é eficiente porque roda em tempo linearmente proporcional ao tamanho da lista, e não quadraticamente como usar `count` dentro de um loop `for`.

De modo mais simples possível, ela faz o equivalente a isso:

```
# Inicializamos um dicionário vazio
dicEspecies = {}

# Para cada animal...
for especie, nome in listaAnimais:

    # Se a espécie ainda não estiver no nosso
    # dicionário, a inicializamos com o valor de 0
    if especie not in dicEspecies:
        dicEspecies[especie] = 0

    # Em qualquer caso, somamos um à contagem
    # dessa espécie
    dicEspecies[especie] += 1

print(dicEspecies)
# {'leao': 3, 'javali': 1, 'hiena': 1}
```

Sobre a performance: é uma observação trivial pra uma lista desse tamanho, mas se a lista fosse de tamanho grande, teríamos que tomar cuidado com a complexidade do algoritmo usado para a contagem. [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33319/o-que-%C3%A9-a-complexidade-de-um-algoritmo) tem conteúdo interessante sobre a complexidade de algoritmos e como analisá-la. [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/78934) também é muito boa.

Basicamente, o approach usando `count` dentro do loop `for` funciona em tempo quadrático O(N^2): isso é, à medida que o tamanho da lista N aumenta, o tempo de execução da função aumenta proporcionalmente a N^2.

Isso acontece porque

- O algoritmo itera sob todos os elementos da lista com o `for`
- Para cada elemento, ele chama `count`: essa função, internamente, novamente percorre toda a lista para contar quantos elementos estão presentes.

Já usando um dicionário ou Counter, só percorremos a lista uma vez no `for`. Os dois, internamente, são uma estrutura de dados chamada de tabela de dispersão (hashmap), que tem a propriedade de ter verificação de pertencimento e acesso em tempo constante; quer dizer, que independe do tamanho N da lista.

Nesse caso, à medida que o tamanho N da lista cresce, o tempo de execução da função aumenta proporcionalmente a N, porque só percorremos a lista uma vez somente, e não N vezes.

Comment: Muito interessante sua resposta. Como faço para saber esses detalhes de performance? Usando seu exemplo, como saber se uma função rodar linear ou quadraticamente em uma lista?

Comment: @Hartnäckig basicamente é um estudo de complexidade de algoritmo - nada importante pra uma lista desse tamanho, mas que vale ter em mente se for lidar com listas muito maiores. Atualizei a resposta pra explicar um pouco melhor!