# verificar se o número é palíndromo em c sem usar vetor

Tags: c, lógica

Estou com dificuldade em um exercício em que preciso verificar se um número é palíndromo ou não, sem usar vetor.
fiz um jeito pra pegar cada dígito do número, mas não sei como armazenar esse dígitos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num=0, resto=0;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    do{
        resto=num%10;
        num=num/10;
        
    }while(num != 0);
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: não precisa armazenar esses dígitos: precisa saber quantos são. E um número `N` tem `(unsigned) floor(1+log10((double)N))` dígitos. Não é algo de C mas sim do ensino fundamental.  `log(N)` retorna o logaritmo de base 10 então ... `log(10)` é `1`, `log(100)` é `2` e assim por diante. Sabendo isso basta um loop para definir se `N` é palíndromo

Comment: Não precisa nem de log, basta pegar os dígitos e ir montando outro número, até que seja igual ao original (na verdade, até a "metade" do original): https://ideone.com/0WhGib

Comment: Correção: https://ideone.com/IrjGH8 (não precisa testar até o número ser zero)

Answer (score 1):

O algoritmo para verificar se um número é um palíndromo é simples, tem complexidade de tempo O(n) e é bem próximo do que estava fazendo. Veja [complexidade de um algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/137387)

No caso irei modificar os nomes das variáveis, tornando-as mais declarativas visando facilitar a compreensão.

Em resumo:

- Declare `numero` variável inteira cujo armazena o número que será testado como palíndromo.
- Declare `palindromo` variável inteira onde será montado o reverso de `numero`.
- Declare `num` variável inteira onde é feita uma cópia de trabalho do valor de `numero`.
- Enquanto o valor de `num` não for `0`...

  - Declare `digito` variável inteira cujo o valor é digito da unidade de `num`.
  - `palindromo` recebe `palindromo` vezes `10` mais `digito`.
  - `num` recebe `num` dividido por `10`, assim removendo sua unidade.
- Verifique se o valor de `palindromo` é igual a `numero`:

  - Caso sejam iguais imprime a frase `"O numero é um palíndromo."`.
  - Caso não sejam iguais imprime a frase `"O numero não é um palíndromo."`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  const int numero = 125521;                 //Armazena o número que será testado como palíndromo.
  //scanf("Digite um número inteiro: %d", &numero);
  int palindromo = 0;                        //Variável onde será computado o reverso de numero.
  int num = numero;                          //É feita uma cópia para manipulação do valor de numero. 

  //Enquanto num não for 0....
  while(num)
  {
    int digito = num % 10;                   //...obtém o dígito da unidade de num.
    palindromo =  palindromo * 10 + digito;  //...multiplica palíndromo por 10 e adiciona o dígito anteriormente obtido.
    num /= 10;                               //...extirpa de num o dígito da unidade.
  }  
  printf(
    "O numero %d %sé um palíndromo.\n", 
    palindromo, 
    palindromo==numero? "" : "não "          //Imprime se o número é ou não um palindromo.
  );    
}
//O numero 125521 é um palíndromo.
```

Caso tenha dificuldades com expressões ternárias o fragmento do código onde imprime se número é ou não um palíndromo pode ser reescrita como:

```
  if (palindromo==numero)
  {
    printf(" O numero %d é um palíndromo.\n", palindromo);  
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf(" O numero %d não é um palíndromo.\n", palindromo); 
  }
```

Outra maneira mais performática, ainda em complexidade de tempo linear, foi apresentado pelo usuário [HKotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) em comentários [aqui](https://ideone.com/IrjGH8) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/559104/verificar-se-o-n%C3%BAmero-%C3%A9-pal%C3%ADndromo-em-c-sem-usar-vetor/560615#comment993395_560615).

> Conforme eu já comentei acima, não precisa inverter o número todo,
> você pode parar na metade.    Por exemplo, se o número é 1221, você
> pode parar quando o número invertido for 12, pois ao comparar com os 2
> primeiros dígitos do número original(que também é 12) você já sabe que
> é palíndromo e se já passou da metade conclui-se diferente pois não
> precisa continuar porque já é sabido que não é palíndromo.

O algoritmo seguiria os seguintespassos:

- Declare `numero` variável inteira cujo armazena o número que será testado como palíndromo.
- Declare `palindromo` variável inteira onde será montado o reverso de `numero`.
- Declare `num` variável inteira onde é feita uma cópia de trabalho do valor de `numero`.
- Teste se `num` é negativo:

  - Caso `num` seja negativo atribua a `num` o seu valor absoluto.
- Enquanto `num` for maior que `palindromo`

  - Declare `digito` variável inteira cujo o valor é digito da unidade de `num`.
  - `palindromo` recebe `palindromo` vezes `10` mais `digito`.
  - Testa se `num` é igual a `palindromo`:
    *Se `num` for igual a `palindromo` abandona o laço de iteração.
  - `num` recebe `num` dividido por 10, assim removendo sua unidade.
  - Testa se `num` é igual a `palindromo`:
    *Se `num` for igual a `palindromo` abandona o laço de iteração.
- Verifique se o valor de `palindromo` é igual a `num`:

  - Caso sejam iguais imprime a frase `"O numero é um palíndromo."`.
  - Caso não sejam iguais imprime a frase `"O numero não é um palíndromo."`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  const int numero = -123532;                 //Armazena o número que será testado como palíndromo.    
  //scanf("Digite um número inteiro: %d", &numero);
  int palindromo = 0;                         //Variável onde será computado o reverso de numero.
  int num = numero;                           //É feita uma cópia para manipulação do valor de numero. 

  if (num < 0) num = -num;                    //Testa se num é negativo, caso seja obtenha seu valor absoluto.
  
  //Enquanto num for maior que palindromo...
  while(num > palindromo)
  {
    int digito = num % 10;                    //...obtém o dígito da unidade de num.
    palindromo =  palindromo * 10 + digito;   //...multiplica palíndromo por 10 e adiciona o dígito anteriormente obtido.
    //...caso num seja igual palindromo ou caso num extirpado das unidades seja igual palindromo sai do laço.
    if (num == palindromo || (num /= 10) == palindromo) break;
  }

  printf(
    " O numero %d %sé um palíndromo.\n", 
    numero, 
    palindromo==num? "" : "não "
  );
}
```

Comment: Conforme eu já comentei acima, não precisa inverter o número todo, vc pode parar na metade. Por exemplo, se o número é 1221, vc pode parar quando o número invertido for 12, pois ao comparar com os 2 primeiros dígitos do número orignal (que também é 12) vc já sabe que é palíndromo. E se já passou da metade e é diferente, não precisa continuar pq já sei que não é: https://ideone.com/IrjGH8

Comment: @hkotsubo, vou retirar a resposta por enquanto ,e irei adicionar mais tarde o seu algoritmo junto de uma explanação. Estou sem tempo no momento. Obrigado!

Comment: @hkotsubo, Está ai. Fiz uma modificação no seu algoritmo removendo a condição `if (num == 0) num = palindromo = -1;` pois é desnecessária: https://ideone.com/53v88m .Obrigado pela orientação.