# Contar número de comparações e tempo de execução dos algoritmos de ordenação em python

Tags: python

Preciso de um algoritmo que calcula o número de comparações feitas nas ordenações do tipo: bubble sort, selection sort, insertion sort e merge sort.

```
def bubbleSort(Lista):
    exchanges = True 
    passnum = len(Lista)-1
    while passnum > 0 and exchanges:
       exchanges = False
       for i in range(passnum):
           if Lista[i]>Lista[i+1]:
               exchanges = True
               temp = Lista[i]
               Lista[i] = Lista[i+1]
               Lista[i+1] = temp
       passnum = passnum-1

def selectionsortcrescente(Lista):
    for i in range(len(Lista) - 1):
        minimo = i
        for j in range( i + 1, len(Lista)):
            if(Lista[j] < Lista[minimo]):
                minimo = j
        if(minimo != i):
            Lista[i], Lista[minimo] = Lista[minimo], Lista[i]

    return Lista 


def selectionsortdecrescente(Lista):
    for i in range(len(Lista) - 1):
        minimo = i
        for j in range(len(Lista)-1,i,-1):
            if(Lista[j] > Lista[minimo]):
                minimo = j
        if(minimo != i):
            Lista[i], Lista[minimo] = Lista[minimo], Lista[i]

    return Lista 


def insertionsortcrescente(Lista):

    for i in range(1, len(Lista)):
        key = Lista[i]
        j = i - 1
        
        while j >= 0 and key < Lista[j]:
          Lista[j + 1] = Lista[j] #troca de posição
            j = j - 1
        
        Lista[j + 1] = key


def insertionsortdecrescente(Lista):

    for i in range(1, len(Lista)):
        key = Lista[i]
        j = i - 1
        
        while j >= 0 and key > Lista[j]:
            Lista[j + 1] = Lista[j] 
            j = j - 1
        
        Lista[j + 1] = key


def mergeSort(Lista):
    if len(Lista) > 1:
        mid = len(Lista) // 2
        left = Lista[:mid]
        right = Lista[mid:]

      
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
              
              Lista[k] = left[i]
              
              i += 1
            else:
             Lista[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            
            k += 1

        while i < len(left):
            Lista[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            Lista[k]=right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

Lista = [85, 43, 12, -31,  3, -40, 98, -47, -6, -79, 31, -59, -81, 15, -66]

print("* Bubble Sort: ")
print("Antes: ", Lista)
print ('Lista ordenada por bubble sort:',bubbleSort(Lista) )

print("* Selection Sort: ")
print("Antes: ", Lista)
print ('Lista ordenada em ordem crescente por selection sort:',selectionsortcrescente(Lista) )
print ('Lista ordenada em ordem decrescente por selection sort:',selectionsortdecrescente(Lista) )

print("* Insetion Sort: ")
print("Antes: ", Lista)
print('Lista ordenada em ordem crescente por insetion sort:',insertionsortcrescente(Lista))
print('Lista ordenada em ordem decrescente por insection sort:'insertionsortdecrescente(Lista))

print("* Merge Sort: ")
print("Antes: ", Lista)
Lista = mergeSort(Lista)
print("Depois:", Lista)
```

Comment: Você não estaria tentando calcular a [complexidade de tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33319/o-que-%c3%a9-a-complexidade-de-um-algoritmo) de cada algoritmo?

Comment: é o mesmo que o tempo gasto para rodar o algoritmo?

Comment: Não, [complexidade não é tempo](/a/33330/112052). Enfim, em cada função, crie um `contador = 0`, e cada vez que uma comparação for feita, dentro do respectivo `if` vc incrementa o contador (`contador += 1`). Depois a função pode retornar o contador. Só um detalhe, como todas as funções alteram a lista, então depois da primeira a lista já estará ordenada, e portanto as próximas não terão o que ordenar :-) Sugiro inicializar a lista novamente, ou então criar uma cópia dela (por exemplo, `bubbleSort(Lista.copy())`)

Comment: e como ficaria isso no código? pois também preciso do tempo de execução