# Tempo de resposta do código pior com funções

Tags: javascript, loop, desempenho, for

Estava no Code Wars fazendo um desafio e fiz dois códigos, um deles da um tempo de resposta grande e o outro um tempo menor, porém ambos usam FOR. No primeiro fiz o uso do `for` e dos métodos `reduce()` e `filter()`. Queria saber se foram os métodos que fizeram o tempo de resposta mais demorado ou se é o processamento do `for` (eu acho ser a mesma coisa em ambos).

Primeiro - tempo lento:

```
function solution(number) {
    if (number <= 0) {
        return 0
    }
    let array_of_K = []//array com números primos repetidos

    for (let i = 0; i < number ; i+=3) {
        array_of_K.push(i)
    }
    for (let i = 5; i < number ; i+=5) {  
            array_of_K.push(i)
        }
    let array_of_K_filter = array_of_K.filter((elememt, i) => array_of_K.indexOf(elememt) === i)
    //array filtrado sem números repetidos 'array_of_K_filter'

    let resul = array_of_K_filter.reduce((acc, ca) => acc + ca)
    //Uso do reduce para somar todos números primos

    console.log(resul)
    return resul
}
solution(10)
```

Segundo código - tempo rápido:

```
function solution(number) {
    let suma = 0
    if (number <= 0) {
        return 0
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        let multi = !(i % 3) || !(i % 5)
        if (multi) {
            suma += i
        }
    }
    return suma
}

solution(10)
```

Comment: Imagine que tem vários livros em uma prateleira, e eu só quero saber quantos livros dos autores A e B foram escritos entre 2000 e 2010. Eu posso pegar todos os livros de A e colocar em uma caixa, depois todos os livros de B e colocar na mesma caixa. Aí eu pego os livros da caixa, vejo se a data está entre 2000 e 2010 e coloco em **outra** caixa. Depois eu conto quanto livros tem nessa caixa. Ou eu posso simplesmente pegar os livros um a um, vejo se é de A ou B, vejo a data, atualizo a contagem e devolvo para a prateleira. Qual será mais rápido?

Comment: No fundo é isso que acontece. Os dois primeiros `for` equivalem a colocar os livros de A e B na caixa. Depois `filter` faz a filtragem segundo algum critério (no meu exemplo foi a data do livro, no seu foi eliminar os repetidos), e como ele retorna **outro** array, equivale a colocar tudo em "outra caixa" - usa mais espaço/recursos (memória). E o `reduce` equivale a contar os que estão na segunda caixa (no seu caso, vc soma, mas na prática é o mesmo, pois vc está percorrendo todos os elementos e fazendo algo com eles). No fim foram feitos vários loops

Comment: Já o segundo código só percorre o array uma vez, vê se cada elemento é o que precisa e caso seja, adiciona-o na soma. É o mesmo que ver todos os livros da prateleira apenas uma vez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro código tem 5 laços, dois explícitos e mais três implícitos nas funções `filter()`, `reduce()` e `indexOf()`. Obviamente que isto é muito mais lento que o segundo código que faz apenas um laço. Fora as chamadas de função de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), em cada passo, necessárias nesse estilo de código.

Essas funções são bonitinhas, mas elas escondem o que estão fazendo e acabam sendo não só mais lentas, mas dão a impressão de serem maravilhosas porque as pessoas acham que o tempo de execução está relacionado com a quantidade de caracteres que está digitado, e não é assim. As pessoas usam essas funções por está na moda, elas não entendem o que está acontecendo ali. Não tem mágica, elas fazem *loops* lá dentro.

Além disso o que o primeiro código faz é algo extremamente ineficiente porque tem que ficar alocando memória sem necessidade alguma, o objetivo é só pegar uma soma (ao que parece), não precisa criar estruturas de dados para armazenar objetos para depois somar, pegue o que já existe, fazendo o filtro e somando, de forma simples.

O segundo código é mais simples, curto, eficiente, mais legível e óbvio, mas pode ser tudo isso melhor ainda.

Sem laços somando justamente os números que deseja e retirando os que geram intersecção entre eles já que não pode contá-los duas vezes.:

```js
function sequence(limite, incremento) {
    limite = incremento * Math.floor(limite / incremento);
    return ((limite / incremento + 1) / 2) * limite;
}

function solution(number) {
    return sequence(number - 1, 3) + sequence(number - 1, 5) -  sequence(number - 1, 15);
}

console.log(solution(10));
console.log(solution(20));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/SumSequenceFilter.js).

Veja mais sobre [complexidade de algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33330/101).