# Javascript - Como usar o reduce para somar todos os itens de um array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Supondo que eu tenha um array nesse formato:

```
[{
    id: 1
    nome: "Primeiro envio"
    estatistica: [{
        id: 1,
        entregues: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        entregues: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2
    nome: "Segundo envio"
    estatistica: [{
        id: 1,
        entregues: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        entregues: 3
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Como eu faria para somar todos os entregues do array? O esperado nesse caso seria 6.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente não entendo essa obsessão por `reduce`, nem sempre fica melhor. Esse é um caso em que um loop simples é mais que suficiente, veja: https://ideone.com/FtCA5x - olha como o `reduce` fica confuso (o fato de "ficar em uma linha" não o torna necessariamente melhor, até porque `reduce` é mais lento que um `for` simples, veja: https://jsbench.me/bol8kaopo4/1)

Comment: No meu entendimento o `reduce` seria melhor por ser mais curto. Obrigado pela informaçao.

Comment: [Código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052). Ver também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/565380/112052)

Comment: Irei ler depois, obrigado pelo conhecimento compartilaho.

Comment: Aliás, o `for..of`, se usar variáveis de uma letra e colocar tudo em uma linha, fica até menor que o `reduce`. Mas como eu já disse, não é o tamanho que torna um código melhor ou pior. Tem outros fatores bem mais relevantes, como legibilidade, facilidade de manutenção, desempenho, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Precisa ser feito um [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para pegar os dados do primeiro `array` e também dentro dessa função um outro [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para varrer o segundo `array` para produzir o resultado esperado, ***exemplo***:

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    nome: "Primeiro envio",
    estatistica: [{
        id: 1,
        entregues: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        entregues: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: "Segundo envio",
    estatistica: [{
        id: 1,
        entregues: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        entregues: 3
      },
    ]
  }
];
const sum = list.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.estatistica.reduce(function(c, d) {
    return c + d.entregues;
  }, 0)
}, 0);
 
document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Total de Itens: " + sum;
```

```html
<div> 
  <div id="result">Total de Itens: 0 </div>
</div>
```

Para fazer isso de maneira bem simples pode ser feito duas estruturas de repetição `for` que também tem o mesmo resultado, ***exemplo***:

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    nome: "Primeiro envio",
    estatistica: [{
        id: 1,
        entregues: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        entregues: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: "Segundo envio",
    estatistica: [{
        id: 1,
        entregues: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        entregues: 3
      },
    ]
  }
];
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < list[i].estatistica.length; j++) {
    sum = sum + list[i].estatistica[j].entregues;
  }
}

document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Total de Itens: " + sum;
```

```html
<div> 
  <div id="result">Total de Itens: 0 </div>
</div>
```

é outra forma eficiente de desenvolver esse tipo de solução.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelo conhecimento compartilhado.

Comment: Olha o voto útil ai gente

Comment: Olha o voto útil aumentando ...!