# Como calcular valores inteiros e de ponto flutuante diretamente no registrador em Python?

Tags: python, otimização

Talvez o título da questão não reflita com clareza o problema, mas é o seguinte: eu desenvolvi um algoritmo eficiente para um problema muito específico, que realiza varias operações aritméticas básicas, e que só funciona eficientemente se as operações forem realizadas diretamente no registrador, isto é: em tempo `O(1)`, tal como em C, C++, etc... Parte do código de exemplo:

```
for i in range(10**5):

    # Realiza o shift do valor.
    value -= data[i - m] * d
    value *= base

    # Soma o dígito à última casa.
    value = round(value + data[i])
```

Como vocês podem ver, é um código bem simples, nada demais. No momento, estou tentando implementá-lo em Python, contudo ele se apresenta absurdamente lento na linguagem.

Estou utilizando como métrica a comparação do seu tempo de execução com o tempo de um outro algoritmo que possui uma complexidade muito maior.

Abaixo uma amostra dos resultados:

```
$ meu_algoritmo_em_cpp.exe
Tempo de execução: 0.82s

$ algoritmo_de_maior_complexidade_em_cpp.exe
Tempo de execução: 1.73s

$ python meu_algoritmo_em_python.py
Tempo de execução: 13.71s

$ python algorito_de_maior_complexidade_em_python.py
Tempo de execução: 4.37s
```

Eu entendo que o motivo dessa lentidão é que Python possui uma camada de implementação por trás dos tipos `int` e `float`, exemplo: nós podemos gerar números absurdamente grandes com eles. Então certamente não é mais uma opção tentar algo com eles.

Pesquisando por soluções, eu encontrei algumas postagens que sugeriam utilizar Cython. Porém mesmo utilizando os seus tipos, tal como `cython.int` e `cython.longlong`, não houve diferença. Na verdade, parece que até aumentou o tempo. Exemplo:

```
# Antes de executar o algoritmo, converti tudo para os tipos do Cython.
# O tempo dessa conversão não foi computado para o resultado final.
value = cython.longlong(value)
base = cython.int(base)
data = [cython.int(v) for v in data]
...
```

Dito isso, existe alguma forma de realizar operações aritméticas diretamente nos registradores, em Python, ou pelo menos diminuir o tempo das operações?

Comment: Se a performance é necessária, seria melhor não usar Python. :P As próprias bibliotecas de Python que exigem isso não são implementadas em Python, mas sim em C, C++, Fortran, etc. O Python fica apenas de "cola".

Comment: O problema é que meu projeto, ao qual eu vou aplicar o algoritmo, já foi feito em Python. Então se não houver solução, o jeito seria criar uma DLL. Só que eu acho difícil que não exista uma forma de otimizar isso, já que, até como você disse, Python é quase uma interface pra C++

Comment: A complexidade de tempo desse algoritmo é O(n). Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/137387

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, eu sei... eu não entendi o porquê você apontou isso kkk Se foi porque eu falei de tempo de execução e complexidade, é porque meu algoritmo é O(n) e o outro é O(n*m), só que o outro tem menor tempo de execução devido à lentidão para calcular do python.

Comment: Na pergunta está escrito *"...se as operações forem realizadas diretamente no registrador, isto é: em tempo O(1), tal como em C, C++, etc...."* O código dentro do laço está condicionado a subtração então mesmo que tente aceleração vetorial SIMD ou uso de GPU o código continuará a iterar.

Comment: Estou me referindo às operações de soma, multiplicação, etc, em cima de `value`. Porque, por exemplo, como Python permite números maiores que 8 bytes para o tipo `int`, então é provável (não conheço a implementação para afirmar) que operações aritméticas nesse tipo não sejam O(1), porque ele precisaria particionar o número e operar em cima das partes. E ainda que isso seja feito em tempo O(1), é fato que a operação não é "pura", isto é: em Python você não simplesmente joga dois valores e soma diretamente, como ocorre em C/C++. Rola alguma coisa por trás que causa esse atraso do algoritmo.

Comment: Eu pensei assim, em `for i in range(10**5):` você tem `10**5` pacotes de operações aritméticas. Para obter algum ganho de processamento você poderia fazer com que a execução de algum desses pacotes de operações aritméticas fossem realizados em paralelo tirando vantagem do hardware, ou com vetoração SIMD ou paralelismo GPU, mas como esses pacotes contém a linha `value -= data[i - m] * d` a subtração `-=` impediria esse tipo de abordagem pois a resolução de qualquer um desses pacotes de operações(exceto o primeiro) é dependente do resultado do pacotes de operações anterior.

Comment: Quanto a demora que percebeu individualmente nas operações em Python com relação ao C/C++ é resultado de como o Python interpreta o loop. Ele interpreta o fonte em bytecode, porém adiciona variáveis de controle para testar a consistência do código interpretado a cada iteração o que o torna mais lento que o equivalente compilado.

Comment: "*é provável... que operações aritméticas nesse tipo não sejam O(1)*" - Em qualquer linguagem esse loop será O(n). Se as operações dentro do loop demoram mais na linguagem A e menos na linguagem B, não importa, a complexidade do algoritmo continua sendo O(n). [Big-O não mede tempo](https://ssp.impulsetrain.com/big-o.html#:~:text=Misconception%203) (apesar de muito material por aí afirmar isso, é uma mentira que de tanto ser contada, virou "verdade").

Comment: Sobre a pergunta em si, não conheço o suficiente pra dar uma solução, mas talvez ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72732401 | https://medium.com/coding-with-clarity/speeding-up-python-and-numpy-c-ing-the-way-3b9658ed78f4 | https://xkcd.com/1205/ :-)

Comment: Obrigado hkotsubo. Mas só corrigindo o primeiro comentário, como o do Augusto, eu não estava usando o BigO para medir tempo, e o problema alvo aqui  não envolve o for-loop e sim apenas as linhas de operações aritméticas. O for-loop no código foi só para mostrar que meu algoritmo depende do tempo de execução dos cálculos, porque são muitos cálculos sendo feitos. Btw, estarei em breve (espero) publicando um paper sobre o algoritmo, que é bem simples até, mas ngm tinha formalizado antes a ideia :D